# Why high rep users's duplicate questions do not get closed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I am aware what reputation is. You have to bust your ass, spend some amount of time and ofcourse know something useful to share with people. I like to have high reputation, everyone likes. But after all, reputation isn't everything, we are still all humans, and programmers. I am writing this because I noticed sometimes, at the very beginning of my Stackoverflow journey I got nice answers posted, but people with higher rep would get all the praise and upvotes. Doesn't matter. Recently, for the first time, I marked a flag as duplicate on a good question posted by high rep user. The question was well written and it was a bug about Google Chrome. Despite it was marked as duplicate, only by me, the user continued to get upvotes. I am not annoyed if someone is getting votes, but what discourages me is that people only see the reputation. They forgot that you don't have to be great to start, but have to start to be great.

So my final question is: how you mark duplicate question, i.e. how people get to vote for a duplicate and when does the question get marked/closed as duplicate. In my case the question was no doubt duplicate, but I turned out to be the 'hater' marking it.

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: Questions closed as dupes can still get upvotes, they just cannot get new answers.

Comment: Question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013486/chrome-css-linear-gradient-bug -- I would attribute it not (yet) being closed to it being viewed only a small number of times, rather than a rep-based form of nepotism.

Comment: Good to know. Anyway is it a crime to ask something you don't know. I understand downvote as a punishment :)

Comment: ...and it only has 2 upvotes!  I was imagining dozens with all the wailing and gnashing of teeth.  votes on meta represent agreement/disagreement with the point of your post.

Comment: Everyone here explain a lot to me. But I didn't post the question to get up/down votes. But I got many downvotes. Why is that?

Comment: read my last comment carefully...they also cost you nothing in terms of rep

Comment: Hmm, not so sure I'm buying, the overtones of envy and lack of documentation make it less than credible.  Regardless, if it was a very well written question then surely you marked the wrong question as the duplicate.  We do strongly prefer to select the best Q+A as the canonical answer, age is irrelevant.

Comment: @Hans  if it is a duplicate does it matter if it is good or bad written? I guess that's the way here

Comment: Also, since votes on Meta does not affect your reputation, people are more comfortable down voting here.

Comment: *does it matter if it is good or bad written?* - It matters when it comes to selecting which question to mark as the duplicate. The badly written question should be marked as a duplicate of the good one, all other things being equal.

Comment: @BSMP then I guess the right thing is to find the first (original) question and edit it. Or if you are saying that if you can ask duplicate question in a better way, then Stackoverflow would be full of duplicates. I can sit and combine articles from many books and re-ask many questions, and even provide better answers to my duplicate questions. That's not the answer, that's not why Stackoverflow is.

Comment: I'm not saying that the old question should be edited or that people should re-ask existing questions. I'm saying that if Question A and Question B are the same but B is the higher quality question, then A should be marked as a duplicate of B even if A is older than B. I actually made a list of how to choose which question should be the target of a duplicate here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295493/what-do-i-do-when-a-question-is-a-duplicate-of-multiple-questions/295500#295500

Comment: The goal of marking duplicates is to direct people to the location with the best answers rather than spreading knowledge out in multiple locations. Question and answer quality are more important than question age.

Answer (score 9):

Your flag has not been processed yet. There are 9,600 questions with a close vote or close flag on them, so it may be a while until your flag is handled. Until your flag is handled, the question will stay open.

This delay has **nothing** to do with the fact the author of the question is high rep. All duplicate flags are handled via this process.

You have marked the question as a duplicate in the correct manner. It will eventually get processed by the close-vote queue, where other users will vote for, or against, the question being closed.

Note that once you reach 3,000 reputation, [you can cast close-votes, rather than close-flags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), but I don't really want to confuse the situation by discussing that here.

Comment: the same negative energy :)
I posted the flag 9 days ago, maybe it takes more time, I don't know, it was my first flag. Anyway thanks

Comment: @krisiliev: Different flags get routed into different queues. You'll usually find low quality/ not an answer/ spam flags get processed quickly. "requires moderator attention" will take longer, and any form of "close" flag will take a lonnnnnng time.

Comment: `It will eventually get processed by the close-vote queue` unless it ages out of the queue....