# How to flag a question which is duplicate of multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Today I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983001/changing-the-value-of-a-pointer-passed-by-reference). After quick googling, I found out that it's exact duplicate of [Pointer to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable) and [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope), which, by the way, are duplicates of each other, and neither is closed as duplicate.

What's the right thing to do when I encounter question which is duplicate of multiple questions again?

**Note**: this question is related to [What do I do when a question is a duplicate of multiple questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295493/3821804), but that question asks about what to do when there are more than one question per question, and each is already answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's handled.

Just close in favor of the best Q&A-pair, and if any of the answers on a closed question would benefit the ones already at the master, also flag for moderators to merge them (mention which answer adds what important point, as a rationale, after concisely saying what you want to happen).