# How to handle questions whose root cause is an already well-answered issue?

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical

Debugging-help questions usually have this format:

> I am trying to do stuff.
>   I wrote this code:
>   `stuff code`
>   But it does not do stuff, it goes bleh instead. What went wrong?

Sometimes the cause of the stuff going bleh is clearly identifiable as a common issue which has already received extremely good answers.

Such an example is a mismanagement/misunderstanding of JavaScript closures and contexts which has already received some [famous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) (and has probably spawned thousands of questions and headaches).

I have thought of multiple ways to react:

- Commenting with a link to the super answers
- Answering and solving the issue with a link to the super answers
- Flagging as duplicate (and probably commenting)

I'm a bit puzzled, I don't know if I *should* answer such questions and I don't know if I should go as far as flagging as duplicate.

What is the best thing to do with these questions?

---

According to the community-accepted answers below, questions like this should be closed as duplicates of the root cause issue.
Funnily enough it's in direct contradiction of [this question posted eleven months before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different). The accepted answers to both questions are the same, but the community seems to strongly disagree...

Spread the chain. When in May of 2016 someone asks this same question and it gets answered in a different way, point them here.

Comment: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406/165773)

Comment: Close the question as duplicate if the issue explained in the linked question is the cause for OP’s problem. You can leave a comment explaining why this is the case specific to their posted code.

Comment: I will leave a comment leading the user to the relevant documentation and hint that they should do some research on the subject and try to figure it out themselves. Then if they can't figure it out I'll help them through correcting their implementation, once their problem is solved I'll vote to close as a duplicate of the question with the explanation that best fits their question. After the question is closed I try to come back and clean all the comments up. I don't, however, think questions like this deserve downvotes, they make good signposts.

Comment: I usually close as a duplicate. Sometimes they (or someone else) will complain that the questions aren't the same. But if they're the same root cause, and the solution is the same, that's good enough for me. I don't take "duplicate" too literally, I like that the wording when the question is closed is "The question already has an answer here".

Comment: I stumbled upon this today. I felt I shouldn't answer, since there are already so many answers to the same root problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978766/code-runs-fine-but-exe-doesnt-work

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254710/is-there-a-benefit-to-closing-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-more-than-one-questio

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Duplication on Stack Overflow is more about answers than questions.

If a question has been answered by a different question's answers, and those answers are high-quality answers to **this** question, close the question as a duplicate.

The benefit of duplicate closure is to attach a question to the best quality answer without having to repeat it, and to focus the answers on the best quality questions. If your duplicate closure advances these two goals, in my opinion, do it.

Note that you should be confident (and accurate in your confidence) that you don't do this incorrectly. Even before you have Mjölnir, voting to close as a duplicate shouldn't be done lightly.

Comment: That last paragraph is important. Frequently, code has **multiple** issues, and yet people close the question as a duplicate of the first issue they see, completely missing that there's more going on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's just a reason why we need closing with multiple duplicate targets :-) Usually I close with the canonical for the fundamental problem the OP is facing, and comment on the other issues. If they need further guidance, they should ask separate, more specific questions.

Comment: @Bergi: Sure, if multiple targets are relevant. But I believe closing a question for reason A when there are reasons B and C outstanding is a disservice to the OP, who is unlikely to understand that these are distinct issues. Finding originals for duplicate questions is a fantastic service the community needs to value more. (I think there should be rep involved, understanding that it would be...complicated.) That said, overdoing it is as bad as not doing it at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: a question involving code with multiple issues, and where the OP is looking for answers to those multiple issues is generally off-topic as "Too broad". It's worth adding a comment to the OP explaining that they need to break their problem into smaller pieces, solving or asking about each individual piece. But that doesn't stop the question from being closed. As a duplicate seems to me to be as valid an option as "too broad", if at least part of the question (especially a major part) is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Such a question isn't necessarily too broad. There are a number of problems that may have multiple root causes. A single error with just a few lines of code, or a problem requesting how to achieve something can very well form a single question that stands on its own, yet require an answer that addresses multiple angles.

Comment: @Bruno: I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree on that point. A "single error" is only going to have "multiple angles" if fixing that error reveals yet more errors; in that case, the duplicate question _does_ answer the _immediate_ question. In general, questions asking "how to achieve something" are most frequently asked in a too-broad way; I rarely see a question like that which is focused enough to not be too broad, and if it is focused enough _and_ there's a duplicate question, then the duplicate question suffices.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I don't think so at all. We see this in the JavaScript tag all the time: A person tries something which, say, use a function declaration within a control block, misunderstands async, and fails to handle `this` properly, isn't necessarily too broad. Any of those problems can mask the others. OP says clearly what they're trying to do, has clearly tried to do it, posts relevant code. I don't see closing that in favor of, say, of a canonical async answer, leaving the other issues dangling or relegated to comments which may well get deleted as they're second-class. Linking, yes.

Comment: Yes, provided that the purported canonical question is [not so broad its applicability to the question is not obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130326/unclear-policy-for-duplication-by-inclusion).

Comment: I think I disagree. A question is a duplicate if the core problem of the question is the same. A completely different question can have the same or similar answer, but that does not make it a duplicate question, and in such cases I'd rather see an answer which answers the question and maybe refers to another answer for more context.

Comment: @golez please provide one example where an answer to a different question is a good answer to the first question, but you do not think they should be a duplicate.  I have **never** seen this case, and I have asked for it from others with an opinion similar to yours.

Comment: Well, the questions "8+10" and "90/5" have the same answer. As well as  What should I do when: "My entire PC is infected by Malware", "I've moved everything to my root directory" and "I've deleted my Windows folder" . Kidding aside, I think the fundamental idea is to judge similarity by question, not by answer. If you can find a question that has the same answer, but you cannot see similarity in the question, I think it's wrong to close as duplicate.

Comment: @GolezTrol The question "8+10" and "90/5" are poor SO questions, and should be closed.  I asked for an actual question, and I meant on stack overflow.  You are not the first person to provide joke answers to that challenge.  Even your second set of "serious" questions are off-topic on stack overflow.  Yet nobody I have asked has ever provided an actual SO question pair that satisfies my criteria, yet shouldn't be closed as duplicate.  (I will admit there is the transitive error possibility, but I haven't actually seen it happen).  Please provide an *actual example*.

Comment: True. The second set may be on topic on SuperUser, bot not SO. I've no SO examples *at hand*, but I've seen these situations and I've gone into discussion and voted to re-open such questions. But you're missing the point. In general, if the answer is the same, you should be able to tell that the question is essentially the same too, so in at least (wild guess) 97% of the cases there is no issue and you and I would vote the same. I'm just saying that if the question *is* different, the question should be what you base the vote on, not the answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol *all questions are different*.  The question is, how do we measure "are these two questions the same?".  My (proposed) criteria on SO is clear: if the same answer would be a *good* answer to *both*, then that is how I determine the two questions are essentially the same.  And hence close as duplicate.  Nobody ever seems to be able to find a good convincing counter example.  It is like hunting invisible pink unicorns: people tell me they taste good, but nobody can show me the meat.  You claim there are some questions on SO with a different "core" yet share the same "good answer".

Comment: Your proposed criteria are very clear. I didn't say they are not. I just disagree with them.

Comment: I just found this question:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different . The community-upvoted answer on it is **the very exact opposite of this community-accepted here**. So what?

Answer (score 20):

I see this often in Java questions too; usually the question takes the form of [comparing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) or the user [received a `NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and is entirely lost.

Depending on the context of the question, my options are usually to:

- Close as duplicate, if the essence of the question boils down to a commonly answered question
- Ask for clarification if I'm uncertain that it should be closed as a duplicate, but am looking for more concrete evidence to suggest that it is
- Answer the question if I'm reasonably certain that it's not *just* one of those common problems that is at play here

Close the question as a duplicate if you're fairly confident that the question is an actual duplicate.  Try to tease out what the question actually is by asking for some clarification.  In my opinion, only answer if you're certain that there is more to explain than just, "this question will answer all for you.  Go there."

Comment: "Ask for clarification if I'm uncertain that it should be closed as a duplicate, but am looking for more concrete evidence to suggest that it is" Why not close as duplicate, or as _unclear what you are asking_, and let people vote to reopen if the required clarification is provided?

Comment: In general I agree with this question. Except, if the question contains too little context to tell it apart from the other question, you can close it as duplicate (as described, they seem the same). I think the close message even states that OP can ask a new question and provide more details about why the other answers didn't help, so that seems to be the desired flow.