# Why don't people sign up and contribute?

Tags: discussion, new-users, sign-up

In all the places I've ever worked, Stack Overflow is frequently used by practically every developer there, and they have a positive experience in which they quickly find a good answer to the problem they're facing.

Yet, **I am the only person I personally know who even has an account**.

That's right, *none* of the developers I've worked with (about 100) has ever bothered to even sign up.

Why is that? Why do so many people not consider signing up, let alone contributing?

I suppose I'm wondering why people don't get a little rep (15) to be able to upvote to give a stronger indicator of which answer works plus as a thanks to the posters - to "give back" to the site.

What are we doing wrong, or not doing? Or is this just "the way people are"?

Do other people find the same level of apathy amongst your co-workers?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking why people aren't creating accounts to ask questions, or to interact with questions by commenting/voting/etc., right?  Or are you asking why most people don't become active answers?

Comment: @Servy I suppose I'm asking "why don't they sign up to get enough rep (15) to be able to thank posters by upvoting". Plus, "how about a few answers too now and again to 'put back' what you get".

Comment: *I am the only person I personally know who even has an account.* OK, but an awful lot of people don't use their real name on Stack Exchange sites. That's probably on purpose.

Comment: @BSMP Presumably he asked them if they had accounts, and they said no.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, but that doesn't mean they were being honest. If I had an account on a site I wished to remain anonymous on, I wouldn't tell the people I know in real life that I have an account there. That defeats the purpose of being anonymous.

Comment: I'm not arguing that they *all* have secret SO accounts, for what it's worth.

Comment: @BSMP Most people using pseudonyms online are doing so so that people that they interact with online and don't know in real life won't know who they are, not so that people they know in real life won't know who they are online.  There are exceptions, but the latter is far less common than the former.

Comment: @BSMP I look at their screens when they use SO and they are not logged on. I also ask them, and they say they haven't got accounts. I think that pretty much covers it.

Comment: Because they're no-good, dirty rotten takers who care for nothing except for their own hides.  Well?  You asked me to look into their souls and tell you about all the black stuff inside.  Then again, I might have absolutely no idea why 100 different individuals have not signed up for a website they use occasionally.

Comment: I can personally say that I know someone who's convinced the only questions they'll ever have are ones that'd be off-topic for the site. I asked them for examples and all of them were either recommendation questions or too broad. And they're not confident enough of their abilities that they believe they'd be able to answer anything but trivial questions.

Comment: @Will not "occasionally". average would be daily

Comment: ... The no-good, dirty rotten takers!

Comment: _the latter is far less common than the former_ @Servy - I have no data either way. Was this a question on one of the annual surveys?

Comment: Maybe some people spend their time at work doing their job......   Or rather read books, or help people in the office.

Comment: Do you contribute to Wikipedia?

Comment: I asked some of my co-workers the same question a while ago (none of them have accounts), and their reply was simply that they'd never needed to ask a question. Heck, the only reason I have an account is because I had some spare time two years ago and felt like *answering* some questions.

Comment: @Taw Yes. Although most contributions I've made were reversed (no matter how accurate they were), including reversing the post of a rare photo of someone whose wiki page didn't have a photo at all because although the photo was mine and I said so, I didn't give the correct licence to it, so it was removed. Rather than fix the problem, their moderator was an anal-retentive a@@h@@@, so I don't bother contributing any more.

Comment: @Dave I signed up because I found a solution to a problem that didn't have a question and wanted to publish both. I was cut down because I didn't post them separately (posted answer *in* the question). I still carry a small scar over that rebuke.

Comment: Why buy the cow when you get the milk for free (even ignoring that the SO cow is free)?  If they did sign up and got to 15, its not likely their nature would change.  The number of 3-4-5 year users with double digit questions, 1-2 accepts and **zero** upvotes is staggering.

Comment: That's strange, all the developers at my job have an account.

Comment: I created my account here when I was still in college not to ask a question but to upvote an answer to a problem that is been bugging me for two weeks.... And after that, I show simple courtesy of upvoting every solutions that also helped me.

Comment: @Bohemian: Same here. But it is the same as SO for the vast majority: Its is a __good enough__ source without even bothering to think about contributing __and__ meeting the standards they observe. - I joined SO because I __wanted to upvote__ some neglected answers.

Comment: @Bohemian Why didn't you just ask your colleagues?

Comment: Depends on your motivation. I take part here but I don't think i've ever voted up or commented on a single amazon review despite having read probably thousands of them.  Both are for-profit sites, and i'm always logged into both of them, but this one has a sense of community; I couldn't care less about Amazon.

Comment: Nobody else on my team has an account either... though, they all use the site as a resource. It's a pity they don't contribute in return.

Comment: I once employed a guy who told me in his interview that he had 20k+ rep on SO and I dismissed it as meaningless. Now I'm an avid user of the site I can see what that really means. I used SO all the time but never realised the benefits to others (and to ME) to get involved. Then I figured something out and wanted to share with the world, so I posted an answer, my life has never been the same since :)

Comment: The guy who sits next to me at work is extremely bright, I can see him rake up 200 rep points a day easily. I see him use stackoverflow very often, so I bug him: "Why don't you register and contribute?". His answer is along the lines of "I don't want to get addicted", he is being half joking, but there is some truth to it.

Comment: I started my account because I had a problem that I could not solve on my own. But it took another month until I first up voted, then I wanted to comment and needed some rep for that, so I answered some simple questions. Then I got annoyed that my edits needed to be approved and so I answered some more. But basically: I entered the community because I like teaching, a lot. I learned the rules of SO to be able to teach in this community. My coworkers don't have accounts or rarely use them, if asked they either say: I don't have a question; or I don't bother.

Comment: Not to be terribly negative, but if everyone who thought their questions were too off topic or broad, would actually not make an account and not ask them, the SO community would be a much better place

Comment: @Bohemian: So you've got cut down both on SO and on WP, but why did you carry on here and there not?

Comment: I have the same thing. After spending a couple of years finding answers, I really wanted to contribute. Now I am the only one in the office that can boast of upvoting and less ads!

Comment: @TaW have you ever tried to contribute to wikipedia? You'd have an easier time trying to join the illuminati.

Comment: Yes, I have and __some__ of it still stands.

Comment: I signed up 6 years ago half because I usually sign up to reserve my preferred username, and half because at the time I was into supporting sites that used OpenID. At that time I was a unix sysadmin, who programmed sometimes in the course of my work. SO was useful, somewhat, but I didn't use it often. Fast forward a few years, I am now a full-time developer, and started to find that nearly all of my Google searches brought me here. It just made sense to get involved and try to help curate what has become one of my most valuable resources online.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

> Why do so many people not consider signing up, let alone contributing?

Because most of them *never need to*.  They have no reason to sign up.  They can find the answers to the problems that they have by searching through questions already asked, and never need to ask new ones.

> What are we doing wrong, or not doing?

We're not doing anything wrong.  We're doing something *very right*.  We're creating so much useful and accessible content that most developers never need to create an account to ask questions, they can find everything they need to know by searching through the existing knowledge base.

What are we doing or not doing, that results in people not creating new accounts, we're doing everything possible to make sure that the useful content that is created when a question asked becomes available and easily accessible to everyone else in the entire world, instead of forcing (or encouraging) every single person that has the same problem to ask a new question.

Comment: Hmmm... ya got me there. Your logic is spot on.

Comment: The reason I DID join was that so many of my questions were answered here (Thank you Google), that when I couldn't find an answer anywhere else, this seemed the best place to ask. I think Servy has the right answer. If/when those other developers run into a question and can't find an existing answer, they'll know where to turn to ask.

Comment: I only joined because I needed to ask a question, other than that SO has all the answers I need and even if I want to try to give back I don't have the time or ability to get 15 rep from just looking up answers to question (besides maybe edits, but that's a lot of time for some)

Comment: I actually didn’t sign up for a looong time but frequently got to this site via Google when I needed to solve some of my own problems and I still do. But at some point I did sign up, not because I needed to ask a question, but because at some point I realized that I got to this same “StackOverflow” site _so often_ and I wondered what else this site had to offer, e. g. what this “Questions” link up there was for. Then I discovered that StackOverflow was a huge community and I discovered that _I could also contribute_. So basically, I signed up for _answering_ questions.

Comment: This answer is really spot on. When SO was first available, I was on my Computer Science course, usually having trouble with coding. At that time, I googled the error, and SO came in the result. Without knowing what SO was actually about, I just browsed and tried the code from the answers. Problem fixed, move on.. Long story short, I graduated, and after learning many things from here and there, I felt I could answer some of the questions just for fun (I still didn't really think about "contributing" seriously). Thankfully, the first answer was received well, and I started to contribute more.

Comment: This is spot on.  I was "one of those" users for years, getting answers to questions that had already been asked, no need to have a registered account (or so I thought at the time).  I only recently decided to sign up and start giving back to the community, and I'm glad I did!  Now I can thank other users with an upvote when one of their answers helps me, and I can also help out with the massive task of cleaning up the bad content so that the good content is more visible.

Comment: While I agree with everything else, I don't with *"Because most of them never need to"*. If I find a good answer, I make it a point to log in and upvote, possibly comment, so that somebody else can find the answer as well. **need** should not be limited to being selfish, solving your problem, and not contributing.

Comment: This is a Nice answer, but it assumes contributing to the site can only be done by asking. Contributing is also up and down voting and answering. I know lots of developers who don't to even up vote a great answer that just saved them a full day of work. What about that? Are these people just selfish? Don't they see the impact SO made on their (I dare to say) career and skill?

Comment: @rolf but the random people we help can't upvote right away so I don't blame them. It took me 2 years of using the site before I started to contribute. I just started to answer before I started asking as well

Comment: Also it's very hard to jump in and contribute good content, especially in question form. There's a significant learning curve (you can't ask broad/opinionated/suggestion questions, you have to put all your code in the question itself, you have to use the right tags, you have to ask a question that hasn't been asked here before, etc.).

Comment: @Servy I disagree at some level. I asked one question in all these years where i actually need help and received only one answer. I am sure there are plenty capable and experienced developers with an answer but hasn't signed up yet and would never answer my question. Even if they stumble upon my ques, they won't bother to sign up just to answer my question. So i am not getting enough feedback and they are not signing up.

Comment: Servy, nice answer and agreed to your point but that doesn't stop someone to signup and start answering/offering help to others. If that's so; then whatever we have made will be at loss; I mean if people start thinking like that and very less people starts contributing then over a time no more good answer to the question would be found here. Is this what it should be??? From your answer, I see that's what you are referring.

Comment: To all of the comments above related to answering, the meta question seemed to be referring to why people aren't creating accounts to ask questions, it wasn't asking about people creating accounts to answer, so I considered that out of scope .  SO does do a lot of things to encourage those people who are interested in answering questions online for free to want to come here, but that's really a whole different question, so I didn't go into it here.  It's also worth remembering that it only needs to make up a *very* small percent of SO's user base; most people don't *need* to be answerers.

Comment: To your point "We're creating so much useful and accessible content that most developers never need to create an account to ask questions, they can find everything they need to know by searching through the existing knowledge base." - You are talking about questions properly answered and I am talking about questions which are not. Both are accessible content, mine is just not useful and you can't create duplicate either.

Comment: @Priyank Like I said, my answer is addressing why people aren't creating new accounts to ask questions all the time.  I specifically considered discussions about creating accounts to answer questions out of scope here, as that's just a completely different discussion altogether.

Comment: Exactly. Let's not be another Quora and "require" people to sign up to view answers. (Quoted, because some ad-blocks remove the sign-in overlay.)

Comment: A lot of this has to do with SO getting worse over the years. The karma system is awful, in particular people being able to bully others through insta-downvoting without making any comment. It's a problem that SO has largely through its own system and I have to honestly say, having been a victim of it myself with my own questions meant that I stopped contributing too actively to SO.

Comment: @shevy Voting is one of the most important systems of the site.  It's how people are able to provide feedback on the quality of posts, something so many other sites lack, and the quality of the content suffers greatly.  That you would rather just not know when you're providing unhelpful content might make you feel better, but it would make the site worse.

Answer (score 79):

Signing up for an account and then contributing also means **you need to put yourself out there**, and risk saying something stupid/wrong - or asking a dumb question and ending up on the programming humor subreddit ;)

Most people I know are pretty scared of being publicly embarrassed or one-upped. @Servy is right that because Stack Overflow works so well at giving great answers to most users, there's little reward to compensate people for the social risk of exposure/humiliation that inherently accompanies contributions.

Comment: Although you can be quite anonymous on SO. You can even change your display name and effectively change your identity if you wish!

Comment: That's true. In that case the apathy explanation does make more sense.

Comment: Notwithstanding the potential for anonymity, in psychological terms it's still pretty easy to feel exposed to the potential of ridicule, especially as a new user. I suspect most high-rep users forget what it was like to answer their first question, and breathe a sigh of relief when an upvote came in `:-)`.

Comment: While I understand your concerns I would like to point out that these risks are attributable to virtually any public activity.  At the beginning downvotes are usually taken quite personal, after a while you understand that this is a part of the game.  And it's a game indeed. You race to give a correct answer first.  So people come here to get an answer and then become entangled into reputation race.  In my case, rep stopped matter after 3K threshold. Now, sometimes, I rather leave a comment with a hint then go for a full-blown answer.

Comment: @katie - Also your "see our work" button on the dune8 page doesnt work:  http://dune8.com/#see-work it redirects you to the current page!  It should be going to http://dune8.com/#our-work not `see-work`.  This is quite embarrassing I should place it on reddit :-p

Comment: @JonH yikes - really embarrassing. I deserve to be on that reddit now ;)  Appreciate the note!

Comment: @JonH: Ah, reddit. Where dignity goes to die.

Comment: Being scared to contribute by asking questions (for whatever reason) is a real thing. I have over 30k in rep but I know at least twice I had a question to ask that I felt really shameful for not knowing (& didn't want to taint my rep)... and so I created anonymous accounts to ask a question.

Comment: @halfer That's how it was for me, when I put something out there, I feel like it's a representation of some part of me because I thought it up and crafted the question and answer. Even if I have no idea who these people are and their comments have no tangible effect on me in any way possible, it still affects me to see that product of my mind ridiculed. Even though I just walk it off and move forward because of my upbeat personality, I can understand why to a lot of people that would be a deterrent to contribute.

Comment: I recently reflected on how negative feedback to my answers on SO, along with other participation and positive feedback, has helped me as a developer. Getting downvoted stings. So does being told you're wrong. But it's worth it. SO participation has helped me to grow and learn.

Answer (score 71):

I wouldn't call it apathy, necessarily.

> It's a problem of motivation, all right? Now if I work my ass off and Initech ships a few extra units, I don't see another dime, so where's the motivation? And here's something else, Bob: I have eight different bosses right now...

Oops... Sorry.  Got carried away there.

Anyway, here's how it breaks down...

The vast majority of people visiting Stack Overflow are there to find an answer to their problem.  This might actually account for 90 to 99 percent of all traffic.  Of the remaining traffic (in progressively smaller percentages):

1. Some will ask a question without reading the Help Center, conclude we're just a bunch of grouchy in-types, and leave.
2. Some will ask a good question.
3. Some will contribute answers.

Those who contribute answers have both *expert knowledge and the desire to contribute.*  There's a sweet spot between not knowing enough to contribute and being an expert in the field who is presumably too busy (or otherwise unmotivated) to contribute.   The percentage of such people in that sweet spot is quite small, and the percentage of such people who contribute substantially is disproportionately smaller than that.

If you look at the user accounts on Stack Overflow (half of them are rep 1), you should find that the level of participation at your workplace pretty much follows the same pattern (you might find one person in a workplace of 100 that is an active participant), for the same reasons that not everyone is a plumber or electrician, and not every plumber and electrician has a blog.

Comment: You mention the sweet spot between novice and expert. I think another limitation of too much expertise is that the questions and opinions an expert has on a topic will be too highly specific to be useful to most people. This makes the tool good for learning a technology, but not necessarily discussing it.

Comment: @Elisa James Lu signed up just 25 days ago. It looks to me like he's doing well for himself!

Comment: @ 1. but you are a bunch of grouchy in-types. Even if you read the help section and every post that was ever written about wrting good questions. You still can end up with your questions beeing heavily downvoted/closed without any feedback or any feedback that makes sense. First few questions I asked were closed with quotes from the help section, the same lines that I read and thought, "ok my question seems to be ontopic". The help section is often horribly ambigous and every sentence can mean 2 different things depending in who reads it. SO is very greedy when it comes to feedback.

Comment: SO can be compared in hostility to 4chan. And on 4chan users don't have the power to close questions or ban other users, so in some sense, SO is even more hostile. On 4chan people can only insult you, on SO people can close your questions and get you banned without even having to talk to you.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: It's not that hard to figure out what Stack Overflow is about and participate in a way that fulfills that.  People who do that seldom have any trouble with the in-types.

Comment: The more I contribute, the more I feel that SO is in fact made up of a bunch of grouchy in-types that actively discourage new contributors.

Comment: In my experience, SO does in fact seem like a den of *extremely* grouchy in-types to new contributors, perhaps even more than Wikipedia at times. I've seen a number of new, perfectly legitimate and focused questions by new users be closed as duplicate by someone who clearly didn't read or understand the question, referencing other questions which were different. By contrast downvotes/upvotes always seemed fair. The fact that they require a mass of people to agree rather than one authority figure who already has shown a propensity for the game-ified aspect of SO.

Answer (score 68):

I'm going to take the opposite stance of [Servy's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297528/1079354).  It reflects conversations I've had with close colleagues and coworkers when I bring up Stack Overflow.

> Why do so many people not consider signing up, let alone contributing?

Most people don't consider signing up because *they're terrified to.*  They have no willpower to sign up; although their question is not answered or they don't know of any other place to find an answer to their question, they are absolutely terrified of falling foul of the community.  [They've seen what happens to those poor, misguided souls that do dare to ask a question here that isn't up to snuff.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1079354)

As sad as it was, a friend of mine remarked that Stack Overflow has done a job of teaching developers not to ask questions on it.  This may be due to the sheer volume of questions previously answered, or the tendency of the community to react as if someone put pineapple and sauerkraut on their pizza if a similar question is asked.

They've got a point, though; a lot of developers that I know who have good questions are just really afraid of breaking any unforeseen taboo or violating any policy that may be present when others are monitoring the site.  I've had a few people swear off the site because of the needless wave of, "What have you tried", or the senseless negativity because they didn't understand the predicament they were actually in.

Those were the people trying to get help, and they thought that struggling through their problem would be better than asking.

I hope to see some more of my friends and coworkers contribute to the site, but their fears are that what they know isn't applicable to the site as a whole, or is too archaic.  I have a friend that has worked exclusively with Perl and FORTRAN for quite some time, and he's afraid that if he were to contribute here, his contributions wouldn't be valued so highly.  I'm working with them on that; it's likely a confidence/typing/eloquence issue more than a community one, but I hope they can contribute here some day.

I'll throw in my perspective.  I'm not keen on asking a question here myself.  Call me jaded, but it's either been asked here before, or I haven't expressed myself eloquently enough to get an answer or any acknowledgment of why I might be confused.  This is why I ask so few questions; I *know* how some of those may be received.

> What are we doing wrong, or not doing?

I can't really answer that.  Rather, I'm not sure if I should be answering that, since it's a problem that's a lot deeper than a few twiddles of a knob can address.

It boils down to molding a contributor into something ideal.  The problem is, I'd say, no one has really defined what that ideal contributor *is* yet. Is it someone that does their research?  Yes, absolutely.  Is it someone that expressed themselves clearly?  Sure.  Are both of those things still subjective enough?  Yes, since "research" and "clarity" are evaluated on a case-by-case basis, and not by the same people all the time.  Some are more lenient, and other are more strict.  No one has a good barometer for this.

A lot of my stance when helping these guys out has been to look at things carefully and objectively, and not to make the same mistakes as people who I often downvote/close.  This has helped, but I'm not confident that the community is tolerant of a few mistakes.  This can sap a new user's confidence straight away; if they're going to be penalized for a few mistakes, why would they **bother** if they can keep hitting Google for other resources?

Comment: Should new members be given a (high rep) "coach" for a week, who they can chat with and who can help draft their questions/answers? Like when you get an older kid assigned as your "bug buddy" (or whatever they call it) when they start school.

Comment: I like the idea, and I've been filling that role with the close group of friends/coworkers I have whenever they want to post here.  The problem with it in general is that it assumes that the high-rep person and the user both have the time to meet up, and that the high-rep user has the area of expertise that the user is looking to get guidance in.  Notwithstanding that a high-rep user can easily point out common SO pitfalls, if the user is looking for help in something very complex, tricky or esoteric, it's tough to say that "Jon Skeet" would be the best candidate to help them out.

Comment: That's not to say that it wouldn't be helpful, though.  Someone giving a question a once-over to be sure that it could be objectively answered *would* help.

Comment: "they are absolutely terrified of falling fowl of the community" Falling _fowl_? You mean they're chicken? :)

Comment: I find this answer much better than the accepted one. It's probably not the end all, be all of the whole issue, but it addresses a *real problem* we have on this site: the constant tension between pushing users for high quality content and responding to low quality too harshly. @Bohemian Wasn't that what the whole dead idea of [Stack Overflow Academy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring) was?

Comment: // , Unfortunately, there is a downside to making knowledge into a competition. Certain hierarchies based on positive feedback loops get set up of the sort that make the technical field so annoying in general. There is a place for Quiz Bowl, and there is a place for actually helping people. They are *supposed to be separate places.*

Comment: // ,  A stack exchange, or any forum, really, that falls prey to this sort of dynamic may become another of the many parts of our culture of an audience of many and performance of the few.

Comment: @jpmc26 this is my 2nd favorite answer. The accepted one does answer the question (ie there is no problem - it's an expected outcome if the site is working well). However, this answer best answers what drove me to ask the question - ie my suspicion that we are neither "welcoming" to, nor tolerant of innocent blunders made by, new users. I suspect it's exacerbated by the sheer volume of flags (2K+ per day) in the SO flag queue that leads to an Attila the Hun "non-nonsense" approach to out-of-line posts (just kill the post and move on to the next flag), which wounds many a new OP

Comment: I have anecdotal experience of a good programmer who believes that the Stack Overflow community is fierce and arrogant. I think he's wrong, and that he should give it another go, but since it _is_ the reason why he's not signed up and contributing, I guess we should listen to stories of this kind. I still think the atmosphere (in the tags I frequent) is mostly fine, and pushing for good quality content is a laudable aim. Maybe the mentoring/pairing thing would help here?

Comment: I just had to point out that this sentence"..Those were the people trying to get help, and they thought that struggling through their problem would be better than asking." is important. One should work in the question before asking for more help if they don't they are loosing other's time, here or in their companies/ teammates.

Comment: @Bohemian I love the idea you had in the first comment, though, i fear there aren't enough "high rep" users to go around. Much less ones willing to help in that way.

Comment: @KevinB you're right about not enough high reppers. [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/328703) (that I just wrote) shows just how the numbers thin out as rep climbs

Comment: @Bohemian From [your comment to jpcm26](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297527/why-dont-people-sign-up-and-contribute#comment210125_297558) I wonder, if _this answer best answer what drove me to ask the question_, why doesn't become the accepted answer?

Comment: @Bohemian I really like the coach for new users idea.  Maybe I was just lucky, but I actually made a tremendous "innocent blunder" when I first created an account here (edited a question to become an entirely new one), and I was very graciously and gently guided in the right direction (Thanks NJones).  Even though I was frustrated in the beginning by the barriers to entry (i.e. needing 15 rep to upvote), I understood that this type of noise reduction is crucial to maintaining high quality content.  SO's model has proven to be superior; kindness must be a matter of personal responsibility.

Comment: Yup, this answer is consistent with what I've observed in real life.  They're terrified of being pounced on and shamed in public.  And I've also heard "SO's arrogant and petty."  I have to admit, when I see the 100th meta question asking something like "should we punish users for (insert innocent action)?" and then it gets 198 upvotes from keen Overflowers, smugly pointing out that SO is the highest quality resource on the internet -  I just groan to myself.

Comment: @BlasSoriano I assume the reason Bohemian accepted the other answer to the question because it actually answers the question. It is frequently the case when intended question and actual question as written don't end up being the same - most people will simply say "these #### can't even understand simple question I *wanted* to ask" and downvote everything, some actually accept the fact that question turned out to be different from the goal and accept/ask new question.

Comment: I agree more with this answer than the accepted. Personally, I was nervous about setting up a StackOverflow account despite having used other code sites before and working in the industry for a while. For other students, including Graduate level, the fear of reprisal because they just don't know has been given as why they don't sign up. I will say that a few of them who signed up have found SO to not be "so scary" due to Chat - where active members (of all levels) really seem to act as "mentors" who guide and help (according to them/also what I've seen).

Comment: I get the same sort of feedback from some of my friends. Being mostly an answerer myself, I find that most of the things with which I could get some help are in areas I know less, typically for which I'm unsure about the terminology. I often end up finding better places to get answers to my question (e.g. project forums, which are typically a bit less judgemental or often know much better about how their own project works anyway). I would also once in a while have questions that are at the fringe of development and sysadmin (e.g. is what I'm doing making any sense in terms of deployment).

Comment: Building on some of the comments here... what if we had a review queue for first-timers that permitted private feedback before a question went live? No formal mentor/mentee pairing, but the opportunity for the new user to receive help wrt community standards for questions without the public shaming?

Comment: @Mogsdad:  It'd be yet another queue that barely anyone does anything with.  It's also been suggested a dozen times and has received much disdain from the community, myself included.  The reason:  if you offer a badge, the people will only work for the badge.  If you don't offer any incentives, they'll think it's a chore and not bother with it.

Comment: Ok - so how would you propose we go about _giving a question a once-over to be sure that it could be objectively answered_, given that as soon as a question has been asked it's being looked at by not just the part of the community that wants to encourage new users to ask better questions, but by the part that would rather poke them with a sharp stick?

Comment: @Mogsdad:  I've had some time to think on it, and I think that it boils down to the sheer size of Stack Overflow.  Perhaps if it were broken up a bit more, this sort of issue may become less of an issue than it is today.  I didn't get much further than that, though, since breaking things up would involve a lot of logistics.

Comment: Thinking along the same lines as @Mogsdad, maybe people's first question could be anonymous by default?  And maybe, there could be a button, Please give me written feedback about this question?  i.e. only keen/frustrated/puzzled newbies would click on it.  This would just formalise the process by which newbies sometimes end up on meta asking why their question got panned.

Comment: @SList We have _userX_ accounts already, so most users are already anonymous, and that doesn't free them from having a negative experience. The idea of a voluntary hold-for-review is interesting. Same concerns that Makato brought up, though: the review would only be valuable if it was done with the "right" motivation.

Comment: @mogsdad, I've used the anon accounts for sensitive questions but they are a pain - you have to create a separate a/c, and then you get nagged to complete it, and you stay automatically logged into it. I'm sure all these things are easy to fix if you know how, but most people aren't that interested.  I didn't mean hold-for-review, actually, I meant something much looser, that someone could just ask for feedback at any point.

Answer (score 38):

I have the same experience (only account around me), and for a long time didn't have an account myself.

The problem? **There was no value to having an account**. I suspect this is the primary issue for most people, and worst of all, it affects the very users we want to attract the most. To start with, there were two reasons I made my account:

1. I had a question.
2. I wanted to comment on other peoples questions (partially because I didn't "get" the whole system yet).

This affects us getting valuable users (the "experts") because they are *really good* at research, and so don't ever need to ask a question. We are victims of our own success here, we are *so good* at curating knowledge that they can find it! Which was the point, but it makes an account far less valuable.

As to the second motivation, you have to want to participate in the site for it to be a motivating factor. Most don't, they just want their answers (again, this is disproportionately true for expert users).

Can we fix it? I don't see any way to under the current system.

Comment: It would be interesting to see some data on whether reasonably high rep accounts (maybe 1000+? 500+?) first posted a question or an answer. I know for my case, I actually happened across a question I felt I could post an answer of value first, and it would be interesting to know which case is more common.

Comment: @jpmc26 No overall statistic of course, but I remember opening an account and answering questions because I wanted to ask a question and have a feel of what it was like to be on the other side before doing so. That said, my first question was not great at all.

Answer (score 23):

There's a stigma surrounding 'signing up' for something, mostly due to how *horribly* nuts other sites unnecessarily complicate the process. I *seldom* sign up for things these days even when I stand to gain something by doing so, because the site fails to convince me that I won't *lose* anything like:

- My privacy
- My time, in figuring out how to unsubscribe from the dozen junk emails they're just *waiting* to send me

Even now that I've grown quite fond of just using Google or Twitter to register, the process of figuring out what I'm actually allowing something I just met to do with those services is *usually* sufficient for me to pass on registration.

People don't know we're not evil because all the evil sites run around saying (wait for it) .. *WE'RE NOT EVIL!*

It then becomes a question of:

- Convince the user that they have nothing to *lose*
- Entice the user by showing them what they can *gain*.

*Come, join us, help us accomplish small units of work in order to make life better for every developer in the world* **does** go a long way, but that makes the assumption that everyone has that kind of time. You hit the site, you find your answer, and you go back to furiously fiddling with things in your editor to the tune of that grinding sound of a deadline drowning out everything else.

The way to get *more* is to do more stuff that encourages long-term orientation starting at the first interaction (which is a page view by someone we don't know). Then you have to figure out how to not be annoying as you do that.

We've got some folks set to tackle that problem, and more when it comes to the experience that new users have in general - that's going to be the only thing they care about for quite a while. I'm *really* excited about it, because it's a very interesting *and* difficult problem to chew on.

Well, it's not *really* a problem in a practical sense, but we feel like we should be doing much better in that area, so that's what we're endeavoring to do.

Comment: Well, as [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/328703) shows, 60% of users never post (have rep 1), so a lot sign up without needing to - that's good. It also shows over 90% have rep < 100 - again good, because a lot signed up without need to post *much*. You may be able to provide stats of how many unique visitors sign up - I suspect it's of the order of 1%

Comment: having 1 rep could also mean they made a post, got downvoted, and decided not to try again, right?

Comment: // , Or that they read this bit about stackoverflow's creeping authoritarianism and lack of humor: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow#section-9

Answer (score 19):

I can't log in at work as my network access to Google login is blocked. I can get Stack Overflow though, so during my workday it's read-only.

Also as a relative newcomer it can be quite difficult to not get a shed ton of negative reputation points for asking a duplicate question or making a simple mistake. There is a high tendency to bite the newcomers as Wikipedia phrases it.

Comment: You don't *need* to use a Google login. You have several to pick from.

Comment: My account is linked through Google though, why would I sign up twice?

Comment: @CarlSixsmith You don't have to sign up twice. You can actually add multiple login methods to your single account. Just go to your settings on your profile, then to the My Logins option to add a new one. For instance, I have two methods: Yahoo, and the Stack Exchange Open Id

Comment: @CarlSixsmith You can have **multiple** logins to the **same account**. Profile -> Settings -> My Logins -> Add more logins... Perhaps the other login types are not blocked at work?

Comment: @DavidPostill see, this sort of info should be more visible. I've been read only at work for 18 months doh!

Comment: See what I mean? A -1 for no real reason. Lets drive the the newbies away.

Comment: Why do you assume it happens for no real reason?

Comment: Because the person that did it hasn't bothered to admit it. Imagine you're a new person to the site, and all of a sudden you're told your contributions are neither valued nor welcome.

Comment: A site I frequent regularly does a "Tips & Tricks" type of posting on site features. Maybe that would be a good idea for Stack Exchange.

Comment: I've been using stack overflow for years on and off. And only recently found out there was a meta site. People are expected to know the etiquette and foibles of the site without it being made clear. This can be intimidating and off putting.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Actually, people are expected to take the [tour] then read the [help] and learn the etiquette of the site through that. Since the help center mentions Meta, they can also come here after reading that and read through posts here to learn more.

Comment: What's the tour? Again not advertised and you're not directed to it when you sign up. Ask a question is in big bold font on the front page, just seen the little tour link above it. Very easy to miss.

Comment: I see a big, orange button that says "Take the Tour" when I go to an SE site I don't have an account on. Do you not see that? Try something like http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BSMP on stack overflow main site (well maybe not the main site but the developer one i use, I've just found tour under the help menu, on scifi stack overflow it's a menu bar at the top, but still very easy to miss. https://stackoverflow.com vs http://scifi.stackexchange.com it seems the tour becomes a distinct menu item after you log on

Comment: You're already a member at SciFi. There's a big banner at the top of SE sites where you don't have an account that contains a big button for the tour.

Comment: Not from what I can see, if I log off, no button.

Comment: Are you saying you've dismissed the tour banner on all 130+ SE sites? You can dismiss the banner without being logged in, that's why logging out doesn't make it reappear.

Comment: It seems there's a cookie issue here, if I log off I don't see take tour button, if I open private browser window it's there. But I've never dismissed a take a tour panel, as it would have been extremely useful.

Comment: @Carl: You've been a member for over 3 years, the tour might not have been thrown in your face in quite the same way, way back then.

Comment: meta is for discussion.  A downvote doesn't necessarily mean "your contributions are neither valued nor welcome".  It primarily means "I disagree."  Do with that what you will.  Presumably, somewhere, somehow, we're allowed to have discussions where not everyone agrees with your opinion.  On SO (not meta) perhaps a downvote is a little closer to "your contributions are neither valued nor welcome", but I would suggest it still means something else: "not useful, unclear, etc.".  It's part of a feedback mechanism to improve content, and signal bad content. SO is not a free-for-all.

Comment: _if I open private browser window it's there_ - Was that really easier than going to an SE site where you don't have an account?

Comment: @BSMP The tour pages for other SE sites do not apply to SO. In particular, the "what to ask" and "what not to ask". It's important for SO users to land on SO's tour page, not some other site's.

Comment: @BSMP as I wanted to see the pages on sites I am a member of, I.e. The ones I have used and never seen the tour link, yes it was.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - You said, _you're not directed to it **when you sign up**_ and I said, _I see a big, orange button...when I go to an SE site **I don't have an account on**_. You said new users aren't directed to the tour, I pointed out that they are.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - I never suggested that SO users should have to go to another site to see the tour.

Comment: @BenVoigt The content of the Tour/FAQ has also changed over the past few years. As a regular member, you can't be expected to keep track of every quarrel / new ban that's discussed on Meta.

Comment: Can we ask why Google is blocked at your workplace? I get why some companies block Facebook, Twitter, YouTube etc. however if you have Internet access it seems odd (to me) that Google is blocked - just curious... I think for me these days this would be a bit of a deal breaker for me as I use Google daily to get my job done.

Comment: @scunliffe I've no idea.

Comment: // , Wikipedia has the same problem with a creeping authoritarianism and lack of humor that StackExchange sites have: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow#section-9

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion, skilled developers don't sign up because they already get a lot of benefit out of Stack Overflow, and they don't think the **reward/effort** ratio is high enough to contribute.

## Rewards are different and better than what lurkers think

Before I was a contributor to Stack Overflow, I thought the rewards would be:

- Showing off my skills and perhaps getting a job. This never actually happened.

In reality, these are the **purely selfish rewards** that I got that I did not anticipate:

- **I have posted questions, and I have had them answered**. This is by far the biggest benefit, and you need 0 reputation points to begin doing it.
- Several times, I have used my favourite search engine to look for an answer to a question, only to find that **I had already answered it** on Stack Overflow. It turns out, making notes in public where Google can search it comes back to reward me in the future. Answering requires 0 reputation points, so you can start investing in this immediately.
- Similarly, I have come across **answers that I have already upvoted**. This saves me the trouble of re-reading all the answers if I know which one I found best last time. You only need 200 reputation points before you can upvote questions everywhere, even on Stack Exchange sites other than Stack Overflow.
- Again similarly, I have come **my own comments that turned out to be useful to me later on**. Again, you only need 200 reputation points before being able to do this on all sites.
- **My wrong answers get corrected**, for free.
- **My mediocre answers get improved**, for free.

Basically, Stack Overflow is like my personal list of notes about technology I'm learning, except Google can search these notes, and I have a huge community helping me to improve them.

## Effort is not as high as lurkers think

The reputation system makes the bar look a lot higher than it is. In reality, **you only need 200 reputation points** before unlocking 100% of the useful privileges on all Stack Exchange sites. You don't need to compete with the top 1%.

Here's how to get to 200 rep: just post questions that are selfishly useful, and post answers that are selfishly useful. In a few months, you'll have gathered 20 upvotes, and since you're only posting selfishly, you'll be reaping benefits even before that point. Be pragmatic and don't join the race unless you find it fun.

Comment: The last part of your answer is interesting. The 200 rep boundary you point out is effectively the limit between "user-oriented" privileges (vote, leave comments, set bounties, etc.) and the "community-oriented" ones (review, tag, close, delete, etc.). That you deem the first category "useful" but not the second meshes with your "selfishly useful" and "for free" concepts, and leaves the impression you're only here to take, not to give. (These are just my two cents, of course.)

Comment: @Flimm - good question!  according to the rules on this site, you should know why it's being downvoted, or you should go read the help center to find out.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - To be fair, Flimm is addressing people with little to no rep and the privileges <= 200 rep are the ones that people complain about not having access to most often.

Comment: Would we make SO a better place by making the privileges that appear at that 200 point threshold easier to obtain? Or worse? Purely subjective question, I realize. Still, if one was to ask + answer "selfishly useful" questions that survived the community's oversight, would that not be an improvement over non-participation?

Comment: @Mogsdad: I don't think we should change the 200 point threshold, rather I think we should explain and advertise posting in SO for its selfish benefits.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi So we don't want users who don't use their moderation privileges? Well, there goes 90% of active users who have them, the selfish takers. The OP was about the threshold between reading SO and participating on it, not participating and moderating. To be honest, I don't care about the latter and don't know what point you were trying to make (if not simply throwing shade). I think the point made here is that, even before one considers altruistic motives, there's a lot to be gained from participating (and this is not well enough known). Teaching is a good way of learning, etc.

Comment: @Frank, I honestly wonder where you read that in my comment. I was trying to explain a downvote, not deciding who we "want" and who we don't.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah, ok. I just see a rambling comment that starts with "interesting" and ends with [paraphrasing] "I reckon you're here to take, not to give" (where giving means using "community-oriented" tools). That conclusion makes no sense to me as a reason to downvote (like "down with takers!"?), but of course no explanation for a downvote is needed.

Comment: @Frank, I see, so e.g. *leaves the impression* or *my two cents* did not soften anything after all. I'll remember that in the future.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Heh, yeah, for me "leaves the impression" does not. It just makes it look like you're stating your opinion but trying to disassociate yourself from it. Also, reclaiming the opinion as your "two cents" undermined the disassociation a little for me. Finally [editing in], "you're only here to take" looks awfully ad hominem.

Answer (score 12):

**Why don't people sign up and contribute?**

Short answer:

As [Servy said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297528/4904830), "Because most of them never need to."

Long answer (check TL;DR at the end): 
First we need to find out what people cannot do without registering. We could just see [Why should I create an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register), or ask ourselves:

Why people would like to sign up?

- To ask new questions
- To give new answers
- To give thanks for an useful answer (by voting)
- To add suggestions on answers (by commenting or suggesting edits)

The first two cases could be expected later, when people would like to feel more involved in the community. The last two cases are, in my opinion, more suitable for newcomers at first.

Then we need to find out how easy it is to do those things after signing up:

- To ask new questions or give new answers, it is needed just to sign in, so 1 reputation point is enough to [create posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts).
- To give thanks for an useful answer (by voting), 15 reputation points are needed to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
- To add suggestions on answers an user could:

  - Suggest an edit, 1 reputation is enough in [our model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), but it requires much more effort to do it well enough to avoid rejections than just a comment.
  - Add a comment, allowed since 50 reputation points to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

I know why the system is currently this way. I'm not questioning if it is OK so or if it should be another way.

Now, we should think about this model: if the advantages of the current system compensates the amount of people not signing up, then the answer could be:

Q- Why don't people sign up and contribute? 
A- [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Otherwise, we could think about the body of your question.

---

**I am the only person I personally know who even has an account.
Why is that? Why do so many people not consider signing up, let alone contributing?**

Me too. So I asked some people around me (all them working as programmers), and got 13 answers:

1 - I don't bother, my time is precious. 
4 - I don't feel myself confident enough to ask/answer in English. 
8 - I scare of being ashamed if somebody search and find me with low reputation or even worse if I make a big mistake.

I ask myself: Did I scare to participate even if I was using Stack Overflow for long to get answers?

My answer is: Yes, I love user-content driven sites, but also I refrained to participate due to the possibility of being ashamed by my workmates/friends if I failed to do the right things at the start; the reputation system was the main reason, in the same way as I almost do not use any social network: everything you write (in public) is kept forever (for glory or shame).

That also gives me some clues to answer now your last question:

**Q- Do other people find the same level of apathy amongst your co-workers?** 
A- I find the same level of refraining, but I think it is not apathy.

---

**What are we doing wrong, or not doing? Or is this just "the way people are"?**
I would add: Could something different be done to encourage more participation?

First, we need to know a bit about how this site is working now, by studying the participation levels. I'm searching for a recent answer in meta with graphics and data on the subject, but I cannot find it now. I'll retry later, but for now this is what I remind: most users keep with 1 reputation forever, and a very low amount of users contributes a lot.

This phenomenon is known as participation inequality, with just very low amount of users accounting for most the action while a very high amount of users never or rarely contribute.

There are a lot of articles about the subject, but I would like to chose an old article by Jacob Nielsen, *[The 90-9-1 Rule for Participation Inequality in Social Media and Online Communities](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/participation-inequality/)*.

In the last paragraph *How to Overcome Participation Inequality*, he answer *You can't*, but I find useful the choice about how you shape the inequality curve's angle.

- Make it easier to contribute.
- Make participation a side effect.
- Encourage more to improve (editing) over creating.
- Rethink the reputation system.
- Make it easier to contribute.
  An unregistered user already gets a good popup when trying to [upvote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndijW.png) or [comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAWBz.png).
  There could be added a link to [Why should I create an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register), or even the full text (it is short).
  Also maybe something like *[How to Say Thanks in an Answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/)* should be clear enough for newcomers. And it could be easy to oversee that [you can post answers being unregistered and hard to understand why not ask for clarification on existing answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNO2o.png)
  If it is a registered user asking a question, a better template could be handy. See *[Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting)*.
  For an already experienced user, make it easier to [find interesting questions to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253683/295117), (not everybody handles the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) well).
- Encourage to improve (editing) over creating.
  I know in our model it is encouraged to edit (see *[What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)*), and we already have got some good improvements to avoid duplicated questions, like [this popup when asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWzkg.png), but there is still some room for improvements. I mean to improve the usability of canonical questions: [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).
  Duplicates and related questions should easily find a place in canonical questions, but I find difficult to learn about that feature on Stack Overflow. Related: *[How to handle questions whose root cause is an already well-answered issue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297422/how-to-handle-questions-whose-root-cause-is-an-already-well-answered-issue)*.
- Rethink the reputation system.
  Besides the possible effect of potential users refraining to sign up, I think a more complex reputation system is needed, not just as it is now. I think the current reputation system is not too bad, but it is far from perfect. But this could be a subject for another debate (too broad to include it here). However, I want to include at least two thoughts. Once burned, twice shy. If the system has treated you poorly (even if you deserved it), then why should you help? I find Makoto's suggestion interesting: [Question Forgiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/259077/edit) and *[Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)*.
  Even with some high reputation some users have a feeling on the system encouraging to game it. See Michael Richter's article on gaming Stack Overflow's reputation: *[Why I no longer contribute to Stack Overflow?](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow)*
- Participation can also be a side effect. There are a lot ways to achieve this, and there are some interesting suggestions on meta.
  [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice). RSS makes it easy to follow a few, not a bunch; however for now [Stack Overflow is not a social network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122136/295117).
  Related could be [Show off the posts I'm most proud of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253687/295117), or another suggestion I cannot find now about high reputation points users allowed to show others (mark) interesting questions and answers. I would add: Users should be able to recommend other similar/related questions that also helped them for this question. These links' visibility should be prominent.
  But again, I'm not trying here to debate on new features; just thinking loud about what could be done.

---

**TL;DR**

All this wall of text is a non-sense. The answer to this question is [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).
If you prefer a more <s>serious</s> specific answer, chose one of these two answers:

Q- Why don't people sign up and contribute? 
A1- [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) 
A2- The advantages of the current system do not compensate the amount of people not signing up.

Comment: // , Have you had a chance to read Michael Richter's bit on Stackoverflow's creeping authoritarianism and lack of humor? 

It's a bit from someone who came to some of the same conclusions about StackOverflow as Makoto had: 

http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow#section-9

Comment: Yes, I've found it interesting, and that's why I linked it. Have you gone directly to the TL;DR part on my answer?  :-)

Comment: // , <.< 

DON'T JUDGE ME.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think Stack Overflow is doing anything particularly "wrong." Nothing is perfect and I'm sure there are improvements that may foster more participation. However, there are some fundamental points that I think might possibly perchance in some conceivable way be influencing a developer's decision on whether or not to sign-up.

- **Developers are inherently antisocial**. I was discussing this with a colleague just the other day. Most developers I know (and I know several hundred) are very picky about who they talk with and socialize with. They like hanging out with friends, but they *don't* like the idea of communicating with people they don't know. My theory is that it's a conditioned response from having grown up thinking in first-order boolean logic. It makes us hard to relate to for most people. "But that's not what you said," should probably be carved on every developers' headstone from constantly picking apart the ambiguous statements everyone else constantly uses to communicate with.
- **Developers value their time more than [McMillon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_McMillon) values money.** At work, we're pressed for time in a big way. At home, we typically are tinkerers -- always wanting to create some program, robot or death ray. Or we want to challenge our brains with the latest video game. Something, anything, other than signing up to tell people over and over, "Post your code and then tell us what you are really trying to do." It's not that developers don't want to be helpful -- we do. We just don't want to feel like we're wasting our time on morons when we could be doing something far more interesting like solving the world's energy crisis, or helping others forget their worthless existence by making the next [Angry Birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angry_Birds).

I realize these are generalizations. But based on my experience, they hold true for most (not all) developers.

Comment: // , Often the sort of developers who, as you say, have a life outside of StackOverflow are much better than the humorless authoritarians who *want* to lecture at "morons": http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow#section-9

EXCELLENT ANSWER.

Answer (score 9):

Just an example to confirm Servy's answer. I had used Stack Overflow for a long time just as a reader without an account. Because I used Google as the primary source of information, and soon found that Wikipedia and Stack Overflow both contained high-quality articles, Stack Overflow was being my reference as a Q&A site.

And one day, the proposed solution was not enough for my requirements (was about [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit)). After digging in reference material and days of tries, I found a solution that was better for me. As I thought it could be useful for others, I decided to create an account and post it. Then, as I had received a lot of help from Stack Overflow, and as I had an account, I then begun give back help to other Stack Overflow users by answering questions. But without that first post on a detailed problem on Dojo Toolkit, I should not have an account today.

Answer (score 7):

You specifically mention the workplace in your question.

> Plus, "how about a few answers too now and again to 'put back' what you get"

I'd like to point out that getting the information that you need to do your job is what you get paid for. On the contrary, helping others with their problems outside the company is **not** what you get paid for.

If you are planning to spend some time answering questions during work time, you should talk to your boss about it. It's good to be able to justify why you want to spend time on solving other people's problems outside the company during your work time. One solution could be to create an "official" account, associated with the company and write off a certain amount of work hours as support answering questions on Stack Overflow or the Internet in general. I have seen it a few times when people complain about a product in forums and the next post is from an employee from the manufacturer of that product, providing support and contact information to solve the problem. This can have the effect of people thinking more positively about the company, because your support reaches out and tries to solve problems, even if not explicitly asked for. (Of course you could fake this, too.)

If you cannot come up with a reason, your boss might be inclined to ask why you are not using other resources to solve your problem, that do not demand you to "put back" anything.

---

Personally, I created an account (not this one) for work, but I am only asking questions there and am not answering other questions. I did this because I was under the impression that you have to provide an email address anyway, even as a guest user. I decided to create a regular account, which I can justify as it helps me getting answers to my questions, whereas I could not justify answering other questions.

Comment: Do you plan to re-assign your work SO account to your boss when you leave his or her employ? If not, maybe you should just have one account, and limit your leisure usage of Stack Overflow to a reasonable level. (I'd say an account that shows you are willing to help as well as take it gives a better view of you as a user/contributor).

Comment: @halfer no. And I don't think that I should. There is no value in that account, it's like one you have to create to download drivers/documentation/whatever. There is not value in those accounts. They (including the one on SO) are only created to gain or simplify access to stuff that I need at work.

Comment: That's interesting, but I think maybe doesn't answer the broad point I was making. I guess I don't see sufficient justification for operating two accounts, and I do see plenty of justification for operating one: namely that people will see you all a contributing member, and not someone who (inadvertently) appears to be here just for his/her own benefit.

Comment: (For clarity, I am not advocating that you should give up one of these accounts. In fact I'd recommend you contact a moderator and ask the accounts to be merged, so as to benefit in the way I describe above).

Comment: @halfer I understand your point and even agree. The metric for being good on SO is reputation, not the ratio of questions asked to answers given. Reputation doesn't ask what you've got it for. After all, every answer needs a question. Asking a good question is a way of contributing to this site. My work place does not permit other ways like answering. While my work account is rarely used and has low rep, it is not one of the many 1 rep accounts. My work account acts selfish, but this is not considered to be a bad thing by the community, as it gained reputation for its actions.

Comment: I think it's right to say that the _Meta_ community considers rep as somewhat flawed, though the advantages of gamification probably outweigh the downsides. Even the help docs say that reputation is a _rough_ estimate of how much the community trusts you - it's not perfect. There are other metrics too, like accept rate (sadly no longer displayed in sig cards, but still somewhat visible in profiles) and general comment interaction between OPs and helpers.

Comment: It's true the site needs questions as much as it needs answers, but - speaking personally here - I tend to be unimpressed by genuinely selfish accounts, where help is always sought and never given, and answers remain unacknowledged. Your work account might be judged by people to be like that, even though here we agree that's an unfair assessment, since you have another one where you volunteer too.

Comment: The core problem here seems to be an excessive authoritarianism at your workplace, where - even in five minutes of downtime - you are explicitly forbidden from answering a question on a Q&A site?

Comment: @halfer let's call it work ethic =). At work, one is explicitly paid for doing one's job and that means implicitly that one should not do other stuff (online or elsewhere). And there's a mental/psychological aspect to this, too: when there is a downtime, it's there for a reason: one is stuck with a problem and needs to take a step back, take a break from thinking. Just imagine you are at the brink of flipping the table because of some persisting problem and somebody pops in to ask "why info.php is *not working*" . I can't and don't want to write answerss at work, they wouldn't be good.

Answer (score 6):

I feel the sign up aspect has been covered in other answers, but let me take a new look at contribute, from my own perspective.

When I first signed up with Stack Overflow, it was for my own needs. I didn't care about helping the site, I cared about the site helping me. For a bit, the site was this cool new thing for me, like many things in my life are.

Then I discovered this site was just one of many- This site was what I needed for work, but there were sites I could enjoy for my personal life as well, such as Arqade. Now my history on Arqade is *far* different than my history on Stack Overflow.

When I created an account on Arqade, it wasn't to help myself. Indeed, I have asked zero questions over there- When it comes to gaming, I can usually find the answer or figure it out myself simply because I have far more experience in it than in programming. So instead of wanting to help *myself,* finding this site that focused on something I was interested in and not just something that I (at the time) was only interested in for work really made me rethink the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

Though I'm currently not active on Arqade, due to a lack of time to game and a lack of time, at home, to access the site really, Arqade made me realize how important these sites all were, and how much work we should be doing to help take care of them.

Since then, my focus when I come to Stack Overflow, or, more often, Meta Stack Overflow, has been "What can I do to help improve the site? What can I learn more to keep myself from *hindering* the site?"

While I don't feel I can really answer many programming questions, I've become decently active on Meta. Through participating here, I'm learning how better to contribute to the site, both to help me and the other users who find things I've done.

How does this answer why people don't contribute? Well, at least for some people, it's because they don't care to. Stack Overflow, to them, is just a means to an end. It's a site to get an answer to that small issue that's holding up their project. To them, the site is not "their community" like it is for some of us here on Meta. They don't see how important this site really is, and for a number of people like this, they likely never will. But for some, when they realize there's more to the network than just Stack Overflow, they may dig deeper and see there's more to Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange as a whole, then just "Ask question, get answer, don't care about anyone else."

As a side note, one of my coworkers had no interest in the Stack Exchange network, creating an account that is, until I told him about the plethora of other sites with other topics. While he still might not ever create a *Stack Overflow* account, he may just decide to join up on one of the smaller sites that interests him, so that is always a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

I rarely have a need to ask a question on Stack Overflow because I usually find the question has been asked already, or since I'm a proficient programmer the random hints I find on related questions are more than enough to help me solve my query.

Often however, I have a useful comment on an answer that I'm unable to contribute because I have less than 50 reputation.

So why not answer a few questions to earn that 50 reputation? Well, there is rarely a question I find particularly worth bothering to answer. If it was worth bothering to answer it would probably require a fair bit of research to meet my own personal standards.

But most stuff of the unanswered/new questions I find are "homework" style questions, or very specific one-off questions that probably have little use to anyone else but the original poster. In addition, any attempt to write an answer to these questions I usually find somebody else gets there first, usually someone with a huge reputation score, and probably a lot more time on their hands than me. What's the point?

Comment: Excellent answer, and probably very close to how it appears to most "lo-rep" contributors. You may want to read [How do new users start on SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/2564301) - although the consensus appears to be "have patience, Grasshopper". Still: *all* contributions are appreciated. Most of all, you should not feel intimidated and shy away if a High Rep User answered a question *you* felt like answering. They just may be wrong, or you may be able to provide a valuable different point of view.

Answer (score 5):

"I'm wondering why people don't **get a little rep (15)** to be able to upvote to give a stronger indicator of which answer works plus as a thanks to the posters - to "give back" to the site."

Because "**get a little rep (15)**" actually takes quite a bit of effort. You can't just sign up and upvote - even if you really want to.

I get that there are (probably good) reasons for that. But it also puts a big barrier in the way of contribution. And if you don't have any rep and want to upvote something, there's actually nothing you can do **immediately** to change that. So not only is there an effort barrier, but **investment** is required. I need to invest time now, in the hope that in the future that investment will be rewarded to the extent that I can upvote. And I know that when that happens the Q/A I wanted to upvote will likely be long forgotten.

That's quite a lot to ask, when all I want to do is say "thanks" or "nice one". The investment I make in signing up is decoupled from the "reward" I want: the ability to upvote.

Answer (score 5):

I've used Stack Overflow as a non-registered user for three years and a half before signing up and here's why:

1. At first I didn't even think about it. That's just that simple.

You know, I do a lot of searches, and I don't always sign up on whatever website/forum/board I find the answer I was looking for. What made me sign up to Stack Overflow is that I eventually ended up here 80% of the time (20 are [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)-related questions to which finding the answer is easily done, because it has great official documentation).

2. I didn't think I was able to contribute (and still feel a little that way).

Let's face it, except if you're super fast or just hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> on newest questions, you can't really answer easy questions because someone already did it five seconds earlier. And not being able to answer easy questions leaves you with unanswered ones (hard ones) and those are the ones I'm afraid I can't really help with.

I'm yet a student, and I don't really have a vast and deep experience on any language (I do have some though -o-) yet and for the much I know, someone here probably has more skills than I do to answer tricky questions.
Introducing my third point:

3. I didn't feel like signing up just to upvote at first.

And when I did, I noticed I had to earn reputation by.... answering questions.
I know there's asking too, but 99.9% of the questions I'm asking myself already are answered here (one way or another) and that's **precisely** why I come to Stack Overflow. Because answers are here.

Just my [two cents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun), hoping it can help you understand one's reasons.

Answer (score 5):

For the past 6-7 years I've been exactly like the people described above. I have used stack overflow, found the answer to hundreds and hundreds of questions, and been a huge fan but I've always just taken the answer and run with it as a guest/lurker.

Why did I finally sign up? I found the answer to such an obscure programming question that had zero votes. I felt obligated to sign in and thank the answer giver with an upvote and possibly a thank you comment so that others would know the answer was valid.

Fastforward several months to now and I have now just enough reputation to make this post. I've been unable to upvote answers to my questions that helped or solved my issue, and I believe the community suffers from it. It might not be a solution to get people to sign up for stack overflow, but I think the community needs to consider a better way to retain the users when they do sign up.

Not being able to vote or comment made me abandon the thought of contributing and not log back in for months - and I'm sure it has made others give up as well. I know my posting risks getting downvotes and losing my chance to contribute as soon as I get it. But, I really have grown to enjoy stack overflow - and think we should encourage new users to stick around (and, employ other means for hunting down trolls and spambots)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's unfortunate that you want to "give back" but need a minimal amount of reputation to vote up or comment, but the reason is clear: **without** such a basic defense, SO would be a prime target for trolls, spammers, and all other kinds of low-life that derive pleasure from disturbing online communities. The bar has been kept pretty low, but nevertheless: the key is *to participate more*, not *less*. Keep asking questions when you need to, and answering when you can, and pretty soon you'll find you have enough of a reputation to move around with confidence.

Answer (score 4):

I won't remark on the general case as I think existing answers cover it fairly well.

To summarize my answer: it's possible some small portion of the 90-99% (lurkers) are unable or not authorized to contribute for one reason or another, including:

- Technical limitations (such as an old computer with an old browser, where development machines are not connected to the internet)
- Language limitations (for example, barely able to read English)
- Policy-based limitations (not allowed to access social media from work)
- Pedantic/incompetent IT policies, especially those created as knee-jerk responses to every security threat no matter how severe

---

The organization I work for has a large number of engineers working for them (on the order of 10k+). Historically developers here didn't have access to the Internet, let alone anything as valuable as Stack Exchange sites. As a consequence, most "good practices" (::cough::) came from books written in the 1980/1990s or word-of-mouth, etc.

Not long after Stack Exchange sites became a usable resource for us, a variety of things (including intentional or incompetent network policies) have rendered many websites mostly or entirely useless (for example, only able to browse a given site). It seems that when someone doesn't know how to make stuff work correctly, their solution to making it safe/secure is to render it useless.

I'm trying to change the developer culture within our group (for example, getting people to read books like *[Code Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Complete)*, doing regular training on technical topics, encourage developers to become regular contributors to Stack Exchange sites, etc.), but this is just one of the many stumbling stones we've hit along that path.

Supposing these problems were magically resolved overnight I wouldn't expect an influx of new accounts/contributors from our organization (whether because they expect stuff to be broken, or they're conditioned to lurking). Nevertheless, it's ***an*** answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

People don't sign up because they don't care about maintaining their record.
When they have a question that needs to be answered and they can't find the solution with search option they will ask, get an answer and leave till the next time.

It's the same thing as for example if you are looking to identify a song. You might ask 1, 2, 5, or 10 requests for identification in a music forum, but you wouldn't really care how the users there rate you or if thous four questions will be related to an account or not.

Normally people are registered to sites for two main reasons:

1. They want to.
2. They are forced to.

It's better that sites will encourage the first type rather than the second type. Sites like [Mailinator.com](http://www.Mailinator.com) were invented because of the second type. They allow a fast "Register and Forget" method.

Answer (score 2):

**Gamification doesn't appeal to everybody.**

Some just want the practical benefits that don't need an account.

Comment: Being able to ask a question is a practical benefit.

Comment: // , One would tend to think that, @Jongware.

Answer (score 0):

Some people don't know how to ask. If they get any issue, they will search through a search engine. They will apply the solution if they got any. If they don't get any solution or are not solving it with the available solution, they will change the problem (will use another method/technique/library). So they won't ask any question.

Comment: It's not too clear what point you're trying to convey here...

Comment: @Lix - They're just saying that some people would rather change how they're doing something than ask a question about their problem on Stack Overflow because don't feel they're able to ask a good question.

Comment: This is my point in a nutshell - if a person doesn't know how to articulate their question, they'll keep looking elsewhere for a solution.  You do highlight a huge concern in the industry though - [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) in which someone believes that a perfect solution exists on the Internet and can be placed into their program, which shouldn't be the goal of *any* site out there.

Comment: // , Plus, many questions are "questions about the question". I'm sure we've all run into problems where we don't even know "where to start". This happens a lot when users do not understand the terminology they're using. Then ANY question is automatically "wrong".

Answer (score -8):

The behavior of the moderators are the biggest deterrent to those possibly interested in opening an account, and maybe even later contributing.

I know several people that have signed up, asked a question, and then were pounced upon by the moderators. After two or three times of that, they just bail.

I have started seeing blogs and other comments on the Internet lamenting the behavior of the moderators on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow as well.

A friend of mine started using Stack Overflow as he began to teach himself [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). He made the mistake of responding to the moderators' questions thinking they had his best interest in mind. Boy was he wrong about that. He was more and more targeted each time he asked a question.

Then he tried to contribute by answering a question, and then the very next question he asked was attacked so fiercely it was almost funny. One moderator marked it as a duplicate, even though the supposed original question had nothing to do with my friend's question. Then my friend made the mistake of pointing that fact out. The next time he tried to ask a question, he found a warning that he was "In danger of being banned from asking questions."

He logged out and has never logged back in again.

Just as he had develop enough knowledge, and felt an obligation, to contribute himself, he was prevented from doing so by self-righteous and self-serving moderators. A real shame.

People see the nastiness when using the site, and they discuss it with each other as well, and the result is to turn many away.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81415/discussion-on-answer-by-jayjay123-why-dont-people-sign-up-and-contribute).

Comment: Moved my very pertinent to the question comment to "Chat." Just reenforcing my comment, and revealing that no one on SO/SE is truly interested in addressing any of the issues that are undermining it.

Comment: // , You dare insult the moderators!!!!!!!! PREPARE FOR CONDEMNATION.

Answer (score -8):

Personally, I find the upvoting / downvoting system to be really frustrating.  I signed up, but I've stopped asking questions because my questions would get downvoting with absolutely no commentary as to why.  Which is silly and pointless -- it's a system where the "in" crowd can play their little points game, but those on the outside find frustration in guessing what gets a downvote and what doesn't.  I even tried emailing the site admins and still got nowhere.  So I've given up trying to be a contributor on this site and am happily lurking.  In my opinion, if you want more contributors, you need to make the point system more transparent and less subjective.  Downvotes should be treated as another way to help someone, not as a method for excluding people who are just trying to contribute.

Comment: As any questions/answers you have posted are either deleted or on another account, it's impossible to figure out why they were downvoted. However, generally speaking, downvoting DOES help people. It's hard to take it as a positive thing, but if you use it as a nudge to write a better question, what's the harm there?

Comment: @canon Yes, I was looking at MSO, d'oh!

Comment: A downvote isn't a positive thing if the recipient can't figure out why it's happening.  Positive means there's feedback, not a big guessing game of what sequence the monkey has to press the buttons in order to get a treat.

Comment: @devlin, a downvote without explanations is perfectly legitimate if the user can figure out what's happening by reading the help center. We cannot possibly spend all our time copy-pasting the site rules under the questions of new users.

Comment: I'm not asking for a babysitter to hand feed me.  I have read the help center / FAQs on asking a good question.  If a smart person with reasonably good communication skills can't figure out how to ask a "proper" question, I think that's a good indication that the downvoting isn't a positive learning tool.

Comment: @canon :  here, try this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083420/getting-json-data-with-ajax-and-converting-to-array-of-strings

Comment: See things from our side of the fence: a large proportion of users turn up with badly formatted, poorly phrased, unresearched questions. A surprising number of them ask for whole tasks to be done for them, or demonstrate they've not read any of the guidelines at all. Helpers on the main site, who are volunteers, get somewhat tired of the avalanche. Then, when these sorts of questions appear on _Meta_, we get hostile posts like yours, which dismiss the community as exclusionary cliques who play silly games. We try to remain positive throughout all this, to varying degrees of success.

Comment: @devlin, believe it or not, it's pretty tricky to understand exactly what you asked in that question. The fact you had to repeat your first sentence in a comment should strike you as odd and prompt you to put more emphasis on that part. From the rest of your question, it looks like you had trouble dumping the actual objects (you got help in the comments), and don't know how to extract an object value from its key (which can be interpreted as lack of research effort). Oh, and your "finally, an intelligent response" comment under the answer probably did not play in your favor.

Comment: I spent years as a volunteer admin on another, similar site, so I understand that sites like this get a bunch of crap questions, and duplicates.  But the point system seems to be targeting that group of questions, at the expense of questions that are reasonably formulated and where the author has taken due diligence in trying to find the answer before asking the question.  Back when I was still posting questions, I always did it as a last resort after spending a good chunk of time trying to find the answer myself.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - shouldn't this be a two way street?  you said earlier that users should be able to figure out what's happening without having their hands held.  Shouldn't the same be true of those who are responding to questions?  And, I'd just like to point out that no one here really knows why that question was downvoted.  So far, we're guessing that it could be a duplicate, or the first sentence in the question wasn't in bold with a question mark behind it.  Next?

Comment: @canon - I'm not saying it's not a possible duplicate.  I'm saying I always look for answers to my questions before posting.  Sometimes, especially when someone is new to a topic (I was just learning php at that time), they don't know the right key words to use.  For me, I didn't know I was trying to get the property of an object.  I thought of it as an array of strings... try searching for answers from that perspective?  Oh, and to bring things back to my point...  the point system is not at all helpful if it takes *this* to get some feedback.  Most users are just going to give up.

Comment: @canon - YES!  and that's the problem!  the system is hinged on the "drive by" voter.  It's easy to tag a completely bad question, and rightly so.  But there is this whole other arena of potential contributors who are victims of the drive by voter.  The system should require the same level of due diligence from the voters as it requires from those asking questions.

Comment: actually, the help center does provide a clear explanation for common reasons for downvotes.  but that doesn't help people who are legitimately attempting to ask well thought out questions.  drive by voters will still mindlessly click the downvote.  it's so easy to do!  oh, and hey!  it looks like i've gained get another downvote on that question!

Comment: yeah, i do.  it's a reasonable question.  and i know i wasn't being lazy in asking it.

Comment: Make it easy for people, ask a question with a question mark. It's astonishing how many people don't understand that. That said, I don't think it deserved downvotes.

Comment: @S List - i have several other examples, with question marks.  i'm not going to post them here because, well, the click happy downvoters are just going to keep up their happy downvoting sprees.  i'll at least make them go through my profile to find their prey... that should deter a mindless drive-by clicker or two.

Comment: @devlincarnate - feedback on your SO post: note that you aggressively ignored request for information "exactly what is the correct format according to you" and claim that people never commented... Which did not make question easier to understand and additionally made more people to reconsider usefulness of adding comments when downvoting.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -  wow...  just WOW!  the first sentence in that question says: "I'm trying to get my data into an array of strings."  how does that not address the comment, "exactly what is the correct format according to you".  If only I could bold the response here:  i was looking for AN ARRAY OF STRINGS.  how is that not clear?  and my response to that comment was "are you people not reading the first sentence?"  again, this thread is just really highlighting the imbalance over holding questioners accountable, but allowing responses and downvotes to be subject to idiocy.

Comment: i give up.  again.  it's obvious that most of the people giving input on this thread don't really care to know why others don't participate. you want clear questions, but you don't require responders or downvoters to have basic reading or thinking skills.  back to lurking for me...

Comment: @devlincarnate no, first sentence says "array of strings *so that I can use it as a dataset for jquery autocomplete*" - it implies that it is somewhat special form of array. I think you imply two opposite things about people on SO - they are complete idiots on one hand but on other hand should be able to understand any question exactly as poster *wnated* to ask... If you'd target your question to just "complete idiots" and provide all details it may be received much better... Explaining problems to other people is *hard*...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - i never said that people on SO are complete idiots.  i said that there is a complete lack of balance in requiring questions to be so carefully crafted that even the lowest common denominator can comprehend what is being asked, and yet responses and downvoting can lack any kind of careful thought or review.  if someone doesn't understand the question i'm asking... move the f* on!  let someone who comprehends the question (as others did in the example we're talking about) respond!

Comment: also, as a quick note:  an array of strings is an array of strings.  there is no such thing as a special format for an array of strings.  so to ask me to compose a question that has in mind that someone might think i'm asking for a special format for an array of strings because i mention how it's going to be used (which i did because i was trying to carefully craft my question!) is a great example of how flawed the voting system is.  and that's really frustrating!

Comment: I agree with you that downvotes without comments are frustrating, generally unhelpful, and unlikely to teach anything to the poster, but I have to agree with @SList: it's a simple thing, but having an actual question in a question greatly helps readability. Most sentences starting with "*I'm trying to ...*" are there to set the context. A lot of users will only give your question a first glance of 5 seconds, and only re-read it if they're interested. If they can't actually spot a question, they'll often downvote (and it seems fair, especially if they've taken the time to ask for clarification)

Comment: @devlincarnate, I agree.  I found it very frustrating.  This is my third attempt over several years to get into it.  I am perservering this time around.  The problem in my opinion is the Review setup.  There are so many audit questions that have been marked down when they shouldnt have been that after you keep getting scolded for doing the right thing, it is easier just to downvote everything.  You get fewer scoldings.

Comment: There are so many instances where the guys has answered the question, yet it has been marked as not answering the question.  Clearly the reviewers have not read or understod because they are too busy trying to get their badges.

Comment: @devlin - sorry, I only looked at that one question.  I hate drive-by downclickers too, especially when they downclick a question in an obscure topic, that they just don't understand, because 3 other people down-voted it (I'm sure this happens!).  I get the impression that you're a thoughtful person, who nevertheless is not a natural communicator - typical software developer in other words :-)  Hope you're not put off SO by these frustrating experiences.

Comment: I see a few issues here. Firstly I'm not really sure why you're getting so upset about downvotes. This is the internet and bad things happen all the time. As a one time admin of a similar forum, you should really get that. Secondly, your attitude in comments is only going to spawn further downvotes. I'm not one of them, but I can see others looking at a comment and dishing out their "punishment".

Comment: @DavidG Bad things happen on the internet all the time indeed, but down/close votes seem to attract more similar votes, not necessarily based on bad quality. Compared to other things that happen on the internet, these votes (esp. close votes) have the power to have a 3rd party prevent a communication between other people. I've seen reasonable questions closed for dubious reasons, even though I found the question sensible and I knew the answer to it. [Here is a recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30809051/372643) which I've managed to answer in time, but failed to reopen so far.

Comment: @Bruno Specifically looking at that question, I would probably VTC it too. Especially looking at the initial revision which basically says "I have some code, don't know what to do, can I open these URLs?" That to me looks like someone who has done no research and not spent any time to write a good question. The further edit only gives us another close reason which is asking for off-site resources.

Comment: @DavidG That's the classic problem of the tension between "canonical" questions and questions with insufficient information. In many cases, like this one, more details won't matter that much. It might not be perfectly worded, but trying to find out whether a server supports TLS 1.2 or not from Python is a perfectly valid question. I'd say more details about the code and what's been attempted make the question often too detailed (at least for this type of question) and slightly missing the actual problem (symptomatic of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/148833)).

Comment: ... Essentially, this sort of behaviour shuts down users who are unsure, but are yet willing to stick their neck out. That user was just acknowledging he may not know everything that well. The feedback system encourage by SO seems to be that it's better to pretend you know what you're talking about when asking, even if you don't. That can lead to even more confusion. (Somehow, this reminds me of what happened with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13135230/372643), which was also discussed on Meta: another question where implementation attempts are not particularly relevant.)

Comment: @Bruno That question was closed days before the OP clarified that he wanted to know if a server supports TLS 1.2. And still the question itself doesn't contain that information. So for me, it should still be left closed. Additionally, if OP fires off a question and then doesn't respond for 3 days, I have little sympathy.

Comment: @DavidG Actually, it was quite clearly in the body of the question to start with. He just didn't make it clear, or maybe wasn't aware, that you need to test the server, not a specific page. This is exactly the problem users have, in that they need to know quite a lot about what they're trying to do before even asking a question. Often, if you have sufficient knowledge to know the terminology in advance, you have sufficient knowledge not to ask the question.

Comment: @Bruno Well I'm happy to agree to disagree on the question's clarity, though it does beg the question of why you asked for clarification! But OP had plenty of time to improve it and didn't. If those comments were merged into the question, I might be happy to reopen too.

Answer (score -8):

They went and [moved](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81415/discussion-on-answer-by-jayjay123-why-dont-people-sign-up-and-contribute) my very pertinent to the question comment to "chat." And they did so by gutting the comment and only copying over one part of it, and displaying that out of context. Behavior that reenforces my comment, and reveals that no one on SO/SE is truly interested in addressing any of the issues that are undermining it. LOL and sad.

Just discovered that, after posting my comment on on the original question, someone went and downloaded several of my questions. Just more proof of what I state--Mean and nasty is why people are shying away from creating accounts on SO and SE.

Mean and nasty.

Comment: I've just compared the deleted comments to the contents of the chatroom. Nowhing was gutted or partially copied that I can see. That process is *entirely automated*. And you were not participating in that extensive discussion.

Comment: // , Welcome to StackOverflow, home of the developers who don't have anything better to do: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow#section-9