# Should I say please when asking an OP to post more information such as code or logs?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

Suppose someone asks a question that isn't answerable without more information. It's natural to post a comment requesting it from them. Is it better to ask like this:

> "Please post your error logs"

or more directly like this:

> "Post your error logs"

There have been claims made by disgruntled users (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297584/696391), and also around the net) that SO "mods" (in practice I think they are usually just other users) are too rude to newbies when asking them to get their questions in shape, so maybe a little bit of extra politeness wouldn't go amiss.

On the other hand, "thanks in advance" and "help please" in questions and "thanks" in comments are [frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1) so maybe a "please" in this context would be inappropriate too?

Comment: You will not lose nothing if you say please

Comment: @ShaifulIslam, but it does not hurt if not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks in comments are frowned upon because it is unnecessary to post a comment just to say thanks if you have nothing else to say — thanks are more appropriately expressed through voting.

But here you are making a request to the OP, not just being polite for the sake of it. In this case, feel free to be as cordial as you like, if you feel that terseness could be seen as rude. Once the request has been fulfilled the comment will eventually be removed as obsolete anyway.

Of course, politeness doesn't guarantee that a user will comply with your request. Some may see it as patronizing, or otherwise take offense to either the tone of the request, or the request itself. These people can never be reasoned with, however, so don't worry about them.

Answer (score 2):

You can formulate a lot of requests (orders?) as statements.

"If I could see then logs then I could understand X"

"I don't know how to help you with X because"

This is perhaps studiously polite and requires more typing and thinking, but has the advantage of accurately describing the relationship that you have to the questioner: you can't make the asker do anything, nor are you obligated to help them. I do this in everyday life as well "Could I get a coffee?", "Would it be okay if...", "I need this so that I can...". This is especially useful when you are trying to force people to do things that they don't want to do, "give that to me" vs "if you don't give that to me I'll have to call my manager"

This approach also defuses situations where you are asking the asker to do something that takes a long time to do, and which they don't understand the use of. ("Just produce a detail behaviour specification including all edge cases of the behaviour you want as well-formed XML".) I don't know how often this is the cause of the perceived rudeness of "give me the logs", but when I've felt piqued by requests for clarification this is often a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Who would be the rude person here? The commenter asking for information need to answer the question? Or the question asker for not bothering to provide it?

"Please" often indicates a request for something optional. It often indicates that the other person would be doing the person saying "Please" a favour. The OP is asking skilled strangers to make an effort for them for free. They are asking for a favour.

So, I reserve " please" for cases where the request is for something nice to have, not something strictly required.