# Was I too harsh when handling a newbie question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, new-users, etiquette

Yesterday, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31658921/2675154), asking:

> Which is the best platform for bootstrap coding ? I have googled but I did not understand.

For me this appears to be a tool recommendation question. Therefore, I flagged it accordingly and commented (as kindly as I could do) that the question is off-topic:

> Please note that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. – honk Jul 27 at 17:02

I didn't ask the OP to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), because they already have the
[Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge.

Later, I saw that the question was still open and received an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31659274/2675154) which was accepted and got three upvotes. The answer refers to my comment in the first sentence. The [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31658921/2675154#comment51263654_31659274) on that answer starts with:

> Thanks for answering his question and not being a total a-hole about it [...]

I think, this comment (which wasn't from the OP, but another user) can be interpreted that way, that I'm a total a-hole for the comment I left.

Now I'm confused. Was I wrong with my judgment? Was I too harsh on this newbie question?

Comment: That's fits "too broad" or "opinion-based".  It should be closed.

Comment: I don't think so. The only harsh thing I saw was his response.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.  :p

Comment: you were actually way more polite than 90% of people commenting when something is Off-Topic. I'd say someone just has a thin skin and got offended for nothing. Don't worry about it, I think you've done exactly what should've been done.

Comment: In case people missed it, the comment was not from the question poster; just another person who happened to see it.

Comment: Man, that was fast.17 minutes and it's already gone. (It's probably always that fast but I usually don't see these until the question's a few hours old.)

Comment: @resueman: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I am reading this question at the time the linked question is already deleted and I dont understand it because there's too many dead links. Maybe add what you commented?

Comment: @Loko comment added by (I assume) Jongware to above post.

Comment: Not harsh at all. Your comment was on point.

Comment: I used to have so many questions downvoted, some even now. And I have a history of so many closed questions. You know what, I am glad that there were moderators and users like you who were kind enough to tell me why they did it that I could learn from it. Also, the moderation in SE is very kind, I did not even know there was a ban till I read other answers in this question. So, pat yourself for a good job ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I would say your comment was fine and the question should be closed as either "too broad" or "opinion-based". In addition, the comment you are referring to should be flagged for attention also, as it provides no value at all.

Comment: Definitely __don't use NAA__.  It is an answer.  The problem is with the question.  And VLQ?  IMO it's not.  It offers a good explanation.  Again, the problem is with the question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu It was edited since I looked at it

Comment: I edited it, but only by removing noise.  It still had all the same content.

Comment: Leave the answer the hell alone. And why did the whole thing have to be deleted now?

Comment: @Pekka웃 You don't need an answer to go say, "look up some tutorials on the topic and that will get you started".  Without an answer like this around someone looking for tutorials on the topic is more likely to find *actual* tutorials on the topic when searching, rather than just an SO post saying that they should look at an actual tutorial on the topic.

Comment: @Pekka웃 "Which is the best platform" > opinion based > off -topic > close > cleanup (delete)

Comment: I think this community in particular is missing the point (in some cases) the user expertise in this community seems uniquely qualified to answer questions that appear to be opinion based. Although the concept of opinion based/subjective answers, and the approach to avoid them seems logical, all too often there appears to be a connection between some responders and the OPs. This may be a dynamic that this community has not considered, think, "You read my mind."  There is really no opinion here, but a like (similar) understanding where a solution is easy provided. Its a disservice to not allow.

Comment: Perhaps it makes more sense to move the question to a more suiting community, I believe a delete is ever appropriate with the exceptions of misuse, i.e. vulgarity, abusiveness, etc.

Comment: @htm11h You can undelete your own posts within 90 days of being deleted. You can always edit the question to make it on-topic. But your belief about deletions is naive. [What about all of the abandoned questions that are automatically deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/288751)

Comment: @htm11h No, you're the one missing the point.  The reason that this community is as good/valuable as it is is precisely because it prohibits questions like these.  These highly broad and opinion based questions discourage experts from participating in the long term.  So by allowing the types of questions that SO permits, it would make SO a poor place to get answers to those questions, (and the questions currently allowed at the same time).

Comment: @TinyGiant He can't undelete the post himself as it was deleted by 3 10k+ users.  He could only undelete it if he deleted it hiimself.

Comment: The issue of abandon questions was not part of this discussion, though I understand the need.

Comment: @servy Oh, thanks for the correction, I was under the impression that only applied to moderator deleted posts.

Comment: @servy I think you missed my point, I said I understand the logic to it. I think the handling is incorrect. There should be no reason to delete a valid question, it just needs to be processed differently.

Comment: @htm11h It's *not* a valid question.  It's content that we don't want here, because the site has determined that they cause more harm than good, and so have considered them out of scope for the site.  It *doesn't* need to be processed differently.

Comment: @htm11h - How you think questions like these should be handled boils down to what you think SO's mission should be. If you think the mission is to answer individual users questions, then you are going to be heavily biased toward allowing just about any question on the site. If you think the mission is to create a repository of high quality content useful for everyone else on the internet, then you are going to be biased toward removing questions that encourage low quality content. Most SO users fit in the second group. Most [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/) users fit the first.

Comment: @htm11h "how do I change a tire on my car" is a valid question. Doesn't mean it should be asked on stack overflow. This site was NEVER meant to answer all questions. It became popular because of its quality standards, and because of that it is now completely flooded with people who think anything and everythig should be allowed. Stack became good because it didn't do that. If we turn around, there's a very real risk quality will DRASTICALLY drop

Comment: @htm11h: We could always [implement migration to yahoo answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99467).

Comment: @servy again you are severely missing the point. You make a ridiculous jump to assume that I mean to allow any and all questions. The site has been plagued by user disgust of on topic questions for a long time. Subjective or opinion based answers (among others) are frequently rejected. Ok fine, move them to a different queue, Stack Exchange has hundreds of communities and could easily move (process differently) the lower quality questions. Don't abandon the effort of someone trying to advance their knowledge, by CLOSING or VOTING to DELETE. Provides no value to those that hope to succeed in IT

Comment: Just to add a little proof to the discussion, here is a rather in depth review of the problem. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271863/misuse-of-off-topic-closure-reason

Comment: If you scroll down there are some actual stats pulled from the site.

Comment: @htm11h So it's completely incorrect of me to say that you want to allow any and all questions; you still don't want all questions to be acceptable, you just want us to stop closing and deleting low quality questions and instead let people ask and answer then anyway.  Sorry, but you're contradicting yourself there.  And if you think that people can only succeed in IT by asking low quality questions and having us pretend that they're not actually low quality questions...

Comment: @servy you apparently only want to argue so we'll never reach an understanding. My point was that questions on recipes, for example, would be deleted/closed, while IT topic type questions could be moved to an appropriate community. Come on dude, its a step to improve, not hinder. Embrace change, or stagnate! If you intend to be belligerent on this topic don't bother to reply. I noticed you had no comment on the stats already gathered! And there is no contradiction, they're simply different approaches.

Comment: @htm11h Why should another community get a bad question moved to them? Also if you are moving questions why not move any question that fits on another community to that community? After all there are places where recipes would fit so why not move that question instead of deleting it? It would just cause a lot of work for other users and mods to move every question that does not belong on the site when it should be the person who asks the question job to post it on the correct site.

Comment: @servy  and where in the world did I say 'people can only succeed in IT by asking low quality questions" ? you continue to fabricate content to my post that is not there!!!.

Comment: @JoeW I did say close/move/delete at the discretion of the reviewer. I think they can handle a mouse click. In fact the site algorithms could likely provide a very close listing of recommended communities to make the process as easy as it is now to move questions, which happens all the time as it is now.

Comment: @htm11h You're not advocating moving the site forward; you're advocating moving it backward.  SO was founded because the other Q/A sites out there were full of crap, and it made finding quality content very hard.  SO was founded on the idea of having a very high signal to noise ratio, by removing low quality content to help the quality content stand out.  You're advocating reversing that founding guiding principle and trying to change SO to be more like the competitors that it has largely crushed into obscurity *through its advances in quality control*.

Comment: @htm11h If you want to participate in sites that welcome bad questions, and refuse to delete anything, regardless of how bad it is, then there are *lots* of sites out there for you where you can spend all the time that you want looking through garbage.  SO was created to be different; and it's not going to completely reverse everything that it stands for so that you can have more low quality content.

Comment: @servy You finally make a hint to a good point. But I am not advocating reducing the quality of content of SO. Your argument fails by again grouping all questions as low quality rather than the original statement of Opinion Based, which does not make them in whole, a bad question. My suggestion was simply to not close/delete but to move as is done with many other questions now.

Comment: @htm11h So you're not advocating reducing the quality of the site, you're just advocating not closing or deleting low quality content, which won't have any affect at all on the quality of the site.  Sorry, but that's not how that works.  When you're advocating not closing or deleting low quality content you *are* advocating reducing the quality of the content on the site.

Comment: @servy you do this a lot, declaring low quality content is inaccurate. The issue was Opinion Based answers which are not automatically low quality. And my point was to allow them to be answered, even if it meant moving them to another community, AGAIN, NOT degrading SO content.

Comment: @htm11h SE has determined that opinion based questions *are* low quality questions, and they *don't* create quality content.  And moving the trash somewhere else, instead of just getting rid of it, is only creating problems for other people.  SE even tried it once, many years ago, (creating a trash bin where all of the bad questions were sent so people like you that think they want to see more low quality content could have it) and it turned into a disaster (whose negative effects are still seen today).  They're not going to repeat the same mistake again.

Comment: @servy again you are incorrect, this is directly from the site...primarily opinion-based - discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well. 
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.    http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: All I am saying is preserve them in another repository.

Comment: @htm11h How does that not support my point?  The site is asserting that primarily opinion based questions generate very low quality content.  Questions that contain some amount of opinion, but that are largely based on objective fact, don't have the same problems.  You're saying that entirely opinion based content isn't low quality content, and as justification are posting a statement saying that entirely opinion based questions generate low quality content.

Comment: @htm11h And all I'm saying is that we aren't going to do that, because it'll cause lots of problems.  How would you feel if your garbage man just stopped taking your garbage, saying that he just wants to preserve that content for you and prevent it from being removed from your property.  Would you be thankful that he's helping you keep around the content that you're actively trying to discard?

Comment: @servy  you are incorrectly tying opinion based content, often submitted from professional experience, as low quality content, IT IS NOT, low quality.

Comment: @servy as to your garbage analogy, that is exactly what has happened by my choice, I now separate my recyclables for separate collection.

Comment: @htm11h The quote that you just provided is stating that it is.  The history of the site, which has extensive experience with it, has demonstrated, time and time again, that opinion based questions generate low quality content, and that the site is better off without them.

Comment: @servy I still disagree and if you again look at the links previously provided there is a large number of members that have stated issues, moderators as well. My only suggestion was to consider handling these borderline issues differently. I would also contend that professional experience is in fact, fact. Just because it hasn't been published or peer reviewed does not in fact make it solely opinion based.

Comment: @htm11h Once again.  We did that once.  It turned out *terribly*.  As much as people claimed that they want this content, when it was actually given to them virtually nobody actually used the site, it created lots of low quality content, has very little traffic, and has had lasting negative impacts *to this day* in the efforts to try to clean it up.  We have considerable amounts of very compelling evidence that these questions create low quality content, and that it's harmful for the site to have them, even though people think they want them.  You've got no evidence to support your position.

Comment: @servy Ok, I appreciate the details to the previous attempt. Perhaps it was not as well developed as could be done today.

Comment: @htm11h If you think you can do better, go ahead and create your own discussion board.  There are tens of thousands of others out there; SE just isn't one of them.

Comment: @servy  SE is great, as it stands. But nothing wrong on looking to improve. Is there a history page for this site and its evolution?

Comment: @htm11h And that's in large part *because questions like this aren't welcome*, as I've already explained to you.  SE improved on other sites *by prohibiting content like this*.  You're proposal wouldn't be improvement, it would be taking steps *backwards* towards the models that have decades long histories of *not working*.

Comment: @servy But they should be, some place on SE. I guess I don't understand you definition of not working, when so many people are complaining about it. Are you simply holding that no one competent enough to answer the questions would do so?

Comment: @htm11h We don't need to guess.  We already know, from extensive experience, that these questions don't generate quality content.  You're guessing that they will, I'm telling you that they've already shown (repeatedly, and extensively) that they won't.  If you want it, go to one of the tens of thousands of other sites out there that don't prohibit those kinds of questions and see for yourself why they don't turn out well.

Comment: @servy just read one of you posts from a side link regarding this site/community content. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297527/why-dont-people-sign-up-and-contribute/297528#297528   I see more of your point, this isn't conveyed well, in the tour or site enrollment, that is community based content. It should be compared to a nudist camp, or block association, where the strict rules dictate house color or landscape design (for example)  as SE dictates content. Not saying its wrong, just restrictive, as you argue for good reason.

Answer (score -24):

Less punishment would allow for more enforcement of high-quality content. Imagine if it were easier to close questions, but harder to punish a person for asking frivolous questions, the community might be more receptive to exacting standards. Also, if the user who asked the low-quality question had a forgiveness period to take back their question or change it, there might be less of a perception of "a-hole"-ness.

As it is, with the extreme punishment of basically banishment from the community and the severe nature of language stating that the question is "low-quality" and "off-topic" and should be "flagged for closure," you can't really enforce the standards without being an a-hole.

I mean, for a newbie, the gravity of asking a low-quality question is at or around the scale of a spilled glass of milk. You don't yell at a person and banish them from the kitchen for spilling milk. You tell them they should take care, then you clean up the milk and move on.

So it is pretty much the penalty system. The mission is fine. Why should the mission be sacrificed for the sake of being able to punish people who don't know any better? My first thought, when I started here and was told my question was off-topic, was: what a draconian ahole. I think you can achieve the mission without pushing the standards of civil society to the point where new users have that kind of reaction.

Simple solution: questions with a certain number of downvotes get removed from the site 5 days after the question is answered; asker gets notified that their content isn't welcome, and life moves on--no ban.  Everyone wins: newbs get the feedback that they need to improve the content, they get their answer, and you can downvote without reservation: the person isn't going to get banned from the site.

Otherwise, the site will have trouble allowing new people in, depriving us all of a stronger community.

Comment: Everyone who uses a Stack Exchange site _needs_ to understand that downvotes and question closure are intended as _guidance_, not as punishment. I don't deny that it can feel bad when it happens, but hey, it's only imaginary internet points, and if it's a new 1 point user they don't even lose any rep. And hopefully, they'll learn from their mistake, improve their question (or answer), and their future contributions will be of higher quality.

Comment: @bordeo If you want to slash (part of) the moderation system, you *really* need to present a replacement which stays viable in the face of, in your words, a-holes dumping their litter. And if you neglect to remove those not willing or able to pay a minimum of respect to the community whose help they desire and what keeps it alive, you are doomed whatever you try.

Comment: If someone shows up and spills a glass of milk, you take the milk away and say "please be careful with the milk".  If they come back 5 minutes later and spill another glass, you say "what are you doing"?  If they come back the next day, grab a glass of milk, and pour it all over the floor while looking you in the eye, you banish them from the kitchen.  It is true that when faced with the fact that they broke pretty clear rules, people get angry: but SO has a surplus of people asking bad questions anyhow, coddling people who respond to correction with anger isn't needed.

Comment: Your "simple solution" there has a problem: It does _not_ actually teach the users that the content they posted isn't welcome here. They still get an answer, so what do they care if the question is gone? The question ban takes _a lot_ to get to. If you are writing that bad of questions and not learning what you're doing is wrong, you need to be told to take a step back and learn the rules before you try again. New people can get in just fine. They just have to learn the rules of the community, similar to joining a new club. Blatantly ignore the rules, get kicked out.

Comment: @Yakk Anti-social behavior like that is a unicorn case.  Most people respond by trying to adapt--otherwise, there would be no community.  Trying to make sure the anti-social 5% behaves requires rules that are prohibitive to learning.  Instead of implementing more and more severe rules, give the community stronger measures to silence them.  If a downvote score of -5 in x hours = removal of the question from the site, then who cares if they stare you in the eye and pour the milk? their anger is their problem...it's out of the scope of SO to confront that kind of behavior.

Comment: @Kendra It is outside the scope of SO to "teach" the users...that kind of attitude is where the A-holeness comes from.  That's why this guy was feeling guilty enough to post this question.  It is about informing them that their content isn't welcome.  If you want to participate in the community and gain rep, you will still have to "learn" the ways of SO...but if you are just trying it out and you screw up, you won't come away saying those SO people are elitist pricks.  SO is big enough and touches enough people that that kind of negative press stymies any kind of extra growth from this point..

Comment: @bordeo The problem is the users that aren't taking the time to learn how the site work usually _do not in any way care about gaining rep._ They just want their problem fixed, that's it. They won't learn the ways of SO because they don't give a crap, so long as they get an answer. And even when the veteran SO user is being nice and polite, if they're told their content isn't welcome, a lot of users cry elitism. I bet you this solution, upon thinking about it more, would _cause the exact same response._ "My content isn't welcome? What a-holes! I even got an answer, how is it not welcome?!"

Comment: Sorry, but the OP of *this* question is just asking for confirmation that they did what they could. And the a-hole obviously felt no remorse at all.

Comment: If you want to kill this site by turning into a personal tutoring helpdesk site, your first update is certainly an efficient way to go about it. But such sites already exist, try yahoo answers or finding some paid tutors in your neighbourhood.

Comment: good point.  @Kendra: it's a matter of degree.  Fewer people will get pissed if they are treated with respect.  The fraction that still gets pissed when they are politely guided will just be silenced by the voting system, and their opinion that SO is elitist won't hold much water because people will just say: they were nice, you got your question answered...so you didn't get any rep and they down voted you--you obviously don't care about that, so what are you complaining about?

Comment: @Deduplicator then say, create a voting threshold where the question doesn't get answered, it just gets deleted.  trivial fix.  What we are talking about is a real reaction: people don't feel informed and guided by SO users, they feel mistreated.  That is a fundamental problem with this site: unless your a professional who needs the site more than you care about being treated with respect, you will learn the ways.  Of course, maybe that is the idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator  the guy who asked this question: "was I too harsh..."  ...that sounds like remorse to me.

Comment: The question being closed is taking the milk away after they already poured it on the table.  See, they wanted to play with milk on the table.  Closing the question and downvoting *instructs* the person who has already failed to read the "do not pour milk on the table" sign that they should not pour milk on the table.  The *punishment* (semi-permanent asking ban) only occurs after you repeatedly ask questions that are downvoted/closed/deleted.  That lines up with the person who comes back the next day, looks the community in the eye, and pours the milk all over the floor.

Comment: "was I too harsh..." is not remorse, it's just asking for confirmation that he did the best he could because the OPs aggressive attack and bad-mouthing rattled him. Such happens, everyone needs a steadying hand and some nice words from time to time, especially in the face of such ungrateful sociopaths with a gigantic sense of entitlement.

Comment: Closing the question is just cleaning up the milk they poured all over the table.  While this might be punishment (they really wanted to play with the milk on the table, taking it away is unfair) in some lights, it is also *keeping the kitchen clean*.

Comment: What you are describing implies malice on the part of the asker...are you seriously suggesting that a new user can't ask 4 or 5 bad questions in a row without malice?

Comment: deleting questions which have reached a certain downvote threshold keeps the kitchen clean.  Some people are clumsy and spill lots of milk (lol)...what you are saying is that people who are clumsy are the same as people who intentionally take milk and pour it all over the floor.

Comment: @bordeo unanswered questions are already deleted after a period of time when they meet certain conditions.  But try to think of the issue in terms of shear volume.  Stack Overflow gets so many new questions (good and bad) that good (and potentially good) questions often do not get the attention they deserve because they are quickly pushed aside by the flood of bad question.  By trying to prevent the bad questions **before** they are asked helps people who want to ask good questions but can't get answers because of the noise.

Comment: @psubsee2003 then there should be some kind of newb island.  Like there is in LOL.  the questions will still be answered, because there will be rep rewards...but they are kept separate from the main bulk of questions

Comment: @bordeo: Such a noob exchange was already proposed. But if you were a noob, would you really go to the place the experts assidiuously avoid because it's full of repetitive and abysmyl crap and ask the noobs there, instead of to the well-curated clean and shining hallowed site where the expertise resides? Then why are they here and not at yahoo answers or some such?

Comment: @deduplicator it would be a good place for intermediate users to practice answering questions like, how do I convert such and such a stream to byte[] etc. But I definitely see your point.  Ok, maybe just a warning--like, these are the rules, don't feel bad if your question isn't well received...we are strict but this is what we are trying to do.

Comment: They get those warnings, when their questions are closed, as well as when they ask the next one and their previous ones are unacceptable. For the first question, they only get lots of guidance and the tour.

Comment: Meh, maybe you are right.