# What makes you improve this site so much?

Tags: discussion, moderation

First, let me say that this is not intended to insult anyone; I am just wondering why you all put in so much effort in editing, flagging, improving, and - if that's not enough - even discussing particular cases here?

This is not going against you; I am really thankful you exist; I use Stack Overflow quite a lot to ask questions; sometimes I can answer some and if I spot an error in an answer of another person, I also edit this one - which hardly happens more often than once a quarter. Recently, someone else's answer just cut off at the end, so I completed it as some people were curious about the last few lines.

However, I am stunned by the dedication you seem to have to make this a better place. Where does that come from? Are you hoping for a free shirt or does the reputation next to the user name make you proud? I simply wouldn't have the time to go that deep into discussing what to edit, to improve, how to justify certain actions ... which is why I am curious what drives you.

Anyway, big props for what you are doing, please keep it up!

Comment: Great, then a group of people will tell me what MIGHT be a reason that another group of people (that I was initially asking) is doing something I was asking about.

Comment: See [Leopold von Sacher-Masoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_von_Sacher-Masoch).

Comment: ^ Update: I've seen Leopold von Sacher-Masoch, and I think I learned a few things about myself in the process.

Comment: Kind of related (and relevant) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you

Comment: It's all about the joke comments. That's what drives Meta.

Comment: Wait, there are free shirts?

Comment: @PaulRoub Wait, why did YOU use the site? I thought everyone did it for the free t-shirts

Comment: 'This board'- Stack Overflow is not a forum or a 'board', it is a Q&A site.

Comment: A bit related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297527

Comment: I'm only here to hit 100k and get myself the legendary box o' swag

Comment: "A pattern will arise in which there is some group of users that cares more than average about the integrity and success of the group as a whole" from [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html) by Clay Shirky

Comment: I am really just hoping for the opportunity to *buy* a Stack Overflow shirt some day.

Comment: I use the site solely to correct people with "we're _not_ a forum, message board, or anything like that!" comments.

Comment: I'm just here for the rep. As soon as I reach a million, I will sell all my points to buy a villa and retire. That is, if the rep to coin exchange rate is a bit better then...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you post to Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18888/147640)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16250/147640)

Comment: @Jan : SO t-shirts?? how do i get it???? :D

Comment: I am on active on this site from more than year , now I come to know its only shirt. I was hoping for a jeans and pair of shoes also

Comment: Reasons. They're all mine! I'd like a t-shirt though please

Comment: `does the reputation next to the user name make you proud?` **Ya.**

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I am not sure how answerable this question really is because ***everyone*** participates for their own reasons, but I will offer my own reasons and hope that it covers a fair share of the community.

1. Stack Overflow has given me so much that I want to give back how I can.  I don't program professionally (at least it is not my primary job description), but I have learned a lot from Stack Overflow to help me with my personal projects, and the professional projects I undertake to help make my job easier.
2. I enjoy being part of a community and helping out however I can.  I am not an expert, so answering unanswerable questions is not something I can usually help with, so I try to help with moderation functions.
3. For the times I do have programming problems and need Stack Overflow to help me, I get greatly annoyed when I find a garbage question or answer, when I expected to find a solution to my problem.  So by helping moderate the crap that is out there, I can help someone else find their solution more easily.

Meta participation itself is part of all of those reason.  By helping people understand the site or learn how to participate better, you help make the site better, even if you don't directly help improve the site by reviewing or performing other moderation functions.

Comment: I am influenced by your 2nd point, and like your thinking. Keep up the good work, +1.

Comment: All of those, but also, just sometimes, [someone is wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Answer (score 86):

I live by simple rules:

> Give back to things that give to you.

Comment: The question is why people edit, flag and contribute to meta. You don't seem to have done either of that much, no offense.

Comment: What if you are given a headache, or 30 days notice, or chlamydia?

Comment: Give this man a cookie!

Comment: @Persijn - `setcookie("prize", $_75g, time() + 4);` - _PHP style_ - Starting now you have 4 seconds to eat!

Comment: @CliffBurton `document.cookie="dataCookie=EATME; expires=Monday, 31-des-2015 24:00:00 GMT";`

Answer (score 53):

Most people probably answer and comment for the recognition that votes and comments provide. An upvote or a comment is an implicit "thank you, you did something awesome!". If you took that away then posting an answer would be like shouting into a black hole. Nothing comes back. I wouldn't answer.

Another aspect is systematizing and organizing. Many developers find that appealing. Cleaning answers up, deleting bad stuff, following the rules to the letter... Very nice activities for people who are usually introverted and have a job where thrive by doing just that. Some developers border on having [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) or [Aspergers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome) (nothing wrong with that; that's the way we are built and it is a strength for us).

And frankly, I think some developers have boring jobs or boring evenings. There sometimes is not enough content on the web to consume. Answering kills time in a fun way.

Another common motivation is leveling up with reputation and badges. That's what those things are *for*.

Many people say they want to give back or do something good for the world. I doubt that is the true motivation for most. Take away the social feedback and make answering questions less interesting and they all would be gone. Philanthropic work really is not what makes people actually use Stack Overflow.

Except for a few who are truly altruistically driven when participating here. I recognize that.

Using Stack Overflow is just a fun thing to do. The Stack Overflow team intentionally makes this site a game. They say that themselves and it's a good thing.

It is a testament to the genius of the founders how well this motivation treadmill works. As a fellow Internet entrepreneur I bow in respect.

Comment: +1 for the honesty, that's somehow what I expected but didn't expect to hear if you get what I mean

Comment: For some of us, it _really is_ just about the community. If I wanted more rep, I'm sure that at this point in my programming career, I could easily throw out answers to dupe/crappy questions and start grabbing rep. I personally actually _do_ just want to make the site a better place so that others trying to struggle their way through a trial-by-fire programming career can find good questions/answers to help with their problems. (On that note, great answer- You did an excellent job of outlining various reasons that many people don't really want to admit is a huge draw for them.)

Comment: @Kendra thanks, I improved the answer in reaction to your comment. I agree with you.

Comment: "_Many developers border on having OCD or Aspergers_" and "_many developers have boring jobs or boring evenings_". I don't think these are accurate insights. The virgin weirdo with glasses and looking like he just woke up is a stereotype, not a developer

Comment: @chiapa yeah, I guess that's too much of a generalization. Fixed.

Comment: @chiapa: long hair, addicted to coffee, and sporting an RS232 plug tattoo; is that better?

Comment: @Jongware, nah man, you're way off :)

Comment: @chiapa: I'd better add it to my profile then. :D

Answer (score 24):

Because there aren't quite so many people who are smart, willing to explain things and can write properly. You need those people on the site to keep it up.

In the years I've been online I've seen plenty of communities crash and burn because the knowledgeable people left. They usually left because of quality problems or clique forming.

By helping to keep the quality high through flagging, voting and discussing what is acceptable and expected behavior, at least I hope to help build towards a community that will stay healthy for longer than the average online community.

Answer (score 14):

user2, we live in the era of "pro-sumption" sites.  This term, coined by [Toffler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvin_Toffler), means businesses where (incredibly) the actual "consumers" of the site -- the customers -- actually "produce" the content; they actually do the work. For free! And willingly!

(You can go ahead and trivially google "Toffler Prosumption" for endless books, articles, talks etc.) (I'm not going to do the "pro-sumption" chore on that!)

Oh, fuck it, I made the "pro-sumption" effort - why'd I do that?!

Here ...

*[The Prosumer Movement: a New Challenge For Marketers](http://www.acrwebsite.org/search/view-conference-proceedings.aspx?Id=6542)*

This is sort of "amazing and unbelievable" when you think about it.  But there are a million examples in modern life.

It used to be that at the airport, staff members of the airline you are paying money to, would type in all your details.  Now, we do that ourselves (often online) - and amazingly we don't complain, we "put up with it" - in fact we rather like it.  Same deal with bank ATMs.

Same deal with any number of large, famous businesses of our day where the "consumers" amazingly enough actually do the work of "producing" the product ... this goes for review sites, amazon's reviews, and so on - not to mention in a way social media - and just many huge categories of dot-com business.

Wikipedia ("our future repository of knowledge" and all that) **is of course a pro-sumption business**, perhaps the biggest. Incredibly, the consumers go ahead and **do all the work**.

So, Stack Exchange is indeed a "pro-sumption" business, in Toffler's natty term.

Now your astute question...

#### Why (the hell) do people do this?

Indeed, this is one of the **major business questions, of our era**. Every time you have a new client coming to you with a pro-sumption idea they want implemented as a startup, everyone sits around with a bottle of cheap whisky and wonders why the hell people so willingly do all the work.  We used to expect Encyclopedia Britannica would do the work for us (e.g., "hire writers", etc.) now for some reason we willingly do the work - pro-sumption.  I wonder why I have "contributed" dozens of articles to [Tripadvisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripadvisor) (which I would otherwise have charged six figures for the lot) ...for free.  With old-fashioned business models like, say, real estate agents, you pay a fee and the company comes and "takes photos" and "puts it on the web", etc.; with futuristic business models like [Airbnb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbnb), you pay a fee and then .............. you do all the work! Why is this so popular? It beats me.

Sure, there are minor side arguments: like, on SO I answer a few iOS questions, since in an obtuse way it helps me get *my* iOS questions answered (setting aside [prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma) issues)...but those are minor issues.  People run to, they are happy to, do all the work on "pro-sumption" businesses! Go figure!

In general, you've basically hit on, as I say, one of the major business questions, even social, questions of our day.  Everyone wants to know the answer; I don't think there's been any breaking psychological studies on what the answer is - but it's a huge, unanswered, question.

In interesting phenomenon is that many folks get **really angry** when they realise they've been on the "production" side of "production for free, to help dot-com millionaires get rich".  But almost everyone just keeps doing it - it's so fun writing posts like this!

Answer to your question: as yet, nobody knows why; but it's one of the major business phenomenons of our era.  (As is often the case, amazing kudos to Toffler for essentially predicting it all at the earliest point.)

---

An interesting point.  I've always felt Toffler made a rare case of his choosing the wrong wrong there.  I find "pro-sumption" ("**pro**duction by con**sumers**) rather clunky.  It should of course be...

#### Con-duction

**Con**sumers surprisingly actually doing the pro**duction**, and doing it willingly, for free, or even paying to do so.  "con-duction" is clearer to me that "pro-sumption".  I feel an initialism (PBC) would have been best and clearer.

Comment: _"Now, we do that ourselves (often online) - and amazingly we don't complain, we 'put up with it' - in fact we rather like it"_ Woah hang on there! Not really. The fact that we have to do most of the check-in procedure for airlines _ourselves_, for free, at risk of a huge fine if we forget or if it's inconvenient, is a frequent source of complaints over the low-budget airline model. I really don't think this is a good example!!

Comment: Hi Light!  Sure, we could discuss whether people do or don't like (say) using ATMs, the airline example etc,; not really the focus of the QA at hand.  The point is, user28 should realise he's asked a "really big question" which is hotly discussed today; indeed it's absolutely central to many of today's biggest businesses.

Comment: I'm just disputing the relevance or benefit of the example you chose, that's all. You're the one who decided it was relevant to the QA at hand, not me! :)

Comment: Can you link to your Toffler reference? I want to know why Kudos.

Comment: I think the **pro**sumption as the opposite of **con**sumption makes some sense, but I don't think consumption is based on contra. It's a neat but complicated word play. Still, I like your term _conduction_ more. It does have something in common with the [actual meaning of the word](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conduction) (simple on purpose).

Answer (score 11):

My motivation is quite strange: life is boring, lessons are boring, and working is boring...:-(

Flagging, voting, and commenting is an excellent way to consume my time:D

Comment: I just up-voted your comment ... cuz I had the time to kill while reading through this during the last fractions of my lunch-break.

You are so right, and I think I applies more often then "I want to safe the world" ... it just sounds a lot worse does it not?

Comment: Procrastination in other words?

Answer (score 11):

It's the [gamification](http://blog.codinghorror.com/level-one-the-intro-stage/). Mostly [that](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-worlds-largest-mmorpg-youre-playing-it-right-now/). Don't [believe it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-stack-overflow)? Check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170115151749/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you).

Comment: Though, as is the case with addicts of other sorts, we're all in denial (hence it took so long for anyone to suggest this as the *real* answer).

Comment: @eggyal Denial? _What_ denial?!

Answer (score 9):

To me it's like walking in a library - I love the smell of books, I like to take them out and see the cover, I like to take one out and read it. Whenever I see a book on the ground or sitting unattended on a counter, visibly abandoned, I take it to where it belongs.

My actions are very similar to the ones I do in a library - I visit questions to see what interests other people. Sometimes I encounter questions where I ask myself - "hey why didn't I ask this question?" and I read it along with the answers. When an answer doesn't satisfy my curiosity I do some research and add the knowledge there, because maybe there is somebody like me who likes browsing and wouldn't be happy with simple one-liner answer.

Why would I flag, edit or moderate in general? Because some users are *not yet* informed how to behave in a library such as SO. Just like there are librarians (moderators), there are those enthusiastic bookworms who just like to keep the place nice for everybody - afterall it's one of the main scout rules - "Always leave the campground cleaner than you found it."

And why would I discuss things here on meta or argue about unrelated topics? Because discussion makes us better people - it shows us the views of other people we haven't considered before. It enhances our opinions and widens our knowledge.

Comment: Re *"Always leave the campground cleaner than you found it."*: It could have been made up by [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin). I have ***never*** been able to find the source for it. Perhaps Uncle Bob derived it from [the founder's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Baden-Powell,_1st_Baron_Baden-Powell#Scouting_Movement) *"Try and leave this world a little better than you found it"*?

Answer (score 8):

Refactoring questions is pretty similar to refactoring code, its maintenance on a communal library of problems and their solutions. Moderating just keeps it something that everyone can read, understand and reference.

Answer (score 8):

You learn some and you give some.

Knowledge is something to be shared, not to be kept to oneself.
If you die, you will not pass the knowledge you've learned to pass, but it will go to waste.

Passing information to the next generation is so they can carry our discoveries.

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow is just part of my programming work flow at this point. It's like Evernote for programmers, except multitudes of programmers are helping me keep it correct and up-to-date for free.

- If I have a problem I need an answer to, I look for it on Stack Overflow.
- If I find a good answer that's useful to me, I upvote it. This helps me know which answer I chose the next time I google the same question, my memory is that bad.
- If I don't find a good answer, I find out, and then I publish the question and answer on Stack Overflow. That way, I can find the answer again in the future, and people will improve and correct it for me for free.

I don't look for answer questions that are not relevant to me much any more, but when I did it was because I found it fun, because I wanted to learn, and because I wanted to have a good profile to include in my CV. The fact that it's all released under CC BY-SA feels fair to me, so I don't feel taken advantage of.

Answer (score 6):

For me it’s simple:

I want to contribute to a better world where I would like to live.

This is one of way for doing the same.

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, I needed points for giving a bounty to one of my questions (spoiler: it worked, thank you guys).

To be politically correct, world peace, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Being human, giving it back :-)

Answer (score -6):

Fake Internet points.

I get two of them each time I improve a post.