# Is there such a thing like reputation creep in SO?

Tags: discussion

Before getting to reputation creep, I'd like to clarify first power creep. In game development, power creep is where players have so much power that they don't do "mundane" tasks anymore. For those players the developers have to add new content that is adequate to their level of expertise and power (skill, hit points, stamina, etc.) Those new content additions, be it new levels, zones, NPCs, will instantly kill new players but they serve as an incentive for them too, so that those new players will try to level up to be able to handle or gain access to the new content.

Now, back to SO, my guess is that user with thousands of points experience something similar when they unlock access to some moderation tasks. They stop writing answers to questions that would have little or no up-votes, even when they might be the ones that could give the right answer. They seems to limit their interaction to write some comment, or to post a link, and they spend most of the time policing the site instead, ensuring that all the new content that is created have the level of quality that they can deliver, but that they aren't willing to do anymore.

Power creep might work for games, but I think it just doesn't for SO, because new users don't thing like new players in a game. They don't see some user of SO with thousands of points policing the site, and say, wow! I'd like to be a moderator too. What happens is that they get scared away, and instead of trying to improve the content they just wrote, they go to Google the answer, or to some other site.

I'm also asking the same question in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/7z5x5r/is_there_such_a_thing_like_reputation_creep_in_so/?ref=share&ref_source=link), so feel free to post some comments there too.

---

**Update:**

I couldn't post my comment to the answer by Servy because it's too long, so I'm adding it here since it complements the original question:

> I think newcomers are thankful to find high quality content like the
>   one in the SO sites, and would want to ask some question they might have
>   right away. Normally what they would expect is some comment pointing
>   where to find the answer, or maybe someone posting the answer they are
>   looking for. Although the most likely thing to happen is that they
>   will get a down-vote in that question, no comment, no suggestion, no
>   answer, just a down-vote. It seems harsh to me compared to other
>   sites, where the worst thing that could happen is that their posts
>   would get buried in the search results, thanks to some obscure
>   algorithm, to never be seen again. In practice the effect would be the
>   same, with the user not coming back to the site, although for entirely
>   different reasons. In one hand they wouldn't want to come back if they
>   don't get an answer, which is how other sites work, and in the other
>   hand they freak out and tell everybody that SO is such a harsh
>   environment. Also I've noticed that most of the time that harshness
>   increases with how old is the site, which makes me think the cause is
>   related to which users are more actively involved in the site,
>   therefore my original question.

---

**Update 2:**

[**Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)

Comment: I think your question was better suited to Reddit than Meta.

Comment: _What happens is that they get scared away [..] they go to Google the answer_ if only that were true..

Comment: If I know the answer, but I don't want the rep or I can't be bothered with looking for the almost-inevitable dupes, I often just drop a quick hint in a comment, eg 'No space for NUL terminators', or 'You must correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like recv()'.

Comment: _Just to prove my point..._ what point does posting it on Reddit prove, exactly?

Comment: @Clive Is there such a thing like reputation creep in SO?

Comment: @rraallvv And how is that point proven by posting it on Reddit?

Comment: Perhaps you actually meant _Just to get arbitrary opinions from people who wouldn't know_ instead?

Comment: see also [What makes you guys improve this board so much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305524/839601)

Comment: There are probably creeps with reputation..

Comment: This was a decent post until you got to the last two paragraphs which in essence should have been an answer and greatly detracted from the ability of the community to address an unbiased starting point for discussion.

Comment: *They stop writing answers to questions that would have little or no up-votes...* That's a function of experience on the site, not reputation. It only takes a few instances of answering questions that get deleted, trying to answer an unclear question and getting down voted, or attempting to answer a question that gets put on hold before you can finish for you to realize you should focus on well asked, well received questions. Anyone who's been answering a while will do this regardless of their reputation  level.

Comment: If they can go to google and get their answer there, and seeing a high rep user makes them scared and go do rhe research that should have been done in the first place... isn't this a great thing?

Comment: So @rraallvv did you put some more thought on all this?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No, the post titled "[Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)" already did that for me.

Comment: No need for the snark @rraallvv. That was a genuine question.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier After reading that post there is very little to be added. That's what I was trying to say, sorry if it seems I was being defensive.

Comment: @rraallvv In retrospect, yours was really not a snarky comment. I think the "did that for me" part gave me the impression you were blindly following any and every idea proposed in the blog.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Interestingly enough, I found that post days after I asked the question, which makes me think Internet functions sometimes as some kind of collective consciousness but at a subconscious level, or rather a collective subconsciousness.

Answer (score 25):

You'll find that most of the people focusing their time on site moderation over answering bad questions is not because they don't earn enough rep from answering bad questions, but rather their experience has shown them that answering bad questions isn't productive, not for them, not for the question author, not for the site, and not for the programming community in general.

This community was *founded* on the idea that *quality* questions that attract *quality* answers are so many orders of magnitude more useful, and that it's more productive to try to help a bad question be improved into a good one, and *then* provide a quality answer, than to try to provide whatever meager answer is possible with the low quality question as it sits.  Users new to the site often don't understand this mentality as it's just so divergent from every other Q/A site out there.

Also note that for active answerers regularly answering lots of questions, they will generally get literal *zero* reputation from most answers, due to the rep cap, rather than your theory of them getting an amount too small for them to consider meaningful when compared to their total reputation.

> They don't see some user of SO with thousands of points policing the site, and say, wow! I'd like to be a moderator too.

We don't *want* users to be doing that.  We want users to be using the moderation tools because they inherently buy in to the site's model that quality content is important, and to have *implicit* motivation to want to make the site, and the programming community at large a better place.  The reputation thresholds exists primarily to make sure that users aren't able to abuse those moderation privileges before they've proven themselves to be trustworthy enough to use them appropriately, and also to ensure that they've had enough experience using the site to know when and how those privileges are meant to be used (after all reputation is a *far* better approximation of experience using the site than it is of technical expertise).

> What happens is that they get scared away, and instead of trying to improve the content they just wrote, they go to Google the answer

Fantastic.  We *want* people to be searching for their answer on Google first, rather than just posting their question here right away.  If they *haven't* done their due diligence searching for existing answers to their question we don't *want* them asking their question here.  It isn't going to be a useful question if the answer is already readily accessible.

Comment: I could't add my comment here because it's too long, so I've attached it as an update to the original question, thanks.

Comment: @rraallvv Your statement that users have entirely unrealistic expectations of the site in which they think it's okay to post bad content, not follow the rules, be inconsiderate of the other users, and also to expect everyone else to refuse to provide accurate feedback on the quality of their contributions, and to personally tutor them on how to use the site (despite the *wealth* of information we provide to new users on how to post a good question) is just not something I have sympathy for.  The people that act appropriately and provide useful contributions have a good experience.

Comment: The majority of people always have unrealistic expectation about pretty much everything. Heck! that's why most people get married. SO is not different, I'm afraid.

Comment: @rraallvv What's your point?  I'm not saying that people aren't allowed to have unrealistic expectations, or that it's rare to have unrealistic expectations, just that we're not obligated to try to meet their unrealistic and inappropriate expectations.

Answer (score 11):

Answering questions isn't mundane, moderating the site is. Editing, flagging, voting and closing questions is much, much more tedious and less rewarding than writing an answer.

However, 99.9% of new questions are debugging questions of which neither the asker, the answerer nor the site improves with getting an answer. So I don't answer them.

Answer (score 4):

The point of a game is (Generally) to gain power.

The rewards system that games are based on are framed to make people think they are attaining some goal, and as they achieve more goals, they have more power and more liberty to do as they please in the game. However, this is the principal focus of the game, so if a person gets to a certain level, they stop doing the parts they don't like or no longer need, like the mundane tasks you mention. This happens because of the game's purpose.

The point of Stack Overflow is (Generally) to contribute to the question and answer repository, finding answers their own questions and helping others find their answers.

The rewards system that Stack Overflow has through reputation is framed to make people think they are attaining some goal, and as they achieve more goals, they have more reputation and more liberty to do as they please on the site, being allowed to vote, comment, downvote, review, etc. However, the principal focus of Stack isn't the reputation, it's the questions and answers, and the reputation system simply encourages that. Users with more reputation, although they might have additional privileges that they can use as they gain more rep, aren't here to gain rep, they're here to help contribute to the site. And all the privileges help a user contribute in new, very important ways.

Of course there are exceptions to both rules. Some gamers just love and keep doing the mundane tasks in spite of power creep. Some people are on Stack Overflow because they want rep and privileges. But those people tend to get bored and leave with time, because Stack Overflow isn't built to cater to someone who isn't actually interested in contributing to the site.

Likewise, if someone new desires to contribute to Stack Overflow, then seeing people with loads of reputation isn't going to scare them away, it will simply be a number on their screen. The person will be focused on the actual content of the questions and answers, will be interested in participating, and the reputation will come as the user participates. If a user is scared away by large rep users, then the user is more focused on points than Q/A, so maybe that user should be playing a game and not participating on Stack Overflow, as they care more about points than actual question and answer quality.

Stack Overflow is good at what it does, and its users and community contribute to a common goal. Rep is just a facilitator, but the driving force is people wanting to provide quality questions and answers.

**TL;DR**
No. There is no reputation creep(, although there are some reputable creeps).