# Are moderation/curation activities rewarded?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

First things first: I'm not asking this question for the *reputation* points' sake.

I'm just interested whether the [pro]active moderation of the posts (questions and answers), namely: voting for closing/re-opening the question, is anyhow rewarded to the user?

I'm new to the reputation which enables the *vote to close* privilege, and I kind of like to participate in the process for the betterment of the site. I also observe, that so far, I have mostly (>95%) voted for the *correct closures*, and I have so far been proving the reasons accordingly.

Participating for keeping the site a bit cleaner and better place, is, I think, quite important thing to do... but doing it forever, just without *any motivation* whatsoever, seems to me kind of predictable to get tiring and boring.

Is there any motivation for the user to actively keep monitoring the sanity of the site?

Comment: The only ongoing reward is the intrinsic reward of curation, of doing your part to maintain the place so it can help others.

Comment: I think I have provided the reason why that can get tiring and boring after some time.

Comment: That doesn't invalidate my statement in any sense.

Comment: You will also get you share of "those @#$@ elitist moderators downtrodden my perfectly valid request to write my homework for me" comments/meta-posts as reward. Not really sure if that is positive motivation you are looking for so :)

Comment: I remember when it was a good thing to be elite. What's wrong with kids today? Hell, what's wrong with their parents? Ah well. Alt least I can take solace in the fact that there are [elite cods out there](https://codelite.org/), even if I can't figure out what makes a cod elite.

Comment: There are many kind of motivations, including negative ones: *"I don't want Stack Overflow to become yet another horrible forum, [hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange), or [Yahoo Answers](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed)."*

Comment: @gnat, no, it certainly doesn't, and it is itself a duplicate of [another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305524/what-makes-you-improve-this-board-so-much) question. Kindly retract your *duplicate* vote on this one.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Duplicates can be duplicates of other duplicates :D

Comment: As I already said, this is not a duplicate of *What people get* questiin. Could whoever's closed this undo their actions? Guys, stop disregarding what the other side thinks and always act liks super self-assured and subjective ones. It's not really cool and I'm seeing this again and again here. **Read theae two questions at least**.  And just respect what others say. You're **not always right**. Having an ability to do something doesn't mean you should be doing that always.

Comment: So, I disagreed the duplicate, for a simple reason. OP is asking if the system/site rewards the user for doing moderation activities, the other is asking the general community their specific motivations of doing moderation activities. Two angles to the "what makes users tick" question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov not to mention the accompanying revenge downvotes.

Comment: @user4581301 chips, peas, salt and vinegar.

Comment: You have to define "reward". For most people a reward is something like a cookie, a pat on the head, a thank you card, money, a free meal ticket or that 15 piece pots and pans set that you always wanted. On Stack Overflow a reward usually comes in the form of the privilege to do more janitorial duties for free.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there is no reward, in the sense of normal rewards that exist on SO; more often you'll receive negative reactions instead. You kinda have to come up with and maintain your own justification for doing it, such as "keeping the site clean" or whatever... but it requires a lot more than just one person to do the job. It can often feel like a thankless, meaningless effort because you rarely see the impact that your work (or that of others in this regard) has.

Just know that you're not alone and can probably find like-minded people in various [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) groups if not here on meta.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. Your response relates exactly to the sense I have about this concern. I think, this is not the best way how to *motivate* people participate in this kind of moderation. I'm really motivated, and doing so good so far, but based from my life experience, I know, that *enthusiastic* work does not last very long in the same active shape. Can we, kind of, make this question something like a poll, or a request to the SO administration, so that they might consider amending existing policy with this respect?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Another motivation I use is staring at my flag count... it kinda helps to motivate me. You can do the same for your close vote count.

Comment: IMO, the most healthy way to approach it is to look for questions to answer and moderate/curate *those* questions. If all you do is look for garbage, it's all you'll ever find.

Comment: @KevinB that's how I do it. I'm not scrolling just to find the question for closing it. However, still.. I think, this is not the best design people might feel encouraged about this.

Comment: Do you people think, that we can, kind of, make this question something like a poll, or a request to the SO administration, so that they might consider amending existing policy with this respect? I'm not sure how the *requests*, for the new features, are made here. So, just asking.

Comment: No, not really. Polls don't move the needle. It would need to be proposed in the form of a fully fleshed out feature request, complete with pros/cons and what problem is being solved as well as proof that a problem exists.

Comment: @KevinB kind of an official proposal request.. with all the pros, cons, considerations, motivations, and etc., something like Enhancement Proposal Document for Java Community Process. :) Then, it seems really complicated to me.. one more proposal, on the fly - to watch actively the most upvoted question on the meta, and consider seriously what they're about to be proposing. :)

Comment: On top of what @KevinB said about feature-requests: there is basically zero chance FR requesting work from the company would have any impact (at least based on FR for last several years). You may have better luck to have impact if it is policy-only suggestion that can be implemented without any coding from the company...

Answer (score 9):

There's only the same reward that you get for doing any other task on Stack Overflow: **the feeling of satisfaction when you help others**.

There are no monetary rewards, there are no reputation points awarded and there's barely any prestige in doing so. You get badges for performing some curation activities, but they are just meaningless flair.

The reason why we all contribute to this site is to maintain a helpful repository of common questions and answers to programming-related problems. If you find a question that acts against this goal, then by voting to close and delete you help in the overall goal of Stack Overflow.

**Thank you for your continuing effort in keeping the site clean!**

Comment: I actually have said, that I enjoy doing what I do; however, I'm quite far from your points, that everything is always with just the pleasure of *voluntary enthusiasm*. This sounds very positive and even romantic, but at some point, I'm pretty sure, that anyone will get tired of doing repetitive work w/o anything in return.

Comment: Jon has been doing great work for SO; yet, I think, that he has [rightfully] received quite a reward from SO alike.

Comment: eh, it's all about what *you* feel a sense of accomplishment for. People who answer questions a lot are doing so because they feel satisfaction in doing so. maybe they like seeing that magical rep number climb, maybe they like seeing that little green checkmark, maybe they just like knowing that someone else out there in the world found their efforts useful. but noone can tell you what you will find satisfactory, or what you feel joy in, and what drives you can certainly change over time.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri giving rep, for example, would certainly motivate a group of people who are motivated by rep, but what about the rest of us? same with badges, and achievements, etc. it's just rare to find satisfaction in an action that a large number of people don't appreciate.

Comment: @KevinB I completely agree. I find more satisfaction in seeing my number of helpful flags and edited posts grow more than the reputation points.

Comment: @KevinB that's what my first line of the question stands for. I don't, *particularly*, speak about reputation, badges, or etc.;however, from my SO experience, there're different ways to motivate people here, including (not limited to): Reputation, Badges, Privileges, Tag Badges, etc. (might be more). So, I won't lie and won't say, that I don't care about reputation or badges **at all** (maybe I won't, after having 250k), but it isn't my top motivational aspect. I just mean, that over some time, I'm almost sure, the repetitive *no-reward* job would get boring.. something should keep people on.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, yes. There are rewards in the way of badges for moderation/curation activities. [The moderation badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) is a prime example of that. But other than that, there's no intrinsic reward built in the system that rewards users for such activities.