# Congratulations to EdChum for 100,000 close reviews!

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, specific-user

The [Close Votes review stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) shows that [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) performed **100,000 close vote reviews**.

> [image]

Getting content properly rated is very important to me because this [helps me use the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386671/839601) and I would like to use this milestone as an opportunity to express appreciation for outstanding contribution and effort.

Thanks for your dedication Ed!

Comment: readers willing to check more review details [at user profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum?tab=activity&sort=reviews) may notice that it shows smaller number of reviews (_much_ smaller, like 40-something thousands instead of 100). The reason for this difference is that in profile page system hides reviews on questions that were later deleted

Comment: This is actually a good thing to thank for. I hope this post will get featured like the others.

Comment: How is it possible that there are thousand separators in the top three blocks but not in the actual "All time" column? The failure of this site to consistently format numbers is such a disgrace.

Comment: Remember when andrewsi was the top reviewer on SO? Pepperidge farm remembers.

Comment: He is one of my super-heroes. The person, I know, I could never become, but the one that I cannot help but always look up to. I wish him all the best and an eventful retirement.

Comment: A month late, but yes it is quite the impressive achievement!

Comment: I know this is something to be celebrated, but I can't help but feel some kind of sadness here.  This person did 100K reviews and decided that they were done with SO after that.  This kind of thing can drive a person up a wall and all we can do is pat them on the back.  I wish Stack Exchange would do more to laud this rather than us cheering them on.

Comment: @TylerH given that it took over 6 years to reach I think that a month here or there doesn't matter much :) (100,000 is 2500 days by 40 reviews a day)

Comment: I applaud the dedication here, but my word what a miserable time EdChum must have had getting there. Also, what do they get for it? Not a single thing.

Comment: @DavidG given that in the meantime Ed managed to get 250+K rep I suppose that it didn't took that much time (my own experience is, it takes 3-5 minutes to do daily 40 reviews, or maybe 10 if you are unlucky). As for what reviewers / curators get for their effort, this was quite thoroughly discussed eg [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305524/839601) (and the linked post in this very congratulation hints at that too, "To me, Stack Overflow is a tool. I use this tool in my job and I just need to keep it sharp.")

Comment: @gnat He could have gotten to 250k rep a lot easier had he not done those reviews. I suspect 3-5 minutes per 40 is conservative, but if it averaged to 4 minutes, that's still 7 solid days of doing nothing but those reviews. FWIW I'm not bashing Ed, I'm (slightly) bashing the review system.

Comment: @DavidG Most reviews do not take 4 minutes to complete. More like 15 seconds. Also, what does EdChum get for it? Bragging rights and his name plastered at the top of the list; a position that is *very hard* to topple. Even greg, right behind him, will need to keep doing 40 reviews a day to surpass him *next year*.

Comment: @TylerH Nevertheless, greg-449's stats are also nice. And greg appears in suggested edits, and LQP.

Comment: Re: _"I know this is something to be celebrated, but I can't help but feel some kind of sadness here. This person did 100K reviews and decided that they were done with SO after that."_ Yes, I agree. It's depressing. SO is about co-education - asking questions and answering each other's questions. Helping each other. Growing an educational community. It's not about shitwork. This sort of thing is just _janitorial work_ which paid SO employees don't want to do. However, since they're paid employees, they absolutely _should_ be doing the janitorial work, not offloading it onto unpaid volunteers.

Comment: There should really be a badge for this kind of dedication, but whatever, people who do this do not care about the badge anyway.

Comment: @Makoto "I wish Stack Exchange would do more to laud this rather than us cheering them on." But what? A medal? Meaningless. Money? We could never adequately pay him for 100k reviews and probably he never expected anything. A stake in the decision making? Not gonna happen. Ed knew what this platform is and he donated his time nevertheless. Only thing we can do is salute him and show absolute understanding that enough is enough at some point. If you have a better idea, I'm all ears.

Comment: I too can't help but feel some kind of sadness here. That users must do thousands and thousands of reviews to even keep the site halfway decent reflects that we and the company still haven't found a solution that doesn't require that much unthankful work, i.e. avoiding the need to review as much as possible upfront. It feels to me like over the years we and the company kind of took the free work there for granted and that did not exactly speedup the ideas to find a better solution.

Comment: @DavidG "Also, what do they get for it? Not a single thing." It's purely altruistic. You do it because others profit from a better SO knowledge library. Personally, it's a loss of time.

Comment: @Trilarion I can't read Ed's mind but it is possible that just like it is for me, it is [investment in the tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386671/839601), "If someone feels that the above sounds selfish, well, yes it _is_ selfish. I am in it because it helps me keep a nice job with good pay..."

Comment: @gnat Yes, I have seen you and others writing that before. I have difficulties really believing it, but it doesn't matter. For whatever reason you are doing, what you are doing, I'm looking up to people like you or Ed or ...

Comment: Inspired by this great achievement I wrote this post on MSE to argue we need more review badges: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354255/review-badges-we-need-more-of-them

Comment: Thank you EdChum. you did awesome work for community

Comment: @TylerH I didn't say 4 minutes for a review, I said 4 minutes to do all 40 for a day. And yes, he gets to be the top of the list, but I didn't even know there was a list until I saw this post. For me, this is a hollow victory for him. The Sisyphean task of review queues is mostly thankless, and SO have done very little to help fix that for a long time.

Comment: @DavidG Ah, I must have inserted the "reviews" from the following line in place of the "per 40"... darn speed reading...

Comment: @gnat It feels awkward that you thank him for his awesome work (which is great!), but then comment below our own post that *I suppose that it didn't took that much time* and *I think that a month here or there doesn't matter much* ...

Comment: @barfuin if you have read comments around this one, you'd notice that we discussed how much time it is expected to take in one day - as I wrote, like 5-10 minutes, not much really (reviews are designed to only take small portion of daily time, system allows only 40 max reviews a day). Awesome part is about doing these small chunks of daily work for _over 6 years_ which resulted in 100,000 reviews total

Comment: Hi @gnat you should post one of these for greg-449.

Comment: [this was announced and celebrated at SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52049918#52049918) @bad_coder

Comment: @bad_coder ...and posted to MSO as well: [Congratulations greg-449, on reaching 100,000 close vote reviews!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407167/839601)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

[Thank you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DitE_e3VDMk)

Comment: hope your retirement eventually turns into [sabbatical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatical) :)

Comment: Thank you Ed. Also thank you for that video. What a brilliant video that is? Never seen it before btw.

Answer (score 98):

> [image: user profile screen-shot, showing a description stating that the user is "retired from SO after hitting 100K close queue reviews"]

Come on, Ed. You can make it to 200k!

Thanks a 100k for the effort anyway.

I hope you change your mind and come back for another 100k. Those queues are not going the get cleared by themselves, you know?

Comment: They're not going to be cleared by EdChum either even if he does come back. It'll take years for him to get that other 100k :) What we need is people to feel inspired by this achievement, because a hundred people doing 1k reviews makes a far bigger dent in a shorter time period... I'm one, need 99 more.

Comment: @Gimby hard to do when they're handing out review bans like candy at Halloween.

Comment: I would imagine somehow EdChum managed not to be review-suspended very often to get to that impressive number. Wonder how they did.

Comment: @yivi it's not difficult, really. I for one did about 2/3 of Ed's reviews and had no single suspension. It's all a matter of focus and selection

Comment: You are right, @gnat. Although remind me to mark certain comments of mine with `/s`, for example. Tongue in cheek is not always clearly understood. It's on me for conveying it poorly.

Comment: I wonder why EdChum quit in the first place.

Comment: This was one of the coolest mic-drops I have ever seen. It reminded me of Forrest Gump after running for a few months and then quitting.

Comment: @10Rep Probably something to do with events from the past year or two. Perhaps 100k CV reviews was a prior commitment that he wanted to see through.

Comment: @yivi probably because the queue vigilantes are not paying attention to the close queue (yet.)

Comment: Sorry @miken32, I don’t understand what you mean

Answer (score 64):

Thank you, EdChum.

I had difficulty making it to the 1,000 mark in that queue. I cannot begin to imagine getting to 10,000, let alone achieving what you have.

Not all heroes wear capes, but some of them are here on Stack Overflow, and you're one of them. Enjoy your retirement - no one is more deserving of a rest, and all the effort in the world would have gone to waste...

Answer (score 25):

This is incredible, and thank you EdChum for making Stack Overflow a better-curated site.

I stopped sometime right after I reached 1000 reviews and got the Steward badge and can't even dream of what you have achieved.

Answer (score 23):

Well, I don't know @EdChum from his review reputation, but certainly do know him as a Python <kbd>pandas</kbd> and <kbd>numpy</kbd> gold badge guru: [Top 10 in Pandas and Top 30 in NumPy](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1294886/pandas-and-numpy-gold-badge-holders)!

Congrats on all feats!

Answer (score 10):

This is incredible. It inspires people like me to reach 3k and do my bit for the community. For the people who are new, the Close Votes review queue is to

> Vote whether or not to close questions with close votes

so if you have 3k reputation, you'll be able to close questions which you think are not up to the standards.

Again, reaching 100k reviews needs dedication, sheer will, commitment and focus.

He's the John Wick of the SO community.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations to EdChum for hitting [1Lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) close vote reviews.