# Congratulations greg-449, on reaching 100,000 close vote reviews!

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

A few minutes ago, I saw, on the [SO Close-vote Review Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), that [greg-449](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) has reached the six-figure mark on close vote reviews:

[image]

That's a remarkable feat that only EdChum has managed to replicate (or the other way around), to me especially because reviewing seems a thankless task.  Thank you, Greg; it inspires me to reach for 3000 reputation to assist with the 4.8K+ close vote review tasks on SO.  That's a lot of dedication, to me more so than the 1M-rep mark.

To reach 100,000 reviews, you'd need to review 40 times *every day* for about 7 years!

Congratulations, and thank you!

Comment: May be not the most popular topic, but my honors too for both!

Comment: Thanks. Like EdChum I have decided that is enough, at least for now. My feeling is that the close votes queue has become a lot harder lately, skipping a lot of questions to find things I was sure about.

Comment: @greg-449 just for the jokes do one more review. You'd be in the lead for quite a long time :)

Comment: @10Rep I think it's reasonable to stop at 100,000 and leave the order intact. Perhaps it's a sign of respect for EdChum? :)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I kinda twitched reading your last sentence. I mean, I think there is no reason to compare between the feats. Reaching 1M rep is a hard task and shows a lot of dedication as well and it literally shows how helpful you are for the site and everybody visiting it...

Comment: To review 100,000 times, you have to review at minimum 40 times a day for nearly 7 years.

Comment: @greg-449 congrats!

Comment: @Tomerikoo from a curation standpoint this is more impressive, but again, I do agree that they both require dedication.

Comment: Congratulations to both of you @EdChum and greg-449  Thanks for all your service and great help to this community !!

Comment: If my math is correct, if each review takes just 15 seconds (they often take much longer), that represents over 17 days of non-stop reviews performed 24/7.

Comment: Ahhhhh... math is fun.  There three kinds of people.  Those who can count and those who can't!

Comment: wow! So awesome numbers! Thanks for your efforts! :)

Comment: @greg-449  Thank you so much! I wish I could do more to show my appreciation. A clean site with high signal to noise ratio is something everyone in the world profits of maybe without realizing it every day. And yes, it's very hard work and I can fully understand the retirement. Enjoy your time and freedom.

Comment: @0-1 this does put things into perspective. Kudos!

Comment: Thanx for doing all this work, greg-449 !

Comment: Wait, to make it clear, did both Ed and Greg simply decided to stop exactly at 100k, or is there some limit for reviews (or at least for the counter)?

Comment: @Tomerikoo There's no limit AFAIK (why should there be?)

Comment: Also note that [greg-449](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) has performed exactly [50,000](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) suggested edit reviews and [53,000](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) low quality post reviews. Making a grand total of *203,000* reviews.

Comment: @Tomerikoo There is no limit, I just decided I didn't want to go past Ed as I was about to stop.

Comment: SO needs a swag pack sent to folks for reaching these amazing feats if they don't already do something like that behind the scenes

Comment: @0-1 And a staggering 203 Steward badges.  Crikey.

Comment: How does one even get to that amount of reputation? really impressive,
congrats!

Comment: Perhaps I misread, but the idea people are actively _looking_ for questions to close is quite sad and supports the view that SO is less friendly these days. Certainly compared to the early days when everyone was here to help. I wish the community was trying to help people improve questions, not just vote to close them. It seems quite a toxic environment to me these days, like the Linux message boards of old :)

Comment: @Mr.Boy I think you got the idea a bit wrong. Review is not really active: one is supposed to spend few minutes a day checking questions considered inappropriate by others and helping to close these that are off-topic. As for helping, reviewers help folks like me who use this site to find answers to our programming problems by making sure that questions about these stand out and aren't obscured by questions that won't help us. If this deprives of "help" those willing to know which sort of coffee is best for programming or how to cheat in their tomorrow homework, too bad for them

Comment: @greg-449 Feel free to post that as an answer - I'll accept it + more visibility.

Comment: @greg-449 Change your mind about stopping at 100k, eh? :-)

Comment: @TylerH Hardly anyone is doing close votes reviews so I started again

Answer (score 22):

#### Hey greg-449, congratulations on 100,000 close vote reviews!

You inspired me to continue reviewing on SO. Yeah, I got review-banned on SO some time ago and it sort of discouraged me from reviewing on SO again afterwards... of course, I've learned from it.

Seeing that you're taking a break from the queue for now, don't worry! I, and other users you inspired, will do our best to fill in the gap ;)

Thank you, and you look great up there with EdChum!