# Can I reopen (nominate) a closed duplicate questions it has more into it than the linked question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

Can I nominate a question for reopen if previously it has been closed as a duplicate if the question has more into it than the linked duplicate question? I would call it composite question.

**What do I mean by composite?**

*The linked duplicate question only answers one aspect of two (or more) that the closed question needs to be fully answered/understood.*

**Example**

[(Stack Overflow) Why 123['toString'].length returns 1? [Duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78119859/why-123tostring-length-returns-1)

Code: `console.log(123['toString'].length)`

- The duplicate question answers how the `length` property works
- For this answer it is furthermore important to understand how `123['toString']` works

I want to avoid wrong Flags/Reopenings and would like to refer to this post later on if I see similar occurrences.

Comment: Someone with a gold badge in JavaScript could edit the duplicate list to include another question that addresses the second part. That's likely the better solution here.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254710/is-there-a-benefit-to-closing-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-more-than-one-questio

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I did not know that. Beside the answers and the linked post, that helps me a lot and is a nice feature. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't.

First off, questions are supposed to be about *practical* programming problems. While there is a certain amount of insight to be gained from looking into corner cases, writing code like `123['toString'].length` is so far from having practical use that it can't help build a useful reference library.

But more importantly, a "composite" question as you describe it is pretty straightforwardly just... two questions being asked in the same place. Such questions should be closed as "Needs More Focus". (Occasionally, it makes sense to ask a how-to question that seems like it could be broken down into two steps, if a) there is a common need to perform those steps together b) there is a reasonable expectation of a way to solve the problem *that isn't* just solving the two sub-problems one after the other. However, for questions about *understanding existing code*, this rationale basically never holds up.)

Answer (score 7):

I find the duplicate to be entirely appropriate.

`123['toString']` is such a minor thing I would not think it hampers the understanding. And even if it does, it is [also a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

There are infinite number of possible combinations of other dupes. We do not need to keep each individual combination open.