# A long list of possible duplicates — C memory allocation and overrunning bounds

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The question [Why does invalid `memset()` after `malloc()` lead to `free()` invalid next size (fast) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643630/why-does-invalid-memset-after-malloc-leads-to-free-invalid-next-size-fas) has just been closed as a duplicate of:

- [free char*: invalid next size (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008077/free-char-invalid-next-size-fast)

But there are multiple other bugs in the related lists of the various questions that should probably also be closed as duplicates of this issue.  This question is primarily to document the set and get approval before using [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers) to close them as duplicates.  The list is in sorted order of increasing SO question number (`sort -u -t/ -k5n` on the list with the `*` at the front).  Thus, the canonical question is nominally the first of those listed, 'Facing an error …'.

#### Designated canonical question

- [free char*: invalid next size (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008077/free-char-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [Facing an error "*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)

#### Closed as duplicates

A few were already closed; they've been annotated with the alternative.

- [realloc(): invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939091/realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast) -- should work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722190/glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast-should-work)
- [* glibc detected * realloc(): invalid next size:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762718/glibc-detected-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [Call to free() with a string gives a *** glibc detected *** error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589843/call-to-free-with-a-string-gives-a-glibc-detected-error)
- [*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0a03c978 ***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980852/glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-normal-0x0a03c978)
- [free(): invalid next size (fast) - Freeing a struct of string array in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341323/free-invalid-next-size-fast-freeing-a-struct-of-string-array-in-c)
- [*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804832a ***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630067/glibc-detected-a-out-free-invalid-pointer-0x0804832a)
- [realloc after free problem ("realloc: invalid next size")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804126/realloc-after-free-problem-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [*** glibc detected *** : free(): invalid next size (fast) in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418563/glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast-in-c-code)
- [*** glibc detected *** sendip: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x09da25e8 ***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654910/glibc-detected-sendip-free-invalid-next-size-normal-0x09da25e8)
- [Why does a perfectly fine free on a string cause "free(): invalid next size"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748736/why-does-a-perfectly-fine-free-on-a-string-cause-free-invalid-next-size)
- [realloc(): invalid next size when reallocating to make space for strcat on char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436898/realloc-invalid-next-size-when-reallocating-to-make-space-for-strcat-on-char)
- [free(): invalid next size (fast) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048421/free-invalid-next-size-fast-in-c)
- [realloc():invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333939/reallocinvalid-next-size)
- [*** glibc detected *** python: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029132/glibc-detected-python-free-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000002119010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312064/realloc-invalid-next-size-0x0000000002119010)
- [*** glibc detected *** ./burcu.exe: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000001dad6310 ***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469886/glibc-detected-burcu-exe-free-invalid-next-size-fast-0x00000000)
- [C code Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888865/c-code-error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [free(): invalid next size (fast) string too long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192841/free-invalid-next-size-fast-string-too-long)
- [realloc(): Invalid next size C dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194528/realloc-invalid-next-size-c-dump)
- [libc detected *** ./textfileread.exe: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x08643008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928593/libc-detected-textfileread-exe-realloc-invalid-next-size-0x08643008)
- [Error:free(): invalid next size (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239369/errorfree-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [realloc: invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337241/realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [Freeing memory failure: free(): invalid next size (fast):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575735/freeing-memory-failure-free-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [realloc() invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754985/realloc-invalid-next-size)
- ["realloc(): invalid next size"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995441/realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [glibc detected: realloc(): invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150230/glibc-detected-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [realloc invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415507/realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [free(): invalid next size (normal) on fclose. But not when Valgrind runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635945/free-invalid-next-size-normal-on-fclose-but-not-when-valgrind-runs)
- [*** glibc detected *** ./m: free(): invalid next size (fast) on trying to free heap memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988217/glibc-detected-m-free-invalid-next-size-fast-on-trying-to-free-h)
- [invalid next size when using free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648152/invalid-next-size-when-using-free)
- [realloc: invalid next size, detected by glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862660/realloc-invalid-next-size-detected-by-glibc)
- [Debugging *** glibc detected *** python: realloc(): invalid next size without Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229838/debugging-glibc-detected-python-realloc-invalid-next-size-without-va)
- [Replacing Tab(s) with a Space - Memory Issues (free invalid next size fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445171/replacing-tabs-with-a-space-memory-issues-free-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [Invalid address on realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578300/invalid-address-on-realloc)
- [realloc(): invalid next size in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995653/realloc-invalid-next-size-in-my-code)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088113/glibc-detected-php-free-invalid-pointer-0x03376f50-when-execute
- [glibc detected realloc(): invalid next size: 0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182411/glibc-detected-realloc-invalid-next-size-0x)
- [realloc says Invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425568/realloc-says-invalid-next-size)
- [C Programming - Free Method Giving me an Invalid next Size (fast) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628462/c-programming-free-method-giving-me-an-invalid-next-size-fast-error)
- [Reallocating memory causes invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761720/reallocating-memory-causes-invalid-next-size)
- [realloc: invalid next size; memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966478/realloc-invalid-next-size-memcpy)
- [C: free(): invalid next size (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215086/c-free-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [Reverse string realloc(): invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453185/reverse-string-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [glibc detected realloc(): invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463849/glibc-detected-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [glibc detected, realloc(): invalid next size:X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761219/glibc-detected-realloc-invalid-next-sizex)
- [Realloc: invalid next size in dynamic vector of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097418/realloc-invalid-next-size-in-dynamic-vector-of-structs)
- [Glibc error with realloc: Invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480329/glibc-error-with-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543786/glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-normal
- [Alternately glibc detected free(): invalid next size (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765139/alternately-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [Can't reallocate memory of an array of structs (invalid next size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937690/cant-reallocate-memory-of-an-array-of-structs-invalid-next-size)
- [Unable to extend array using realloc: "invalid next size"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563313/unable-to-extend-aray-using-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [what does this error mean in C: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000020b0200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687388/what-does-this-error-mean-in-c-free-invalid-next-size-fast-0x00000000020b)
- [Segmentation fault and realloc(): invalid next size:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947131/segmentation-fault-and-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [Problems with realloc - "invalid next size"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396942/problems-with-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [Dynamic memory allocation - realloc(): invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884869/dynamic-memory-allocation-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [Strange behaviour on Realloc: invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295558/strange-behaviour-on-realloc-invalid-next-size)
- [Intel MKL --- *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006302c0 ***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314888/intel-mkl-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast-0x0000000)

#### Not duplicated (already closed)

- [Facing an error "*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)
- [*** glibc detected *** ./all: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0804b008 ***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582299/glibc-detected-all-realloc-invalid-next-size-0x0804b008)

OK; that's at least 61.  It avoids 'old size' problems, double free, invalid pointer, and C++ questions.

Comment: Yes, you have my support. Thanks for taking the time to hunt these down. :) Is there a good canonical somewhere in there that we can use as the target?

Comment: I've nominated the lowest numbered one ([Facing an error — glibc detected free invalid next size (fast)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317021/facing-an-error-glibc-detected-free-invalid-next-size-fast)); we can request any better answers to be migrated.

Comment: @Mysticial: Can I persuade you to close the last 7 ones which I couldn't close?  Then update the question with the information.  If you do it — or someone else does it — thanks!

Comment: I was hoping for a better canonical than that first one. One where the question is short and clear. And the answer explains everything in detail. In the C++ tag we have a lot of self-answers that do this, but there doesn't seem to be much of an effort in C.

Comment: Fair enough.  Choose your preferred alternative and tell me.  If it's already closed by me, I'll cancel that.  You can then make it the canonical for the remaining few, and for 'Facing an error'.  I am just about to update 'Facing an error' with a pointer to this question.  (I'm also headed for bed; it should be 6+ hours before I get around to doing anything more.)

Comment: Running down that list, it looks like the [one you sent me earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008077/free-char-invalid-next-size-fast) is the best. It's still not great, but better than all the other ones. The error is in the title and the question is pretty short. Unwind's answer is straight to the point with "overwriting your allocated space". So I'll the dupe the rest of them to that one. If anyone does come along with a good canonical later on, we can dupe the head of the chain to that instead.

Comment: @Mysticial: Works for me. We can clean up more tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the progress. I stopped short of repointing the head of the chain to the canonical you sent me earlier. We can decide on that later.

Comment: I can't _believe_ I hadn't thought of using Mjölnir for this! Thanks for the idea, and good on you for putting all this research in!

Comment: Should the canonical answer also be extended to discuss the symptoms/fixes on Windows with the MS toolchain? The error message is of course different but the coding errors are the same. Or should it be a separate (but very similar) question and answer?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: If you have the expertise to do so -- and the solutions for the problem in glibc on Windows are different from on Unix -- then yes, please (but that should probably be the [canonical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680334) created by [PlasmaHH](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/833362/plasmahh).  At the moment, this is not a generic 'all memory allocation errors' Q&A; it is tied to the glibc implementation specifically.  I'd like to get the glibc version fixed before we go further and generalize it too much.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please undo this! The 'master' question is tagged 'linux', 'jni' and 'centos', yet many of the duplcates are 'c', 'malloc', and 'realloc'. Totally different topics!

Comment: What does "fast" mean?

Comment: @JL2210 — dunno; it’s part of the error message and presumably means something to the authors of the `malloc()` package and contrasts with slow or thorough or some other word.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

(Correct me if I'm wrong and the causes of all the problems are listed in [that tiny little answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2584523/1711796), but...)

A canonical question + answer should contain everything (all causes of and solutions to a problem) **prior** to having everything closed as a duplicate of it. And that just seems like a randomly nominated candidate as opposed to **an especially constructed one** (its question number isn't a good selection criteria).

The motivation should **not** be:

> Let's get all these questions closed.

But rather:

> Let's make one super awesome post containing all this information ... and then get rid of all the redundant questions.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like people are doing it already anyways... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469886

Comment: I think the list collection work was done reasonably well and thoroughly. I think the duplicate chosen was (fairly badly) mis-chosen. I will work on rectifying that, but it will take time. I wish I'd waited rather than trying to get it all done last night; it is easy to be wise after the event.  One good thing: the list above identifies the afflicted questions, so it makes chasing what needs repairing that much easier. (So, in case it isn't clear, I agree with the criticism. And yes, the intention was to get to a super-awesome post, but there was a big gap between intention and achievement).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Is -- to your knowledge -- anyone working on that super awesome post? When not swamped with more stuff I could try doing something tomorrow. We should probably collect topics that we want to have in there. imho we should point out that: this is not a good type of question for SO but the answer is there so we can link duplicates to it. it should emphasize that there is no single reason and people need to debug, and then list a bunch of helpful things to start debugging.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: As of 'right now', I don't know of anyone working on it.  Mysticial has looked at the issue and likes one item as the canonical.  I will look at it later -- this evening, after work and a school concert.  I also plan to look at some of the other related items (notably 'old size' error messages; that's a dozen or so questions), to see if they should be added to the list.  To the extent there's a plan, I will look at the accepted answer in the proposed canonical.  I want to make sure `valgrind` is mentioned somewhere.  Otherwise, it shouldn't need much touching up.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: If it seems best, I'll add a CW answer that covers points not already made by the accepted answer.  It might also point to some of the related issues.  If someone else gets in and fixes up the mess before I get to it, that'll be fine with me (as long as the mess afterwards is less of a mess than it is now).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: For the canonical q/a pair I would prefer a "fresh" one because then we could make the question itself already list all kinds of typical error message for this kind of issue. It shouldn't be a big deal to move/copy the answer to that new fresh question should we find resources to create and re-duplicate-link it.

Answer (score 3):

Since the initial choice of "canonical" Q/A was rather suboptimal, 
I have just created a Q/A pair, which I think should quite a good starting point: [What is a glibc free/malloc/realloc invalid next size/invalid pointer error and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680334)

Maybe someone else can make it "super awesome" as requested by [Dukeling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling)

We should re-duplicate-close with targeting this.

Comment: I've done some work on both question and answer. There's a lot more to do. Amongst other things still to do: (1) Add credit for example question (I added the link and the question body); (2) Add answer to the example question and credit for it; (3) Convert to Community Wiki, please; (4) Update this question with links to the other error types than 'invalid next size' (since most of them occur somewhere in SO, but I deliberately excluded them originally); (5) Make a note that this problem can happen in C++ programs that are using the C memory allocation facilities (and add to the list here).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks a lot. regarding (5): It can happen in C++ programs too, since normally their memory allocation facilities will just use those of C. I will have a look at things tomorrow, now I need to try getting a certain kid to stay in her bed...