# Is it reasonable to create an "authority" post and close all older questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, etiquette, canonical

I just saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23740548/369450) and it is showing behavior I have never seen on a post before. It appears that multiple, older posts have been closed as duplicates of this new post. In the comments, the user [metacompactness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2536558/metacompactness) pointed out that at least 5 older questions have been closed as duplicates:

- [PHP array to JS variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23601606/369450)
- [cant pass php variables to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10161936/369450)
- [How to get PHP array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22706599/369450)
- [Passing a javascript variable to php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15474995/369450)
- [Passing php variable to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15196590/369450)

This seems very odd to me. Is it a valid practice to create an "authority" question for older questions, and close them all as duplicates even though the "authority" question itself is a duplicate?

**Note:** I am aware that it is perfectly valid to ask and answer your own questions. This just seems to be taking it a step further.

Comment: I thought newer dupe questions were closed instead of older ones.

Comment: Yes, this is a relatively standard practice. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254782/a-long-list-of-possible-duplicates-c-memory-allocation-and-overrunning-bounds for example.

Comment: See also: [Do “reference questions” make sense?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63762/do-reference-questions-make-sense)

Comment: See the [tag:php] tag wiki and the [tag:android] tag wiki for some great examples of reference questions.

Comment: See also: [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/process-for-nominating-and-promoting-canonical-questions). Its answers don't explain whether or not closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question is acceptable.

Comment: @SEisdead That's a separate issue, which is addressed by e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423085 (or on SE meta, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841).

Answer (score 1):

Why would it not be valid practice? If two questions are duplicates of each other and the newer question has better answers than the older one, then it should be perfectly acceptable to close the older question as a duplicate of the newer one.

In fact, [this has been done on Meta Stack <s>Overflow</s> Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/86997?page=9&sort=newest).