# Creating a dupe target to manage a plethora of duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, canonical

On the [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) tag, a few times a week (and I've seen as many as three in one day) a question is posted with the title along the lines of

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type ..

The three most recent ones from this week are

- [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type …
  requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290195/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-requires)
- [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type… but this
  dictionary requires a model item of
  type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188352/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)
- [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
  'MVC_Web_App.Models.Products'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233443/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-mvc-web-app-models-product)

When the user asked the question, they would have been prompted with 25 possible dupes (and entering it in the Stack Overflow *Search Q&A* box brings up over 800).

The error message itself is self explanatory. The OP is creating a model of type `Foo` in the controller and passing it to a view which expects a model of type `Bar`. Typically this is a result of using a LINQ query that returns an anonymous object, or that returns `IEnumerable<Foo>` when the view expects `Foo`. The error is also thrown when a view is calling a partial view and the wrong model is passed to the partial view, or when the view uses a layout that declares a different model, which is perhaps less obvious, but easily identifiable had the user put a break-point on their code and stepped through it.

While nothing can be done about stopping the question being repeatedly asked, many of them do not include the relevant code to accurately answer the question, or are left unanswered, or have poor quality (and sometimes wrong) answers that are unlikely to help other users.

There are a few good answers on Stack Overflow that address specific code errors which could be used as a dupe targets in some cases, but AFAIK, nothing which addresses the broader issue - why it occurs, how to identify the source of the error and how to solve it.

I'm considering creating a canonical question/community wiki answer along the lines [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) that explains why the error occurs and including code examples for typical cases, which can be then used as a dupe target.

What concerns me is that if I worded the question similar to that one, it would be quickly closed and nuked as being ***too broad***, making it a waste of time.

Is there to way to structure the question in a way that would not be considered too broad, or should I perhaps include a sub-heading stating it's been created as a dupe target, or are there other ways this could be handled (or should I just let it be)?

Comment: [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/process-for-nominating-and-promoting-canonical-questions)

Comment: @TinyGiant, Yes, I read that one as I was writing the question, and it and a few others suggest I should go ahead and do it. Its the fact that it might be quickly closed as _too broad_ before it can do any good that concerns me.

Comment: The process seems to be: 1. Ask if anyone knows of a good one - if a good one is found use that or 2. Request collaboration on the creation of a canonical, or just make one and hope for the best. Requesting collaboration can give a canonical an easier entrance into life as you have more people who are invested in the outcome, and the community knows what you're doing.

Comment: The first two links in the opening text don't work for me. FYI -su llewellyn