# The SQL NULL is extremely difficult to ask about - can we make it easier?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I searched for hours for questions about the SQL NULL and properly comparing maybe-null with maybe-null (column with query parameter). but once I asked about it the answer came pretty quick.

the SQL tutorials out there don't talk about this, so I assumed `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` were just special constructs, and didn't think the `NULL` could be changed for another value.

I think we should devise a question specifically to talk about the SQL NULL and these cases not covered by tutorials. it would also serve as a good target for duplicate questions about NULL comparisons.

[my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56207567) got flagged as a duplicate of [How to: Representing NULL in SQLite queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600551/how-to-representing-null-in-sqlite-queries), but the problem is that I wouldn't have been able to solve my problem with the answers to that question, as they don't touch on the issue I described above.

can we do something to improve this?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I would go ahead and post your question (and self-answer, if you see fit). If you are unsure, post your proposed question on meta perhaps and ask for feedback?

Comment: see [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276010/839601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you’ve found an excellent use-case for the ability to ask and answer a question. You’ve done your research, and ultimately found the answer through perseverance, but in the process discovered that the answer is not easy to find on Stack Overflow.

You are in the perfect position to fix this, since you both know what a person would be looking for (and thus can write a good question) *and* know the answer.

We do Q&A here, which requires both questions and answers. Normally, those are generated by different people, but they don’t have to be. As long as your question is on-topic and fits within our other guidelines, it is welcome here. **If you see a gap in our knowledge base that you think you can fill, please do so!**

Just, please, make sure that you always ask your question in the form of a question, including the answer as a *separate* answer. Don’t try to merge them together or write a blog entry. This is still Q&A. We keep the same format, regardless of who is writing the posts and when.

And, of course, even when you *don’t* know the answer, you can still ask a question to improve the usefulness of Stack Overflow as a resource. We have plenty of experts who can answer questions.

I cannot comment on the duplicate that was proposed for your question, as I am not a SQL expert. But keep in mind that duplicates often serve a very useful purpose as signposts, allowing people with similar questions to find the answers they’re looking for, even if they don’t know the right terms to search. On the other hand, if you genuinely feel that the answer to your question is not contained in the duplicate, then you should edit your question to clarify the difference. It has only received one vote, so there’s still plenty of time left to clarify before it gets closed.