# Is this "fake" question with a documentation like answer on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope, self-answer

[How to understand Format Specifiers in C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59575694/1116364)

It's a ... "fake" question with an answer which is very documentation like.  Ignoring the mistakes in the answer for a moment, is such a question / answer style even on topic?

Comment: I'd appreciate help with tagging (this meta question)

Comment: It's a pity StackOverflow Documentation was shut down, because it was designed for this sort of content

Comment: Recently I have read this post -> https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. This link can be found on `Ask a question` tab. I have already experience lot of people struggling with format specifiers even now a days. There for I tried to explain that using examples to understand to anyone who came with format specifiers issues. That is the only reason.

Comment: Move that info into the tag wiki.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/process-for-nominating-and-promoting-canonical-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting

Comment: *"is such a question / answer style even on topic?"* **Absolutely!** See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 6):

That Q&A is not inherently off-topic. We welcome self-accepted answers as a way to share knowledge. Personally, I did it [only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265625/why-i-am-suddenly-getting-a-typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initiali), since I find it relatively difficult, but the reception I got with that one clearly shows that if not done terribly poorly, it can be found helpful.

I believe the biggest issue with this question is how it was stated. Multiple questions, none of which were particularly focused; a lot of exposition and some noise.

I've tried to offer an edit that I believe makes it much clearer and does a better job at explaining what the question expects as an answer. I'm very far from being a C expert, so hopefully users more knowledgeable than me can weight in with edits and votes.

The answer could probably do with an edit as well, but the answer quality should not matter in deciding if the question needs to be closed or not.

In the end, the question was deleted by its author, probably because it got 6 downvotes, making the whole issue moot.

For reference, this was the revision that got closed:

> [image]

And after this edit, it got 2 reopen votes from other users before it was deleted:

> [image]

Comment: I have deleted it because two peoples are voted for delete my question. with one vote that post will be deleted. I have never thought that post would be not helpful to others. I will never do that Q&A style again. It feels lots of discouragement.

Comment: Every month I saw more than 10 questions which are users struggling with format specifiers. Even today I also saw that kind of question. There for I thought post Q with A to help these people. I have followed this article -> [https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/] before I posting the Q&A