# Canonical question on how to generate lists of inputs in Snakemake?

Tags: discussion, canonical

The last couple of months I found a number of questions about Snakemake that all concern how to generate a list of expected inputs with `expand` when the default behavior of `expand` doesn't do the trick. Usually the answer is to use `expand` with `zip`, or maybe drop `expand` altogether and generate the list some other way.

However, whenever a new one pops up, I feel the other ones are too specific to use as a dupe target. I've tried to look for some canonical question/answer pair, but can't seem to find one.

Is there a good one I've been overlooking? If not, is it all right for me to write one given I've got relatively low rep and am not one of the top answerers in the Snakemake tag, but am fairly familiar with that particular bit of Snakemake? It looks to me like [the process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276010/process-for-nominating-and-promoting-canonical-questions) (as of 2014) is/was "identify it's missing and write it", but I want to be sure I'm making the right call and not waltzing over everyone with more experience in the tag.

Comment: Just make sure that your question is well asked and can stand on its own, without being self answered. That means you will have to introduce and explain the problem in the question even though you know the solution. If you make one line question, it will probably not go well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is it all right for me to write one

Sure, why not. [Self-answers are encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  If you have put in the effort and not found one, then perhaps it does not exist or it is just hard to find and thus may as well not exist.

The "worst" thing that could happen is that somebody finds a proper duplicate, which means another signpost to it.

It might also turn out your own Q&A might be a better duplicate target anyway.

> given I've got relatively low rep

Irrelevant.

> and am not one of the top answerers in the Snakemake tag

Irrelevant.

> but am fairly familiar with that particular bit of Snakemake?

This is the only part relevant to whether you are qualified to write a good explanation.

Comment: An attempt has been made now, thanks for nudging me into giving it a shot.