# Duplicate Closing Rampage

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, privileges, dupehammer

It happened to me today that I found several duplicate questions for a common questions. So I identified [the oldest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work) (with a good, high-voted, unfortunately unaccepted answer), and went on a rampage with my [superpowers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders). This made my voting log look like this:

```
8m  closure     (deleted)     Javascript hash replace error [duplicate] 
11m closure     (deleted)     JavaScript .replace() part of a url not working [duplicate] 
12m closure     (deleted)     Javascript Regex with Special Character and Space [duplicate]     
12m closure     (deleted)     Remove a substring from a string in Jquery [duplicate] 
12m closure     (deleted)     Javascript replace function won't remove the string [duplicate] 
13m closure     (deleted)     removing numbers from string? [duplicate] 
14m closure     (deleted)     How to replace "{ with { in string using Javascript? [duplicate] 
15m closure     (deleted)     Replace certain characters in a string [duplicate] 
16m closure     (deleted)     Replace angle brackets in Javascript string? [duplicate] 
16m closure     (deleted)     JS replace not working on string [duplicate] 
18m closure     (deleted)     Replace function not replacing [duplicate] 
20m closure     (deleted)     How to remove line breaks in string? [duplicate] 
21m closure     (deleted)     Want to remove curly bracers from a string [duplicate] 
23m upvote                    Replace method doesn't work 
31m closure     (deleted)     JavaScript String.replace() RegEx: ; replacement with " and / in RegEx [duplicate]
```

…which made me wonder: **Am I abusing my superpowers?**

Am I doing the community a great service by not filling the close vote queue, and cleaning up the site; or is it non-democratic to decide by myself that all these questions deserve closing?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to post your plan ahead of time. Like this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254782/a-long-list-of-possible-duplicates-c-memory-allocation-and-overrunning-bounds But if you believe those are dupes, you're trusted to use that power appropriately.

Comment: No. It's fine. If you think things should be closed, VTC. If the system happens to grant you superpowers, that shouldn't change things.

Comment: This is the sort of thing we dared not even hope for when discussing this feature. Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Uh oh. I've seen enough superhero movies to know that immediately after the protagonist discusses his inner moral conflict at whether it's right for him to use his superpowers, that's when the villain strikes.

Comment: Can we come up with a better title for the original question?  Maybe something like "Replace method doesn't replace original string?".

Comment: Hey @Shog9, when do I get to have my own superpowers too? I've answered over 300 [tag:git] questions with a score of 737, which is actually probably a little lower than the real score because of the recent problems with them not being updated daily like they used to be. I've seen my fair share of duplicates too, but [tag:git] doesn't get as much traffic as popular tags like [tag:javascript], so it's probably going to be another couple of years before I hit gold status in Git, unless I go out of my way to feed the vampires for a few months `:/`

Comment: @cupcake There are 14 gold-badge git user (https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/161/git), low traffic tags have < 5.

Comment: Along the same line, I sometimes ask myself why should I vote with  4 other people to close a question when a mod can come along and do it in one fell swoop. But in the case of SO, a question can always be reopened so I don't see it as a problem.

Comment: It is appalling how many people asked these trivial questions when Google would have given them the answer immediately.

Comment: @Cupcake: we have [well over 31500 Qt questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), and [zero gold badge](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/topusers).

Comment: @LaszloPapp [tag:qt] (`[tag:qt]`).

Comment: Rampage on!!!!!

Comment: My closing log is longer than yours!

Comment: @usr: [Is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr?tab=activity&sort=reviews) Of course I could only post an excerpt [of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Comment: @Bergi for some reason I was not previously able to access your log. I just looked at the killing spree that you posted here. I bow to you.

Comment: Ah, the `votes` tab is not public accessible (and `review` seems to be a bit different thing - I have 2,191 close votes but only 531 reviews). I'll remove the link.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

No. If you're spending the time to find actual duplicates that need to be closed, you're using your powers exactly as they were intended to be used. It makes a lot more sense to have a gold tag badge holder close these questions than a moderator because they actually know a lot about the tag, whereas a moderator may not.

Abusing the powers would be closing things as duplicates which are not actually duplicates (without actually trying to verify the fact). You are clearly not doing that. In fact, a moderator closing these questions instead of you would likely be considered more of an abuse of power, because we may not necessarily know as much about the tag (depending on which tag it is, speaking generally here).

If anyone disagrees with your duplicate closures, there is still the normal process of reopening, or even bringing the issue to Meta.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! What I feared was that when someone disagrees, he might not even *recognize* that I went to close so many question, and refrain from bringing it up on meta.

Comment: This. Exactly this. I would _much_ rather someone with a great degree of domain knowledge _and_ a thorough knowledge of the content we have _in_ the tag do this rather than a mod, because you're going to be _much_ more accurate and effective. **This is exactly what I designed the feature to do, and you are using it wonderfully.**

Comment: The funny thing is that I was running into heavy objection when I had this idea and discussed it a while ago with others to give more power to the experts. It is a warm fuzzy feeling to see it coming to the reality.

Comment: So when do the people with gold badge get more decision rights, i.e. extending it to other close vote reasons? It is clear now that this improvement did not help with balancing the close vote queue, so I imagine the community has to go further and having more rights would be even nicer.

Answer (score 45):

You are using the feature ***precisely*** as we hoped that you would. You have:

- A great deal of knowledge *about* the tag
- A thorough grasp of the content that exists *within* the tag
- A little time to help us keep things clean

As animuson points out, you're going to be much more accurate than a moderator that doesn't have the same badge, because they don't have 2 out of the 3 things I listed above. I can't tell you how many 'other' flags I've dismissed as helpful without action simply because I couldn't make the call myself; leaving them for another moderator wouldn't have helped, especially with 1000+ flags in a 2+ week backlog.

Don't forget that there *is* community oversight, just like there is when moderators cast a single binding vote. Someone else with the same badge can easily re-open the post, or mark it as a duplicate of a better canonical question. Being marked as a duplicate is only a permanent state if folks feel that it should be. The community's ability to reverse these particular types of binding votes is much greater than their ability to overrule a moderator's binding votes; it only takes one vote from the right people.

I'm extremely pleased and admittedly *proud* of the way gold tag badge holders have been stepping up to help cut through the massive amount of duplicate questions that we receive, many of very poor quality. Thank you for reinforcing that this was, indeed a *good* idea - Shog and I went out on a bit of a limb pushing it through the way that we did.

Comment: Let me take the opportunity to say *thank you* to you and Shog, then! Just in the subset of tags that I monitor, it has made a huge difference. Hopefully if we gold badge holders keep up the good work, you guys will be persuaded to give us tools to close questions for other reasons, too (e.g. off topic and unclear). These are at least as big a problem as duplicates.

Comment: @CodyGray It's something we looked at, and we _want_ the net gain that opening this up to other types of close reasons would yield. However, it _completely_ blurs the line between established/trusted users and moderators - for instances where _any_ subjectivity might come into play, folks really want to elect the users that get a binding vote. Requiring _fewer_ votes if gold tag badge holders are in the mix of close-voters is not entirely off the table, however, but we have to give this much more time to soak. It's also important to note that this is one of perhaps a _dozen_ things we're doing

Comment: ... to address the perceived quality issues on Stack Overflow. It could be, this combined with other things does the job nicely, and we don't need to open Pandora's close-vote closet just _yet_, let's wait and see.

Answer (score 20):

My only problem is the criteria you're using: "the oldest one" (otherwise - Good work! Keep it up!)

I'm sure (well, I hope) you'd only use the oldest one if it:

- Was of high quality and
- Covers all problems of any question you close as a duplicate of

But you really shouldn't even use age as a criteria at all - just because it's older doesn't make it in any way more appropriate to be the 'master' post - age is just a number and says nothing of quality.

Look purely for the one of the highest quality.

If there was one asked ... today, that's of higher quality than any others, use that instead. If there aren't **any** of sufficiently high quality, write your own.

Comment: I'm not sure if self-answered questions are liked by the community unless they're made CW. At least, in my experience, not making the question and answer CW will cause people to accuse you of "repwhoring" (when you're actually doing the opposite).

Comment: @AmalMurali Haters gonna hate, but there are usually enough upvoters to cancel out any downvoters and a moderator will come along at some point (due to a flag, maybe) to clean up any comments and/or put them in their place.

Comment: To this I would add: if you find that *multiple* duplicate questions have good answers, flag and request that they be merged. (in this specific case, the answer was fairly trivial, so I don't think this is a concern)

Comment: Um, [it is a Jon Skeet answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433217/1048572)! How can it possibly be low-quality? :-D Well, if there are multiple threads of equal quality, I choose the oldest one  as it has should have been the natural close target for any questions that were asked after it. In this particular case, the problem was trivial, and there were many similar answers. I just needed one that had a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Another motivation behind this feature is to allow someone with a gold badge to come along and say "Yes, that's a duplicate, _but I know a much better one it could point to_". Don't feel bad about re-opening with the intent of closing again in these cases.

Comment: @Shog9 Just curious, what will happen if both the questions being merged have accepted answers?

Comment: Nothing special, @thefortheye

Comment: @TimPost: This looks like it might be useful for a new feature: retargetting of duplicates (for mods and goldmods)

Comment: @PlasmaHH Why do we need a new feature if the same can already be done with the existing features?

Comment: @Dukeling: reopening and closing again seems like a lot of noise and useless clicking. and as far as I understood the goldclose/reopen, to prevent clos/reopen wars, you can only use that power once per question, so for the second time (retargetted duplicate) you need the community again

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm pretty sure you can close once and reopen once (same as normal close voting rules), thus you can close and reopen it yourself.

Comment: @Bergi: Just to prove the possibility: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265771

Answer (score -2):

If you'd closed the one you left open as a duplicate of one of the closed ones, yeah that would have been abuse of powers.
As is, if they're indeed all the same question, at most the choice which to close and which to leave open might be questioned (not checked into them, but no doubt somebody would disagree with whichever gets left open).