# How is this question well researched?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, upvotes

I know that I won't see eye-to-eye with everyone, but [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array) has **743 upvotes** and **0 downvotes**.

The question, reproduced in its entirety:

> How do I append to an array in Javascript?

Is there a bug? *Did 743 people unanimously really think it showed research effort?*

Is it a bug because the question is a community question? (If so, this needs to be fixed...votes should reflect the usefulness and research of the question/answer, community or not.)

Comment: "votes should reflect the **usefulness** and research of the question/answer" - 743+ people found it useful. And for someone starting out with Javascript, such a question would totally be useful.

Comment: That question is crazy old and has been viewed ~400k times. Standards were different back then. And 743 / 400k isn't that many, I think.

Comment: It's also a Canonical/Reference question.

Look at the side bar, and see how many posts are linked to it as duplicates.

Comment: @Mysticial, "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear." It doesn't seem like an either-or; it seems that research effort is **required**.

Comment: The tooltip didn't say that back then.

Comment: @joran, 0 downvotes out 400k views is also low.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, what were SO posts voted on?

Comment: Your question presumes that there is a rule you must follow.  There isn't.  The tooltip gives useful guidance for voting, but it is not a mandate.

Comment: @PaulDraper True, but I think that's just a behavioral thing. People are much more likely to down vote new questions they see as bad than old ones.

Comment: The main thing is that it's from 2008. It managed to accumulate the upvotes during a different historical period with different standards.

Comment: @Pekka웃, ah, I was not aware the standards for SO had changed so much. (If asked today, the only think stopping that question from getting 743 downvotes would be automatic deletion. ;)

Comment: @PaulDraper As far as "research effort" goes. If you asked the question today, it would show no research effort because it's a single google search would have led to that very question. Roll back a few years. You're the OP of that question and you couldn't find the answer anywhere on the internet. You come to SO to ask it. You've now created the canonical go-to question for everyone in the future asking the same question.

Comment: @Mysticial, huh, I still would have thought that would be easily searchable even in 2008, but maybe not. Google had only been around for 9 years at that time.

Comment: That question dates from the time when *"No question is too basic"* was still policy. Compare to the move a turtle in logo question. Policy has changed.

Comment: Look at previous versions. Over the years, the question has been whittled down to an absolute minimum.

Comment: @Jongware, so the question has improved. And yet, I still think it is poor quality.

Comment: I'd upvote it if I had the same question myself and found it useful. I wouldn't give a stuff that it doesn't contain verbiage about research. Short, to the point, questions are fine by me.

Comment: @dmckee: Not much.  The "General Reference" close reason was considered for Stack Overflow, but ultimately discarded.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The question timeline shows [it still gets a steady stream of upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/351409/timeline). These aren't all historic. Averaging over a vote a day for May so far.

Comment: @PaulDraper back in 2008, W3Schools was (and often still is) the top search result for JavaScript documentation. I don't remember [the Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) being a big thing back then, if it even existed yet at all. Given that, I think it's understandable that someone would ask a question like that back then...there just weren't any good JavaScript resources (yet).

Comment: **[Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair)**

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? => https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331597/4356188

Answer (score 8):

That question was asked in December 2008.

Are you sure that all the documentation available in JavaScript on the subject was available in 2008?

Remember, a big point in Stack Overflow is to build a knowledge base, a lot of the answers I find to common questions now *are* from Stack Overflow.

So:

- If it were asked today, it would not have been appropriate.
- However, that is mainly because it was already asked in 2008.

I'd also like to add again:

Although you can vote however you choose, **votes are intended for usefulness** and not anything else.

Comment: Valid point, though W3Schools has been around since 1999, and I'm 99.7% certain they had `Array.prototype.push` at the end of 2008.

Comment: @PaulDraper w3schools is a horrible reference that used to be a much worse one, and their code contained a lot of mistakes. I totally understand someone not trusting them as a reference. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: Yes, I agree about W3Schools. (I hesitated to even suggest it :P) It seems impossible to me that only six years ago, that *appending to a Javascript array* was not findable by a five-second Internet search, but maybe that was the case. (I think not, but I have no proof.)

Comment: @PaulDraper it's not that it wasn't doable, it's that finding a reference was harder and less accessible. Also keep in mind such a question would likely be heavily downvoted today, the culture changed a lot in SO too.

Comment: "the culture changed a lot in SO" Indeed, after reading the comments and answers, I realize I underestimated the amount it has changed in that time.

Comment: @PaulDraper here, have a blast http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/unofficial-stack-overflow-deleted-question-archive-now-available

Comment: I believe this is absolutely the correct answer. I wasn't around in 2008, but my understanding is that in the beginning, super-basic, documentation-repeating questions were deliberately asked by people who already knew the answers, to start up the archive and provide a sort of "good honeypot" for searchers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I still do that today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800010 but the real artists are people like Felix Kling with hits like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/

Comment: Amen, @BenjaminGruenbaum; I'm hopefully about to start work on one of those myself this week, as [an anvil for the golden hammer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255757/). I'd say your questions are a fair bit more advanced than "add to array", though.

Answer (score 4):

The asker of a question is supposed to accomplish 2 things.

- Help potential answerers understand what the need is.
- Help other users who need the answer match that question to their own needs

In both of those regards the question is a resounding success.

The time it takes you to understand what is being asked, with this question is lower than any contemporary question I've seen in over a year.

How can one possibly call such a question low quality?

Comment: I apologize if I did not make that clear. It was because it did not show research effort, which (I thought) was part of the criteria for an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't a bug.

People are free to vote however they want except fraudulently or serially targeting another user.

Clearly 743 people found the answers (and by extension the existence of the question) useful enough to believe it warranted an upvote and couldn't care less about the research effort.

My view is that adding any information about research efforts would likely not improve this question one iota.

It is also worth mentioning that the advice in [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) doesn't even mention research as a factor.

> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is
>   especially useful, vote it up!