# High ranked question that shows no research?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally, I come across these little gems which have an enormous amount of up-votes, yet show no real effort from the author of the question.

While the solution provided is usually in-depth, the lack of effort shown by the question author, is astounding. Currently, if no source examples are provided, simplified, customized to replicate the problem, research to links on Google, etc., definitions, language documentation, and so on - are not supplied, this usually results in negative response.

One in particular is this:

[image: What is a metaclass in Python]

In fairness, the question was posted in 2008, however, the Internet was not an infant at the time. Google had already established a strong foothold as the dominant search engine, and HTML5 was undergoing some draft revisions prior to it's first stable release in 2014 (6 years later). The web was very graphical, Windows 7 was mainstream, and open-source packages like Python 2.5 (now at 3) had websites with documentation as well as man pages. Since then, the Python 2.5 documentation was rolled up into Python 2.6 documentation (with 2.6 adjustments), and deprecated and eventually deleted the 2.5 documentation from their site.

That is just one set of primary source where more information could have been found to show research on this subject. The solutions on [this proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255843) lay claim to information not being available at that time - which in this case, is simply not true.

What makes this question a unique snowflake among the snowstorm?

Comment: @approxiblue - i can agree the pretense is similar in nature given it is the same question type, however none of those solutions are valid as there was plenty of documentation on this back in 2008, in fact -- further to around 2004 even.  Planet-Source-Code.com was prime hunting grounds as well as linux man pages, and -- 2008, internet was well established with Google being the dominant search engine.  This question genuinely did not show any research effort whatsoever, and it wasn't for lack of access to the information !

Comment: In 2008, there was documentation on this elsewhere, but not on SO, which just started.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'd expect a canonical question about metaclasses to ask.  Maybe you think it's adequately documented elsewhere, and you are probably right.  It may also be too broad.  But just not showing effort or including code is not a problem.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - I understand the logic, as it is a founded question - however my brief history, asking a question of this nature warrants numerous down-votes and/or deletion such as "What is a DataContract?" with the body being "What is a DataContract ? How is it used ?". While the question itself is valid, it does not show any effort and is extremely vague in nature expecting others to do all the work for you.  As a standard question, it is valid, but not in the context of what SO currently requires.

Comment: @approxiblue - I haven't scoured SO for relevant information dating back to 2008, however the current guide encourages at least links to things tried that didn't work, and more information than just the question - a copy/paste from the (then) current 2.5 python documentation regarding metaclasses would have been a minimal effort to show effort to understand the concept as per the question as stated.

Comment: Yeah, the standards have changed to prevent people from re-asking questions that have already been asked. If you're asking questions now, then certainly follow the current standards.

Comment: @approxiblue - Can / should  that question be revised to current standards ?

Comment: Questions don't have to show research or an attempt to solve the problem. Questions that don't include those things are more likely to be too broad, unclear, or otherwise off-topic, but those things are not required. It is generally a good idea to remove noise such as that once the question has been successfully answered as it is truly just more text for future readers to wade through. Once a question has reached the canonical point like this one has, you want as little unnecessary information as possible. [Relevant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)

Comment: Google did that.  They stole the answer, not the question.  Impressive how they copied the image as well and made it fit, that must have been done by hand.  Not attributed correctly, as usual, the big boys don't have to play by the rules.

Comment: @HansPassant - explain ?

Comment: Just google "what is a python metaclass".  Look at the top of the page.

Comment: @HansPassant - I see what you mean.  I suppose it is okay for them to pick and choose what they steal for their page -- it is in their terms, regarding crawling (stealing) site content  XD

Comment: @HansPassant: Remember when SO decided they have the right to retroactively "clarify" the attribution requirement to [whatever they choose](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/attribution-required/), instead of the license terms we agreed to when we post under CC BY-SA?  Probably Google is meeting the attribution requirements they negotiates with SO (note that there is a link to the original question, which has always been the part of attribution that SO is unwillingly to bend on, even though the license terms never specify that attribution has to take the form of a hyperlink)