# Questions that could be answered by a simple Google search

Tags: discussion

I am going through a question like this:

*[What is a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure)*

And it strikes me that: How does it get 124 up-votes?

A simple Google search leads to excellent articles including below Wikipedia article *[Stored procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure)*.

What is the point of asking such trivial question on Stack Overflow without any research?

I missed the age of the question. Still, it surprises me how it gets so many upvotes.

Comment: It's eight years old, from the very beginning of the site. Things were very different then and it would not work today. One could vote to close it as "too broad"

Comment: The age is exactly how it got so many upvotes. Probably also Google, it is in the top 10 search results for "stored procedure". You [can see that the votes trickled in slowly over time](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/459457/timeline).

Comment: @CodyGray: which button give the nice timeline view you included?

Comment: Did you actually try that simple Google search?  That question is the top hit, still today.  Google can turn any crap into gold, a quarter of a million views easily takes care of that.  But consider that only 1 in every 2000 programmers that looked at it found the question helpful.  Still impressed?

Comment: There is no button, you have to know the magic sequence. Coincidentally, [it was recently proposed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340703/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) to make it a button.

Comment: @CodyGray, you got me there :) I searched "stack overflow see question timeline" and found it is part if the SO API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-timeline

Comment: @HansPassant: I did search for "Stored Procedure" and the question is ranked right below Wiki article. Please consider any post of SO gets a big boost in google ranking logic.

Comment: `Please consider any post of SO gets a big boost in google ranking logic` yup, that's Hans' Point.

Comment: Ok, I agree this question is a duplicate. What should I do when my question is a duplicate? Should I delete it?

Comment: "Should I delete it?" No, not necessarily. This question currently serves as a signpost to [the question it was closed as a duplicate of (and on which the community came to a consensus on this)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255843/how-is-this-question-well-researched), which means the duplicate target is now even easier to find.