# Canonical questions and the dupe-hammer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, canonical

A while back, I noticed that a particular Spring question was exceedingly common and wrote up [a canonical question on it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1189885); I then proceeded to march through a bunch of questions that were essentially the same and propose close-as-duplicate.

I've run across another repeated issue that doesn't have a canonical question (about trying to write a method inside another method in Java), and it's so cookie-cutter that it deserves one. However, I have a gold [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) badge, and I wanted to get input before unilateral self-promotion.

Is it considered proper for a gold badge holder to use the dupehammer to mass-close questions as duplicate of the user's own canonical question?

Comment: It's perfectly fine in my opinion. It's perfectly ok to promote your contributions on the site, the general benefit for the community and users of having a canonical answers should definitely outweigh the "negative" feelings you're having from "self promoting"

Comment: So long as it's a good Q&A, yeah. More power to you. Clean it up brother.

Comment: It does not matter whose question it is. Given that, the answer is exactly the same as this question: [Duplicate Closing Rampage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255738)

Comment: @CodyGray "It does not matter whose question" is an answer to this one, but the question here is specifically about "self-promoted" answers.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You said that you are closing duplicate questions, using the new dupe-hammer, as duplicates of a canonical question you wrote. That's perfectly fine, on all fronts. It does not matter that *you* wrote the canonical question, it matters only if it's a duplicate. And if it is, then we thank you for your efforts in improving the site.

Comment: @CodyGray: This question is about whether the conflict-of-interest is a problem. You can certainly answer "no, the conflict-of-interest is not a problem", but that doesn't make this a duplicate of every other question about actions that are O.K.

Comment: "No, the conflict-of-interest is not a problem, **for the exact same reasons detailed in the answers to that other question**." Hence, duplicate.