# Strengthening the Dupe Hammer with General Questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

Related topics:

- [Canonical question for "=" typo for "=="](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312052/canonical-question-for-typo-for)
- [Canonical questions and the dupe-hammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256265/canonical-questions-and-the-dupe-hammer)

The dupe hammer, used correctly and actively, is one way to naturally keep the site clean while still educating the people who inadvertently ask a duplicate question more than merely shutting down their Q.

Yet how do we strengthen it? How do we improve its chances of being used correctly, unambiguously, and more actively? This leads me to the thought: *we need general redirection targets!*

I see some beginners who are earnest but just so terribly naive. They cannot really be set on the right path through a mere answer of what's wrong with their basic code snippet. It's the wrong context for them to be educated. Yet at the heart of that faulty code snippet is the hidden general question, *"How does recursion work?"*, e.g. I see that question there, disguised, and my thought is that it wouldn't be so bad if there was actually such a question on the site.

"General" often implies somewhat lazy and broad, like *"How do I debug my C++ program?"* -- no MCVE, just a one-liner question, and hopefully with answers that cover the basics of how to use GDB, MSVC debugger, XCode, etc.

Now we have the perfect redirection targets whenever someone asks a basic question about an error that could be spotted within 1 minute of debugging. Moreover it should be really great for both the site and the absolute beginner who posted that question to be *redirected towards generality*. We're giving them the "fishing rod", not "one fish" -- we're giving them the means to become *self-sufficient*.

Take two duplicate questions like, *"Q: Why does my particle simulator crash?"* and *"Q: Why does creating a button in Qt segfault?"* Behind the code snippets for both might be the underlying question, *"Q: What happens when returning a pointer to a local object in a function?"*

The problem with general questions is that they are often discouraged by the site. A question asking how to debug a C++ program or how recursion works would often get mercilessly shut down as too broad. But the questions are effectively there already, at least with the way I'm looking at it, just hidden within thousands and thousands of faulty code snippets. If they're explicitly there rather than disguised within a myriad of faulty code snippets, might that have a chance to help the situation?

Comment: Garbage questions should not be closed as dupes. Duplicates don't get automatically cleaned up (as quickly if at all). We don't need garbage pointing to gold. If a question is on-topic and has no other problems, but has been asked before, then it should be closed as a duplicate. Otherwise, close it for whatever other reason may apply.

Comment: @TinyGiant The fear I have with that, and it doesn't seem to be completely unfounded, is that the absolute beginners who get downvoted and shut down don't seem to learn very quickly. They have a pattern of similar behavior when they might just need to learn how to use a debugger. A redirection to a Q about debugging seems like a good way to send them to boot camp. The other is that we got that FGITW problem where so many people are tempted to answer those garbage Qs.

Comment: So redirect them, don't stop garbage questions from being deleted. Stack Overflow is supposed to be useful for everyone, not just for the OP.

Comment: But, if you close questions as duplicates, it stops them from being deleted. I fail to see how making a duplicate target for all of the garbage questions on the site is solving a problem.

Comment: @TinyGiant A Q like *"How do I debug a C++ program?"* isn't currently canonical but it's absolutely ideal as that general root of redirection. It could be a stable root target for all Qs that fail to exhibit any basic knowledge of debugging -- the kind where one Q gets redirected to another Q which gets redirected to this.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's true -- but the problem I'm looking at are those "vampire" questions which feed the fastest gun in the west. They often get answers if they don't get redirections, and they're engulfing the site, at least in tags like [tag:c] and [tag:c++].

Comment: I wish I had a hammer for meta posts where the author so obviously did not spend the time to make it shorter.  It is a common courtesy.

Comment: "*How do I debug a C++ program*" is waaaay too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HansPassant Apologies, I will see if I can make it shorter. One of the reasons for my verboseness is that English isn't my native language and I am always worried about using a wrong word and totally misleading people. I work around the problem by explaining around it and trying to disambiguate with more rather than less. I've never been very confident with a shorter post.

Comment: Re vampire questions: close them for the reasons that apply, don't keep them around on the site *to stop* them from being FGITW answered. There are [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) available to help with closing questions that need to be closed quickly in order to avoid FGITW.

Comment: @TinyGiant Agreed by the current site's standards. I'm just seeing it as the perfect redirection target. I'm looking at it like there are tens of thousands of questions now which basically need that question and answer if we want to link them to something within the site rather than outside the site.

Comment: Again: Redirect them, you don't need to close the question as a duplicate to do that. Don't stop garbage questions from being deleted just to save them from being answered.

Comment: @TinyGiant That might be the ideal advice, but I'm just disappointed by the results I'm seeing now as a result of it. Maybe the ideal is that we just pull together and start finding ways to delete these troubleshooting routine questions as fast as they can be asked, but it feels like we're outnumbered. The laziest beginners who can't be bothered to learn what a debugger is or read a basic book have boatloads of questions, and I can't see those of us trying to prevent them from taking up everyone's time as being able to keep up.

Comment: @TinyGiant My line of thinking is that if we can't beat the beginners, recruit them. Redirect them to those general educational sources which hit their underlying issue, and hope they come back experienced and helping to keep the site clean for future generations.

Comment: Re your first comment after my last one: Well, in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) that is exactly what we try to do every single day, and every day we get more and more users helping out.

Comment: @TinyGiant Ooh nice, I will see if I can contribute there!

Comment: Re redirecting users: That is fine and dandy as I've said before, but duplicate closure doesn't help with that goal. That just makes cleaning up the site that much harder.

Comment: @TinyGiant I might be looking at this in a convoluted kind of way, but the hope there was beyond a single question. Just a prerequisite knowledge of how to use a debugger might have halved the number of Qs in a tag like [tag:c] (in a very good way). I was thinking (hoping) that if we could redirect a VLQ troubleshooter Q to a debugging resource, that would prevent the beginner from asking a lot more questions. It's not about *that* question, it's about *that* user as I see it. I was hoping we could make him more self-sufficient and even eventually join in moderating the site.

Comment: @TinyGiant I know one such user (actually "users") who complained a lot to me about SO being harsh. He has used 4 different accounts and got a question ban on all of them. He hasn't learned yet what he's doing wrong, and he still doesn't know how to debug his code. I don't know if this an extremely exceptional case, but the only way to "fix" him is to "guide" him. That dupe hammer done right might have a chance.

Comment: @Ike do we really want to "fix" such a user though? I don't know for you, but if I had to create four accounts and got banned on ALL... I would ask myself what I AM doing wrong, not that the site is harsh. After 4 failed attempts, he should understand he's going at it the wrong way and adapt. If he's not changing and just creates other accounts to throw his bad questions around.... the problem is that if you guide him, 10% of people will listen and be glad you helped them, and the 90% others will just say "I don't care, help me".

Comment: I've seen a new user LITERALLY say "I don't care about this site's quality, just help me out!". These type of users are NON-REDEEMABLE. Your idea here is tailored to new users, with the assumption most of them are HAPPY to adapt to the site... it's not the reality of it, unfortunately

Comment: @Patrice Ugh, that is very bleak. In spite of my posts here on meta, I'm looking at this in a very optimistic (albeit very possibly naive) way.

Comment: @Ike This is just a matter of experience around the site. I know you are still very optimistic, but I've seen enough TERRIBLE (and trust me, truly terrible) push backs about this site and how it works that I'm not that optimistic anymore. Too often did I reach out to a new user, to try to explain to him how to make the best out of the tool that is stack overflow, just to be told "look, if you can't answer, don't bother, I don't care about anything else I just want this fixed". After 10-20 encounters like that (and only 1-2 where user actually listens), yeah you grow cynical... :S

Comment: Today's best from non-debugger with gross errors due to global misuse: ' It is astonishingly unbelievable how idiotic, stupid and utterly inbecile your moral engagement is'.  That poster then demonstrated his own moral engagement by reposting his question, but without the recursive function that used global variables, ie 'my code there was crap, so I hid it'.

Comment: @Martin thanks for proving my point. I was sure you had some example somewhere.... also that it is an example from TODAY makes it even better :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182147/exc-bad-access-error-while-using-c  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199132/exc-bad-access-error-code-2

Comment: @Patrice When I first joined the site I didn't know better so I was answering a lot of these uber-beginner questions thinking they were easy. But being a former teacher, I would always add some extra stuff to it recommending to learn how to use a debugger and so forth, to which I would often get the disappointing response, *"What's a debugger?"* I stopped posting answers to those types of Qs to avoid encouraging poor habits. Now if I participate in those types of Qs, it's usually only in the comments.

Comment: I'm the same.  I don't want rep from such questions.  'Debugger? I don't use IDE(just editor and compiler), so i don't know how to use that.' 10k+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306856/for-loop-terminating-early-when-for-loop-variable-is-very-big

Comment: @Patrice My kind of perspective on this is that I see some beginners who are earnest but just so terribly naive. They cannot really be set on the right path through a mere answer of what's wrong with their basic code snippet. It's the wrong context for them to be properly educated. Yet at the heart of that code snippet is the hidden question, "How does recursion work?", e.g. I see that question there, disguised, and my thought is that it wouldn't be so bad if there was actually such a question on the site -- but I'm reacting to a symptom rather than the root.

Comment: @Ike The problem is that Stack is not meant as a learning tool AT ALL, so those extremely basic misconceptions are not something that Stack can cure. Stack is just ONE arrow in a quiver of tools for coders. If you get blocked and your first step when faced with "How does recursion work" is to jump on stack instead of doing a modicum of research (let's be honest, if user is blocked with recursion in this way on a question that is already asked elsewhere, this is HOMEWORK, and he should use the proper resource there (ie: his teacher/TA)), then it may be hard to help them....

Comment: @Patrice We have a seeming army of students nevertheless pounding the site. :-( One thing is that I like SO conceptually as a learning tool. Maybe because of my former teaching experience (albeit brief), I see it as a way to sharpen skills at educating -- that people providing answers are basically competing at being the best teacher. Perhaps that's a very personal view, but with SO as an "uber knowledge base" (a goal I see cited often), a knowledge base would often imply to me a prioritization of the basic things people need to learn/wonder about.

Comment: @Ike not at all. There can be a site for tutorial, "here's what you need to learn to being coding in language X", and a site for more involved issues. The thing I see is that BECAUSE Stack is so good, people come here and expect it to fix EVERYTHING. I had to break this out of my own mindset rapidly. Honestly, Stack is just one resource out of SO MANY. Having a "here's what you need to know to start coding" isn't really something that can fit the Q&A format. If anything, I would suggest a detailed blog post that you can show in your comments to these types of questions

Comment: @Patrice That's true -- ideally the best platform would be outside this site for such basics. I've seen people state that SO should be the last place you look to for help when you've exhausted the other possibilities, and I would agree -- it would be wonderful if that was how it was used (imagine how interesting and challenging all the questions would be!). At the moment I'm just reacting to the questions I'm seeing, and what they're actually seeming to often want to ask at the heart of the matter.

Comment: @Patrice My biggest fear, to be honest, is that I look at magnificent posts from professional users. Their answers made me join the site. But they're old, even one of my heroes (Mysticial) said he kind of lost interest and hasn't done much with SO in a year. I worry that these amazing posts will become rarer, while the beginner student "please fix this" posts will become more and more common. It's not the number of low-quality posts I'm worried about, I'm worried that somehow these will drown out the high-quality ones and cause the pros to lose interest.

Comment: @Ike there is a good chance that these good posts stop happening. The problem is that you won't get good posters back by ENCOURAGING terrible questions around. If we start reading INTO the question to help out the user who doesn't even understand his own issue, we end up encouraging him to come back with crappier and crappier questions, no? I see what you're trying to do, and I highly respect you for it (100% sincere here, normally new users aren't like you and it's a VERY nice change), but I don't see if your way to go at it will be beneficial. I may very well be too cynical here though

Comment: @Patrice I appreciate that the goal is understood even if my suggestions for it are bad and might have the opposite effect! It's an admittedly-selfish one though. I couldn't believe how good some of the answers on this site were before (sometimes better than acclaimed books), but many of them are old. I find some great ones still today but they tend to receive less attention with the influx of questions -- quality seems more fleeting, transient now because of the traffic, less likely to be noticed. I mainly just want to see more of those answers that inspired me in the first place.

Comment: @Patrice Everything I'm thinking about is trying to place myself in the shoes of the Mysticials out there, the world record holder for computing pi to the largest number of digits, wow -- an unbelievable contributor to the site. With such legends in our midst, how do we keep them inspired, interested, challenged? That might lie at the heart of my questions (making them all duplicates! :-D).

Comment: He would have calculate pi to even more digits if his anime collection had left enough disk space.

Comment: "Duplicates don't get automatically cleaned up (as quickly if at all)" The 2022 state of affairs: currently, it takes 3 downvotes to make a closed question qualify for deletion, and 3 votes to either close or delete. The way I see it, if I dupe-hammer a question and vote to delete, I have already gotten it 4/9 of the way there, **plus** I have headed off any attempts to answer the question that could interfere with the Roomba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference questions are perfectly fine, *so long as they're well-written.*  Poorly written reference questions are going to get closed just like every other poorly-written question.

Some examples of good reference questions:

[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

And many others.

Reference questions are strengthened by a good tag wiki.  The [PHP Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) is one of the best ones on the site.  The Tag Wiki becomes a "Table of Contents" for the reference questions.

There are dangers to the close as dupe process, however.

1. **"Your answer is over here."**  This is absolutely the wrong way to close as dupe, unless you're definitively answering his specific question with a reference question.  Don't make people hunt for answers in a question that doesn't seem to have any resemblance to the OP's question.
2. **If a reference question does not exist,** the dupe target really needs to be *asking the same question as the OP.*  This is a variation on "Your answer is over here," except that this time you haven't even bothered to identify a suitable reference question.

There are great rewards to the site for those folks who take the time to write up good reference questions.  Reference questions are one of the few avenues we have left that meet the goal of "providing a repository of useful programming knowledge."  The vast majority of questions asked on Stack Overflow nowadays are "help me fix my broken code" questions, which seldom help anyone else but the OP.

Comment: That "fix my code -- P.S. what's a debugger?" syndrome is what bothers me most. There's so many of them and I'm really sad because I see glimmers of brilliance here, a reminder of the potential of this site, and next to it is that a wasteland of "fix my code" questions. I was tempted to write and answer my own kind of reference question like "How do I debug C++ code?" with a comprehensive answer covering all kinds of debuggers which I want to link for all these "fix my code" Qs, but I was afraid that my question, being in such basic/broad form, would be down-voted to death if not closed.

Comment: @Ike: And therein lies the danger.  You can't close every "what's wrong with my C++ code" question as a duplicate of "How do I debug C++ code?"  That's basically saying "The C++ tag community will no longer be accepting code troubleshooting questions," which is not a defensible position.

Comment: 'help me fix my broken code' is an optimistic description,  I'm rapidly reaching the point where I believe that the majority of such code is copied from web pages or copied from other students, (either stolen without permission or copied with permission and a fee for completing it).

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's very awkward for sure. There are definitely legit troubleshooting questions where, say, a question about Qt is actually relevant to the Qt library. But when posed by a beginner who doesn't know how to debug yet about a segfault in code using Qt, it often has nothing to do with Qt, and just a basic misunderstanding of the language. That's the issue I see as the worst -- the lack of debugging knowledge often poses a variety of shape-shifting questions posed in contexts which ultimately boil down to an issue not relevant to those contexts.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Whether the question is about how recursion works in the context of a binary search tree or a segfault in a code using a sparse matrix, these questions look very precise, but at the heart of them are often the underlying themes, "How does a pointer work? How does recursion work? How do I debug this code?" The general question is there, underlying all these common ultra-beginner level troubleshooting questions, it's just not explicitly stated -- it becomes revealed through a faulty code snippet.

Comment: @Ike Questions like that should simply be closed as Too Broad or Unclear, not Closed as Duplicate to a reference question that provides general guidance but no actual answer to the OP's specific problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My sadness is that what "should happen" and what "does happen" don't seem to align here so often, I'm looking at the same bleak kind of picture Martin is seeing as one who frequents the same tags. But I'll try to be more active about doing this kind of thing personally and hope for the best.