# Jon Skeet flagged low quality. How to handle this LQ post?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I guess it happens to the best of us: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5308506.

Screenshot:

> [image]
>
> That depends on what you mean by "represent". Do you just want round-tripping, or the decimal representation of the exact value? Does it have to be human readable, or could you just treat the 4/8 bytes as opaque binary data and base64 or hex encode them?

What would you do? Delete? Vote? Skip?

Comment: "*Answer not found*". Any screenshots for us plebs?

Comment: 6 votes seems a little excessive. Is that because of his rep or just that people wanted to be immortalised as one of the jury that got to remove one of Jon Skeets' posts

Comment: LOL, I have no idea. It just showed up in my queue. It was a comment, not an answer, so the hammer fell as it does for everyone.

Comment: A bit of a delayed reaction, as the answer was posted in Nov '09.  Indeed, it is a comment and not an answer.  BTW, it was deleted 13 minutes ago.

Comment: I really need to pay more attention to the post dates. I think SO didn't get serious about that sort of thing until late '09 / early 2010.

Comment: It really doesn't matter...it will probably regenerate itself soon and ban all users who deleted

Comment: @Qantas I'd accept the screenshot as the answer.

Comment: Only when Jon Skeet grows another hydra head.

Comment: I like to think the OP above was a young Martijn Pieters before he earned his j.

Comment: The answer was posted before there was a comment feature. It should still be deleted, but that's why it exists.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I would accept that as an answer, as well. Please provide some historical context. I discovered SO in 2012, so I didn't know there was a time before comments.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I'm wrong about that; there were comments a lot earlier than I thought. I'm trying to find the exact date.

Comment: The first comment ever was [reportedly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/) by [Jeff Atwood, in 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-or-operators/35314#comment1_35314).

Comment: **Five. Years. Ago.**

Sheesh,  I hope nobody's keeping track of what *I* did five years ago.

Comment: When I saw this question in the sidebar I wondered what the odds would be that it was somehow related to my earlier downvote and flag ... well, it's gone now :)

Comment: I've seen a certain 200K+ user posting "similar answers" even now.

Comment: _What would you do?_ -- Don't delete by yourself.  Simply downvote and move on.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Lol.  We all know what _you_ did last summer.

Comment: When I saw this in the review queue I took a *long* look at it... but did vote to delete.

Comment: I thought only Jon Skeet could delete answers by Jon Skeet. This answer was probably posted by the first draft of the answering bot he wrote.

Comment: it would be interesting to know what Jon Skeet thinks about it now `:P`

Comment: @GolezTrol I was going to comment this was posted five years ago when Jon Skeet was young and inexperienced. But yours is funnier.

Comment: Was he? Or maybe SO was too inexperienced to give him the recognition he should have had from the moment he signed on.

Comment: @GolezTrol this post appeared on meta because may be He is bored and whated to troll us LOL `:P`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899502/can-i-use-sql-to-find-missing-numbers-in-the-example-table-i-give-below/899520#899520 , you mean? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey the internet remembers **everything**.

Comment: Worthless question: if an answer is low quality it's low quality regardless of who asked it

Comment: Torch 'im!!!!!!!

Comment: @AustinMullins sorry to disappoint you; my account predates that post (albeit in a semi-dormant state still). Besides, my [`ij` doesn't come in sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_%28digraph%29), like Dutch clogs it's all one piece.

Comment: This is evidence that even individuals who potentially have a lot to contribute to the community, may make some mistakes early on.  Mistakes which some people seem to think are destroying the site and justify taking a very hostile stance against such offenders.  Of course we have to delete stuff like this and keep things cleaned up, but imagine who we might be turning away if we take an attitude of hostility towards such individuals instead of an attitude of education.

Comment: Great point @AaronLS.

Comment: @AaronLS "*[...] may make some mistakes early on*", or later. We all have bad days.

Comment: Why close as off-topic? Isn't "not constructive" a better reason?

Comment: @AustinMullins Does the "Not Constructive" reason still exist? I thought that reason was removed a while ago

Comment: @user3580294 would explain it.

Comment: It is so unfortunate that SO still doesn't have a tag called "Ask Jon Skeet"

Comment: skeet is a self entitled smart*ss. He acts cocky and know it all in all his posts, like what he knows can't be read in books. Well I have bad news for him. I wrote better code and he's angry about it

Answer (score 173, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't matter who posted it.

It's not an answer, it's a request for clarification. It does not provide, or even attempt to provide, a solution to the problem. It should be deleted.

I should note, however, that this answer was posted in the very early days of the site, when things were a little bit looser. That doesn't justify keeping it around now, however.

Comment: The answer was posted in November 2009. Comments had existed long before then. In fact, you can see that there are comments on the question all dated shortly *after* this answer.

Comment: Thanks, @BoltClock; I was looking for some kind of feature announcement just now and realized I was wrong about the date. Trying to figure out when...

Comment: Can't seem to find it on the blog either.

Comment: I got it; see [my comment above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265771/jon-skeet-flagged-low-quality/265776?noredirect=1#comment62057_265771).

Comment: I agree.  Let's send a message to those that provide "answers" like these.  BAN JON SKEET.

Comment: Haha!  Actually Jon Skeet can afford to post such "answers" now.  I'm certain that such answers by him would now attract a dozen upvotes in lesser number of seconds.

Comment: It's also possible that John Skeet didn't have commenting privilege at that time.

Comment: His [rep tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=71) shows more than enough rep earned by that point to reach the comment threshold.

Comment: OMG there were days when he failed to score the max 200 rep!

Comment: I'm sure I was able to comment then, and indeed I should have done so. This definitely counts as a low quality post, and deserved to be deleted. I have no problem with that at all.

Comment: @ClickRick: Indeed, since September 26th 2009 I've had 22 days where I didn't earn 200 rep, and 40 days where I didn't get to 200 rep just from votes (i.e. I didn't actually hit the cap).

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I have less days where I *did* earn 200 rep and *did* hit the rep cap XD

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess that you saw the difference now.  Any other similar "answer" would have been downvoted into oblivion before being deleted.  Lucky you!

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh my!  I didn't realize that you've already earned this -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=22656

Comment: @devnull Look at Jon's recent answers : none of them got a dozen upvotes. It's certain his name brings attention to his answers, and probably some upvotes, but that's not a magical device making them all accepted and stellarly upvoted.

Comment: @devnull You were clearly unaware of how much he had to pay to get enough people to do that.

Comment: @devnull even the best of us have an occasional off day, or just guess wrong about someone's ambiguous question prior to them clarifying what they meant.

Comment: I just wish he had answered this question with a comment, thereby giving the middle finger to everyone.

Comment: How dare you??!

Comment: Note to self: never ever answer a question involving Jon Skeet again. This is idiotic.

Comment: @devnull He surely did for earning the badge :p

Answer (score 13):

What do you mean "what would I do"? The same thing as with every low quality post, and this *is* one of those.

Jon is a great contributor but he is not a god to whom you must only ever attribute praise and glory. He is a human being, on Stack Overflow.

Can we move on now? Skeetmania is kinda boring.

Comment: It says "Skeet", nuff said.

Comment: Let us make Lightmania, and pray for our next overlord.

Comment: I'd argue that whining on Meta about perceived Skeetmania (which is all this answer adds to the discussion) is just as boring.