# Users rep not taken into consideration while deciding a answer as low quality

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Users rep should be taken into consideration while deciding a answer as low quality. I think this answer should not have come into the review queue.

Link to original post -> [Python: Length of longest common subsequence of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547641/python-length-of-longest-common-subsequence-of-lists)

[image: pick showing the issue]

Comment: Did you consider that this may be a review audit?

Comment: Yes... i did go through it quickly.

Comment: If you went through that quickly... then you may wish to review your reviewing strategy :p

Comment: Yup I take a note of that. But I do go through them and it's easy to find out how the answer is. You can check my review queue history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, reputation should not be taken into consideration when flagging/deciding on low quality.

Last week there was a post about [Jon Skeet flagged low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265771/jon-skeet-flagged-low-quality) (mainly because the post was already 5 years old) so your logic is flawed.

To cite [Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell) from his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265776/2829009):

> it doesn't matter who posted it.

Answer (score 1):

That post was an audit - you were *supposed* to read it and say "Looks OK".

Not because of the author's reputation though; because it's clearly not a piece of irredeemable garbage. It was a test, to make sure you were paying attention.

Because, believe it or not, some folks *do* flag answers like this, and we depend on folks like you to tell them to take a hike.