# If the answer I give is garbage, should I delete it?

Tags: discussion

I foolishly answered a question in haste, and, although answering the question, I did not give the best answer. {*hangs head in shame*}

I've learned my lesson and won't do this again.

But now I have a dilemma, the answer I gave is crap essentially. Someone else gave a much better answer. Should I just delete my answer? Or should I leave it be for posterity?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt8TC.png

Comment: My answer was not downvoted.

Comment: Absolutely delete it. Just yesterday I posted an answer that was completely wrong, and I realized it almost immediately after hitting the Post button. I clicked "delete" as fast as I could, hoping that nobody had seen it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately my answer was seen and I was chastised for my flawed response (rightly so- I deserved it). :)

Comment: I once deleted a completely wrong answer that had been upvoted twice, the most upvotes I had gotten on an answer in the previous few days.

Comment: You might not delete it if you *feel* it is crap only *compared* to the other answer, but is still correct. I only delete wrong or non-answers.

Comment: voted to reopen it again because question is bit different..

Comment: [top answer in duplicate question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263048/839601) seems to cover this under #2: "If I no longer feel my answer provides anything useful to future readers of the question, I delete it."

Comment: @RossRidge: If you had waited for one more upvote before deleting, you could have gotten yourself the http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined badge.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The answer I gave is crap essentially Should I just delete my answer?

Yes you should delete it if you feel it is completely crap. It happens with everyone except [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) & we delete it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will delete it!

Comment: Nope. It happened to Jon Skeet too: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265771/jon-skeet-flagged-low-quality-how-to-handle-this-lq-post

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=22656

Comment: I remember that John Skeet even deleted his correct answer, because he was lower scored than the best other answer.

Comment: Jon Skeet thinks very highly of his presence here don't piss him off.