# Indicate when answer comes from the post author in 'Low quality post' review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

For instance in this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8424833) the user give the solution he found to solve its problem. Even the answer could be improved, it helps the author and so perhaps others peoples. Then I think it should not be deleted.

Often reviewing I notice that I check if the answer comes from the post author, perhaps others reviewers too ?

Perhaps it is possible to indicate this information in the review header ?

Comment: Eh, it's easy to scroll down to see the author of the question.  And it's often irrelevant, unless it looks like it's supposed to be an edit.

Comment: Yeah, besides it's easy to scroll down and check the answers currently given, this situation might deserve some extra notice. May be, it's no longer that easy today, some of our great and in depth canonical questions (like e.g. [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)), start out with an incredible poor question (same for my rare attempts on canonicals).

Comment: @ryanyuyu : sure but sometimes the question is so long that you cannot see the user of the answer and the user of the post on the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That information is already present. The blue background on the usercard of the answer's author indicates that the user is also the question author:

[image]

If the post is not by the author of the question, the usercard looks like this:

[image]

It's important to note that this circumstance should not change the way you review the post in the Low Quality review queue. [The identity of the poster isn't a saving grace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265776/603977) there (or anywhere, really).

Comment: Thanks I did not notice this. I think it matter when the user precise in its answer some details that should better takes place in its question. In such a situation I could let a comment in this sens.