# Can we stop posting LQP auto-comments on answers from SO's dark ages?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, etiquette, automatic-comments

I see a fair number of auto-comments on ancient answers (2008, 2009, and 2010 vintage, and occasionally newer — usually posted by users who now have a fair amount of rep) where sure, the auto-comment is quite right: that **is** a comment, or a link-only answer, or whatever. But it just seems tacky and redundant to notify, say, Jon Skeet*, "Dude, we're totally deleting one of your old comment-ish answers from when SO didn't really get that those were a bad idea." *He knows they're a bad idea already.*

I'm not, of course, arguing that the *deletion* is unwarranted. Delete away! It's just the tone-deaf use of auto-comments, as though if a vaguely-fitting auto-comment isn't selected, it doesn't "count" or something. Ugh.

If the user can reasonably be expected to be somewhat aware of these policies, and the post is from before they were set in place, there's no reason to bug them about it, at least not with auto-comments.

<sub>**Slight exaggeration, but I'm not sure I haven't seen one of Skeet's answers getting the axe…*</sub>

Comment: Where do you draw the line then?  Should auto-comments be stopped on any post?  On posts with a power above a certain rep value?  On content that's gone past a specific age?

Comment: Mostly, a) users that have enough rep they should reasonably know what's up *and* b) posts that predate the policies.

Comment: I'm not so sure I agree.  First, not everyone (not even Skeet himself) started out with *a ton* of reputation or understood the rules of engagement.  Second, the questions of yesteryear are being applied to the standards of today.  If you're saying that the standard process of today doesn't mesh well with older questions, then it's likely the fault of the process and not the message being delivered (even if it is an automatic comment).

Comment: @Makoto: The comment is optional. It's optional for a reason. This is that reason, to my mind. And whether or not the user in question understood the policy *then* is not really the point; the point is whether they have already figured it out *by now*: if the post is so old it can't indicate any ignorance or rejection of the policy, and the user would otherwise be expected to get it, then there's no need to belabor them with tedious notifications. Only if someone *needs to be instructed* should they have the auto-comments used.

Comment: So I return to my original question then; where do we draw the line?  I'll be blunt; I've seen users with 5K, 10K, 20K, or even 50K+ reputation need a chiding every now and then.

Comment: @Makoto: If you see them *still doing it*, that's when you post the comment. If there's no reason to suppose J Random High-Rep User failed to get the message when it was hashed out on Meta, simply deleting is all that's really needed.

Comment: Again, this assumes that a reviewer has the wherewithal to follow up on some high rep user's progress with posting content that makes its way into that queue...and given the attentiveness of *most* reviewers that make their presence known on Meta, I have my doubts that such a scenario would happen.

Comment: @Makoto: No no, this is a stateless algorithm. I am proposing that any reviewer that comes across a modern instance should act in the usual way, and any reviewer that sees a post that, given no information other than presented in the queue, matches these two criteria, forgo the commenting. No tracking, no recognition, nothing but on-the-spot heuristics.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the part where you're excluding the human(?) reviewer in this heuristic.  If you're looking to educate the reviewer themselves, you're in for a ***long*** battle uphill.  But in actuality, I say we address this problem when we have a deluge of high-rep users that feel like they get it and are annoyed by the comments.

Comment: @Makoto: This is not a feature-request, because there is no software change desired. This is a discussion, because there's a change in community behavior desired. And while we could, of course, wait for high-rep users to collectively get sufficiently annoyed, it seems reasonable enough to preempt the source of irritation before it gets too individually severe, as long as the broader patterns are plain to see.

Comment: Frankly I think the only issue is the tone of the comments - they are clearly tailored to new users, so to a seasoned user they may come across as patronizing or ignorant. When I see an old post by a seasoned user I always write a custom comment instead before reviewing, something like "Hey, your post was recently flagged for review, you may want to update or remove this." and they're always happy to oblige.

Comment: Skeet delete: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265771/603977

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I detest how noisy these comments become, and [it turns out they're not particularly effective on old posts either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317388/a-lot-of-while-this-link-may-answer-the-question-whats-happening/318484#318484). So...

> - On answers 6 months old or older, the "link only" comment will be the *only* one available in review.
> - Once a week, a scheduled task will delete *all* comments generated from review that didn't result in the answer being deleted (unless they sparked a conversation).

Comment: How old must those comments be at the time to be eligible? A week to a month sounds reasonable...

Comment: The age of the *comments* is irrelevant, @Deduplicator. The check ensures the post has gone through review (and the moderator queue, if needed) first; if that happens and it's still not deleted, it's probably not going to be.

Answer (score 24):

Honestly nudging high rep users who should know better is probably a lot more effective than nudging new users.

Using your example, I'm sure Jon Skeet would take the time to update one of his old answers if it received an auto-comment from a review queue. Shouldn't that be the more desirable result? Rather than having info lost to deletion we may see it fleshed out into a proper modern answer.

I've had a couple of times where I have seen high-rep/moderator's old posts land in the VLQ. I opted to send more personal messages rather than just using one of the canned messages. Something along the lines of:

> "Hey your post landed in the VLQ review, you may want to take a look
>   at it."

Comment: Hmm. If it's link-only ... maybe. If it's just a comment, there's not much to be done at this point; it's probably not needed anyway.

Comment: @NathanTuggy In that case wouldn't a high rep user just opt to delete their own old noise?

Comment: That's actually a fair point, although it may or may not come in time to really save any effort. Still, hmm.

Comment: Accepting after edit because I've sent custom comments myself.