# A lot of "while this link may answer the question" - what's happening?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I've started getting a lot of "while this link may answer the question" review comments recently, on quite old answers (4-5 years old).
Ok, I did not have much experience back then, I'd answer these questions differently now.

But still, most links are still good and helpful and I'm definitely not going to improve these old answers.

What surprises me is that it started to happen just a few days ago. What is the reason for this?

Next, does it really makes sense to waste review resources on those old answers? I mean, yes, these *are* one-link answers but is it really likely that they will be improved after 5 years of being there?

Comment: As you know I left a comment under one of your answer that I reviewed (which I skipped after spending time googling without your link to understand if the answer was useful), this to let you know it was in review que and seeing your activity I was sure that it could become a great answer. The main problem I think (whether we like it or not)  is that there is a great risk that the LQP que will delete these answers (not everybody is up to googling, understanding the issue, evaluating etc.). Why not spend sometime improving them?, making them great?.. for the good of SO and avoid other users del.

Comment: If there are a few (perhaps even to undelete at this point), I am happy to have a go at putting some highlights of the article in. I did it recently off a github posting from someone. It is not a blast, but I will.

Comment: Rather than delete answers you don't care to maintain/improve, you decided it would be better to write a meta post to "waste resources" complaining about other people wasting resources?

Comment: "Is it really likely that they will be improved after 5 years of being there?" Well when your attitude is "I'm definitely not going to improve these old answers", then it's less likely.

Comment: @TylerH It's less of an attitude, more of lack of time vs. "is it really worth it" balance.

Comment: @cimmanon I was just wondering why my old answers were targeted, that's all.

Comment: @lexicore And now that you're advertising on meta that you're not interested in improving bad answers you've posted, you're inviting yourself to be scrutinized even further.

Comment: @cimmanon But that's not bad at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What surprizes me is that it started to happen just a few days ago. What is the reason for this?

I checked your flag history, and it looks like someone went through your answers and serially flagged them as "not an answer" recently. This would have resulted in your answers being queued for review.

> Next, does it really makes sense to waste review resources on those old answers? I mean, yes, these are one-link answers but is it really likely that they will be improved after 5 years of being there?

Ironically, it would seem that everyone who's reviewed your answers agrees with you, seeing as not one of them has spent any time improving your answers either. All they've done is leave canned comments as if you were new and needed to be educated on why link-only answers are so harmful to the site.

The review system works fine with old posts, but many reviewers don't realize that things weren't as strict a few years ago as they are today and proceed to leave canned comments that sound belittling to veteran users, leaving a bad taste in their mouths. This is why, when reviewing old link-only answers, I either

- delete them without commenting at all, or
- leave a *custom comment* letting the author know that their old answer was flagged, if the answer seems like it would be worth their time editing into shape.

If you don't wish to improve your answers, you are not required to, but they'll just get deleted eventually whether through the review process or by a moderator (at their discretion).

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll leave them because it's pretty likely that newer better anwers exist already. I was just wondering if it's some change in the review scheduling algorithms or new policies.
However, I still don't think these answers are harmful so I'll leave them as is. If the consensus will be that they should be deleted, I'm fine with that, but that's not my opinion.

Comment: Just curious, @lexicore: If newer, better answers exist, _and_ the consensus is that link-only answers should be deleted, why wouldn't you just remove them? To be blunt, you have nothing to gain from keeping them there. They may even get downvoted, if they're not deleted. Of course, you're entitled to your opinion on whether or not they should be removed, but I don't really see the point in keeping them.

Comment: Because I still think these answers provide valueable, helpful pointers. Take [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869547/jaxb-creating-modules-for-reuse/5876215#5876215), for instance. It links to a [full guide](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation) on how to configure modular schema compilation. The link is still valid and the information is correct, relevant and helpful. Yes, this is a "textbook link-only answer". But is it helpful or is it harmful?

Comment: @Cerbrus To make it clear, I am the author of the tool in scope ([tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin]) and I've linked to what was reference documentation at that moment.

Comment: The problem with those link only answers is that they lose all value when the link dies. A better alternative is a short explanation, accompanied with a link to the full documentation. Generally, links are bonus material in an answer. A answer should still answer the question if not a single link in there works.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm quite aware of this position. You've asked why I won't delete my post, this is the answer. No longer worth improving, still helpful as it is.
The "better alternative" means that I have to invest even more time. I've already invested time to write the original guide (and the tool behind that) so investing even more time is not a "better alternative" for me.

Comment: "canned comments", I hope your not referring to mine, then I'm sorry, I was actually trying to help, so user could see it was in review que and from a simple/normal review point of view it could risk deletion (see screen shot in answer below), I deleted my comment as @lexicore responded.

Comment: I'm going to be blunt again: What the "better alternative" is for you is irrelevant. Answers on SO should benefit users looking for answers. You chose to post that link as an answer, which means there are some standards / rules the answer should follow. If that sentence were posted as a comment, instead, there wouldn't have been a problem. If we're talking about investing time: Clicking the "delete" button requires a trivial amount of effort compared to posting a meta question.

Comment: @PetterFriberg your comment was a nice one. It also showed you put some effort in with google to show a good reason to improve the answer. By deleting the comment, it shows to me at least that one gets easily intimidated :P

Comment: @Drew I know where you live... and you know where I'm from.... (lets say I do not like to litter post if user does not agree)... better to move on....

Comment: Yes. We are not a Commonwealth.

Comment: @PetterFriberg You took care, put effort and left a nice comment - thank you for this.

Answer (score 25):

For some reason, those answers seem to have gotten some kind of attention, resulting in a "link-only answer" flag.

The standards of quality have changed a bit, in those years, so they may no longer be considered good enough.

If you can, you *should* improve those answers, if you have a moment to spare.

---

I don't think this is a waste of review resources. Only the "Close-vote" queue has problems with the amount of flags / votes. the rest of the queues empty out quick enough.
Think of it like cleaning out that one drawer you dump stuff in and never look back at.

---

That said, one example of an answer that would probably be better off, if deleted, would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876215/1835379):

[image]

That's a textbook link-only answer.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect you meant it rhetorically, but this is a rather good question:

> is it really likely that they will be improved after 5 years of being there?

Well, here are the numbers for "link-only answer" comments:

- They've been left on 101,608 answers
- 10,178 of those answers have been subsequently edited
- 6,864 of *those* are not currently deleted

And here are the numbers for "link-only answer" comments on old answers:

- They've been left on 6,241 answers aged 5 years old at the time of the comment's creation
- 186 of those answers were subsequently edited
- 39 of *those* answers are not currently deleted

So, the answer to the question is "no" - it *isn't* particularly likely that they'll be edited, much less actually be improved.

However, at least they *can* be improved. We can't do much more than give folks the *chance* to improve them, but we can at least do that.

Truth is, once you get more than a month out, the chance of anything useful happening in response to *any* of the canned review comments is pretty low. They become little more than noise, the sorts of meta commentary you usually see junking up traditional forums. And Stack Overflow is supposed to be a place *without* all that "forum noise".

So starting today, let's try something:

- On answers 6 months old or older, the "link only" comment will be the *only* one available in review.
- Once a week, a scheduled task will delete *all* comments generated from review that didn't result in the answer being deleted (unless they sparked a conversation).

If you don't care to improve these answers, they'll still be deleted, but perhaps by making this commentary a bit less noisy we can emphasize the importance of it.

Comment: Currently the presence of old review comments signals to me that while someone agreed with me that an answer is bad, it isn't bad enough to merit deletion, so I shouldn't bother sending it through the queue again.  Is there any other way to find out that a post survived a previous review?  (On the other hand I'm happy to see them cleaned up, especially on those few posts that actually do get edited.)

Comment: You normally *can't* send a post through review twice, @Jeffrey - if it gets flagged again, it'll go straight into the moderator queue.

Comment: Nice to know, but my question stands: if review comments are being deleted, how do I know I probably shouldn't bug the mods with this one?  Or am I just not supposed to care about review history?

Comment: You can get it via the timeline (although there's a bug with that right now). But yeah, normally I'd say don't worry about it - either the answer is bad enough to flag or it isn't.

Comment: These comments aren't deleted if the post itself is deleted, right?  Because if the post itself is deleted then the comment isn't adding noise; it just means that if the author *does* get the notification they'll be able to see why the post was deleted (whether they care enough to improve it or not).

Comment: Correct, @Servy. They aren't even deleted if the post is deleted from review and then undeleted, because that'd be kinda stupid. Once the comment has a shot at having been effective, we'd want them to be cleaned up manually (if at all).

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly "unless they sparked a conversation" means? Does it mean that they're exempt from automatic deletion if *any* comment was posted after the review one, or does any subsequent comment specifically have to @-reply to the user who posted the review comment?

Comment: Effectively, the author was not replied to anywhere in the thread, @gparyani - either explicitly (`@author`) or implicitly (per normal rules for implicit replies).

Answer (score 8):

We're looking at changing the selectable comments if a post is over a certain age, and possibly re-working some of the standard comments to boot. If you have 5 posts that landed in review over this, what you see is:

- While this link may answer the question ...
- While this link may answer the question ...
- While this link may answer the question ...
- While this link may answer the question ...
- While this link may answer the question ...

That's not incredibly helpful because it leaves you thinking:

> *but if I answered the damn question, why are you bothering me?!*

What's needed here is something that actually stands a shot at motivating you to *go fix it* by:

- Thanking you for helping
- Telling you that it could be much more helpful with just a tiny amount of additional effort
- (ironically) linking you to something that shows how simple pulling context from a link often is
- informs you that the answer might be removed ***and why***, so please try to find a few minutes in the next week or two, but we're totally cool if you're busy.

There's also something to be said for merging signals here, since they're essentially telling you the same thing - but there needs to be another clear way to get back to the list of stuff that was identified if you're going to do anything.

Summarizing, the system was working in that it identified stuff that could use more attention if you have it to give. It wasn't working in that it did very little to motivate you, and actually accomplished the opposite.

We'll see what we can do after we've looked into it some more.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. A bit of my perspective. I'm a tool author and I wrote reference documentation to cover the exact topic. I've answered with a link to that reference documentation five years ago. So suggestions to copy-paste my reference documentation to StackOverflow or to summarize my reference documentation for StackOverflow because my link-only answer was marked in a review are not really motivating. I've put a lot of resources in it already. At the same time, the link is still alive and helpful.

Comment: *"Thanking you for helping"* - On the fence about that one. It is too easy to read "thanks for helping, but not really because insert reasons here" into it. IMO.

Comment: @TimPost You might take the account's age into... account, relative to its first post, and say something more welcoming to newbies who have the "help a fellow person" mindset instead of the "build a Q&A repository" mindset the current comment comes from.  I've seen some users leaving their own pro forma comments that start with a "Welcome, we're a bit different" sentence (and also mention in the last sentence that the answer may be deleted, with a link to the meta rationale). Basically the current comments fell into the trap of being written for people who don't need them.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom That is _not_ a bad idea.