# Handle auto generated review comments automatically

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools

Please can mod tools automatically do the right thing to automatically generated comments:

1. When converting to comment discount them entirely for the purpose of "auto convert comments". That means never convert them if you are converting comments and pretend they don't exist when deciding if that option should be present.
2. When declining associated flags as "no evidence to support" automatically delete them.
3. When no action->helpful delete them as obsolete if the post had been edited.

They're automatically generated and ephemeral, so it makes sense for their moderation to also be automated off the signals that already exist.

Comment: [Review comments are now deleted weekly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318484/3614835) if they didn't result in the post being deleted "unless they sparked a conversation".  Does that help with point 2?