# Don't make a reviewer manually leave a comment when an answer 'has been on the site for quite a while'

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, automatic-comments

Apparently, when reviewing an older answer in the Low Quality Posts queue, you don't get the usual list of comments to choose from:

> [image: screenshot of the dialog]

Why do you want a reviewer to leave the review queue and manually type out a comment that somewhat resembles one of the auto comments? What benefit does this have?

Please show the usual list of comments.

Answer (score 4):

The last line of the dialog explains why we don't think commenting is a good idea:

> This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary.

There's very little point adding a comment, especially a predefined comment, to an answer that's several years old. The author might not be active on the site any more, or if they are active they might have moved on to other things and might not be in a position to improve the answer.

If you really want to comment then open the answer in another tab/window and comment from there, but please bear in mind that your comment is more than likely going to fall on deaf ears.

Comment: So what if it does, what does it hurt? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Stijn [People complain that they're expected to update their old answers now that Stack Overflow has higher standards.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317388/a-lot-of-while-this-link-may-answer-the-question-whats-happening) Apparently, they'd prefer them to just be deleted silently.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Ah, I see. Thank you.