# Review system wrongly detects a link-only answers

Tags: bug, review-queues

When reviewing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14019856), when clicking on *Delete* option, the system wrongly detects that:

> This is a link-only answer (and not spam)

despite the answer doesn't have any links at all, so there is no any possibility to select any other pre-defined comment as usual (e.g. *This is commentary* which is not available).

The same for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14022334).

---

[image: Stack Exchange - Review|Low Quality Posts filter - This is a link-only answer (and not spam)]

Comment: I remember that autocomments on post older than 60 (?) days are disabled, but LOA .BTW, is not the sistem that does.

Answer (score 6):

The system doesn't try to detect link-only at all. It only removed the other options. Posts that have a certain age (6 months, as [pointed out by Gimby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336534/review-system-wrongly-detects-a-link-only-answers/336541?noredirect=1#comment405691_336541)) don't give you the other possible auto-comments because they probably don't help anymore.

Note the sentence at the bottom:

> The answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary.

Comment: [6 months](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319367/424903). Kind of oddly specific that the link-only reason is allowed to stay.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks, edited that in.