# Why was this moderator intervention flag declined on a link only accepted answer?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, specific-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560134/scrolling-a-div-with-animate-on-mousedown-and-stop-on-mouse-up/7560669#7560669), which is nothing more than a link to jsfiddle, for moderator intervention. It was also the accepted answer. The flag was declined with the explanation:

> "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

Normally I'd flag this type of answer as very low quality, but since it has two upvotes that isn't an option. The answer explains nothing, and even admits to being buggy. What's the logic for declining the flag?

Comment: This is a link-only answer, and should be deleted, or have the content from the link edited into the body.  Maybe your message in the mod flag wasn't clear?

Comment: Can't you vote to delete directly? I'm a lowly 3K user, so I'm not sure, but I thought that at your rep level, you could.

Comment: @yivi No, it has currently two upvotes and deleting it isn't an option. I believe it needs a net -2 for that.

Comment: I would have flagged as NAA, myself. (Standard flag, which may have been the gist of the mod rejection). Still, since the answer is (was) positively scored, a mod would have had to review the flag anyway...

Comment: The text of your custom mod flag is also relevant to see why would a mod reject your flag. A good explanation, with the important bits in the beggining, is more likely to be successful.

Comment: Since its the only answer, the jsfiddle should have some weight. (Guess not, its deleted now.)

Comment: Next time can you add that it's the accepted answer in the flag?

Comment: Why not copy the relevant text from the link and then edit the answer to include it? You would be improving the answer and also allowing the answer to remain for others in the future.

Comment: (what was the answer? ...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I cannot answer why the flag was declined. I deleted the answer now and left a comment for the author. You did the right thing raising that flag.

It was an accepted answer, which means it won't be deleted through the review queues on review votes, only the mods can see it, as it requires moderators to delete it.

Next time make a note in the flag that it's an accepted answer or if an answer is highly upvoted, raise a custom flag explaining why.

The comment I left:

> This is essentially a link only answer, as if the link dies, the answer is useless. Please raise a mod flag to have your answer undeleted if you edit it to retain all the pertinent details within the answer. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not as if the flag raised was a NAA flag. The OP raised a custom flag where a NAA flag would have suited. At that point the community could have handled deleting that post without moderator intervention. (disclaimer: not the mod that declined the flag, but I would probably have done the same).

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was an accepted answer. Do accepted answers still go into the review queue?

Comment: Right, that wasn't clear from the context and that information is not present on the answer once deleted, nor was that clear from the custom flag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would agree that NAA would be the more appropriate flag, but IMO, this "offense" does not justify a declined flag. Maybe marking it helpful with a custom message to use NAA in the future would be the best option.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: perhaps, but I can see why it was declined by the moderator in question. The custom flag description did not state why a moderator intervention was required, the *should only be used to make moderators aware* decline reason is the closest we moderators have to a *your flag is unclear, we don't know what you want us to do here* declination.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I mean, the flag stated: *Very low quality answer with absolutely no explanation or code*. In the huge pile of flags we get to process every day, that's not the kind of flag that'll get a lot of thought from moderators, where we get comments misdirected to content flags all the time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I edited my answer to show that it was the accepted answer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen see my edit, it was an accepted answer. so it needed mod deletion

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not know the exact flag text of course, but if you decline a flag for being unclear, would it not be better to say so in the decline reason?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: just like closing questions or downvoting, there are just too many flags to deal with to give every single flag we decline individualised attention.

Comment: @YvetteColomb You can still use the NAA flag, it will end up in the right queue automatically. Probably some "Delete LQQ review on accepted answer" autoflag or sth. like that; but the flag's intention would be clear at least.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: right, but accepted status is **not visible in the flag UI**. We can retroactively guess as to why something was flagged, but I note that the OP of this question doesn't mention the fact that the post was accepted as a motivation to flag it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen yes true. It gives the mod more to go by with a custom flag on an accepeted answer, but it wasn't mentioned in the flag. but it is something I noticed.

Comment: While deleting the answer is the correct thing, I still think people should be encourage to raise correct flags or as in this case write a clear message why they are raising a custom flag "... accepted answer, I can't flag VLQ, halp please" (since I don't know that I can raise NAA).

Comment: *and if mods decline, decline with correct message*, "Wrong flag, sorry mate"

Comment: @YvetteColomb - it feels like you should edit answer with guidance which probably is "flag NAA as NAA even if it is accepted/upvoted. This will eventually go trough diamond queue and proper action will be taken. If you raise custom tag specify explicitly why you could not use NAA like 'need mod action to delete link-only post as this is accepted answer'". Otherwise the answer is essentially "ping Yvette" which likely not the guidance you want to give :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've edited it before coffee, feel free to assess it! Thanks :D

Comment: @YvetteColomb May I suggest to add the advice to use NAA for standard link-only (esp. if VLQ is not an option)? The system shows the flag to the right people automatically and the intention is clear. Less room for human error that way, and probably a slight reduction of mod workload by having to parse fewer custom flags. (You can also ping me here and I'll do it for you, but I don't want to put any words in your mouth.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen if it's an accepted answer a custom flag works well, to alert mods to the fact it won't be review deleted. NAA makes no difference, the mods need to look at it and delte it anyway

Comment: @YvetteColomb True, but it *can* lead to confusion and, as far as I understood from my discussion with Martijn, at least some mods don't appreciate the "wrong flag type". NAA is easier and safer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen not if the flagger puts that it's an accepted answer.

Answer (score -20):

This answer is so old that it pre-dates the fiddle-link-only answer restriction.

A moderator could delete the answer, leaving the question with nothing, and unlikely to receive a good answer again due to its age and extremely low traffic. Presumably the moderator decided that an answer linking to something that may or may not work (based on the author's own description of it as "buggy") was better than nothing at all. Plus, as I said, the answer is really old. It didn't seem like something that needed deleting unless the link was dead (which you didn't say it was — you merely pointed out, correctly, that it was a link-only answer that says nothing useful on its own).

If the answer bothers you so much, you can ask the author to add their code in, add a flag stating that you've done so, and if no action has been taken on the answer for some time there's a much higher chance the answer is going to get deleted since the link will be *as good as* dead (even if it isn't).

Comment: *"This answer is so old that it pre-dates the fiddle-link-only answer restriction."* I don't think that's a good reason to leave link-only answers around. Posts and flags should be judged by today's standards.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: The reasoning in my answer starts in the second paragraph, not the first. And the last paragraph didn't say "leave it as it is". It said "fix the problem if it bothers you so much."

Comment: Now we'll have a meta post "what to do when two mods give different answers" :D

Comment: My point applies to your second paragraph as well. We don't leave new link only answers alone because they are "better than nothing", and I don't think we should treat old answers differently.

Comment: FWIW [canonical reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165773) on link-only answers was posted 2 years before that answer

Comment: _"If the answer bothers you so much, you can edit the code in yourself"_ Obviously, however without any explanation from the person who wrote it, there's little value in that. Plus the author himself wrote that it's buggy, so there's even less value.

Comment: @j08691: You can edit the answer so that it no longer breaks the rules. Then downvote it for not being useful because it doesn't contain an explanation. These two issues are separate.

Comment: @Yvette Colomb: I'm sure there are a handful of answers that speak of the legend of mods disagreeing with one another...

Comment: @BoltClock are they found carved into the walls of high roofed caves?

Comment: This is funny, specially since on the Low quality review queue, the only reason [for than 6 months old answers is precisely to remove those kind of answers.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319367/792066)

Comment: Editing the code in violates the OPs original license with JSFiddle by means of applying an incompatible license. Please don't suggest that users do this.

Comment: @TinyGiant yes I was also wondering about that. re editing the code from JSFiddle.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: That's interesting, has this always been the case? Thanks for letting me know either way.

Comment: @BoltClockB yes, [here is one meta topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698/4639281) which talks more broadly about editing code in from third party sources. There are others around, and one that is specific to JSFiddle is linked to in the question.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Thanks, that does complicate things a whole lot. At the same time, it ironically makes the decision of deleting the answer much simpler...

Comment: I'm a little disappointed this has gotten so many downvotes: Removing the only accepted solution, to leave an answer answerless, seems so much worse than leaving a link-only (working) answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant So we can't edit in code, and jsfiddle link-only answers are no longer allowed on the site. Is the only accepted solution here to delete the only answer to a question? This seems downright wrong.

Comment: @FrankerZ [this post at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116360) argues for opposite: "If a link-only answer is accepted, it is especially important to delete it (converting to a comment if the link isn't broken yet), and it has to be done by a moderator because the community cannot delete accepted answers. When a question has an accepted answer, it looks like it has a definitive answer, and there is not much point in looking for a better one. People who are looking to improve the site by providing better answers tend to consider questions with accepted answers as very low-priority..."

Comment: @gnat If that's the case, then why is the accepted/upvoted solution to delete the answer, instead of converting it to a comment?