# Is Unikong about Jon Skeet?

Tags: discussion, unikong, specific-user

1. That looks kinda like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (who already has a unicorn)
2. He collects badges just as fast as Jon Skeet
3. He picks up a rainbow gun and shoots trolls who stands in the way of his badge collecting

Jon Skeet shooting?

Comment: Stupid question: What does the "rainbow gun" thing have to do with Jon Skeet?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I guess it was too vague for most people. I just noticed the Unikong banner has been altered, which provides a concrete answer now

[image: New Unikong banner]

The thread about what Unikong is has a pic of the original

[What's with the Stack Overflow UNIKONG game?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320189/whats-with-the-stack-overflow-unikong-game)

Comment: I wonder what genre of music are J. Skeet and The Trolls making.

Comment: I don't know, but I bet it's in the key of C# ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet))

Answer (score 49):

[image: Yes, actually.]

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: If you look at the image too long, the red writing appears to float above it.

Comment: "DDOS prevention" is the best thing to be credited for.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Only if successful.

Comment: Is the "DDOS Prevention" prevention of DDOS'ing yourselves again?

Comment: I think "DDoS Prevention" means having no actual track record of high scores and just showing made up values

Answer (score 15):

I don't think the character is Jon Skeet.

- Humans can't control Jon Skeet. Jon Skeet controls Jon Skeet.
- The character dies when it makes a mistake. Jon Skeet doesn't make mistakes.
- Jon Skeet doesn't try to get to unicorns. Unicorns try to get to Jon Skeet.
- Jon Skeet killed the Dead Sea. Do you really think a bullet fired by a unicorn can kill him?

Comment: Is Jon Skeet the Chuck Norris' successor?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer No way!!! Chuck Norris is Jon Skeet's successor.

Comment: Oh, you're right!! How could I thought the opposite? :_

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Precisely. I hope we haven't angered Jon Skeet. That would be a major cause for concern.

Comment: BTW your statement has some problem... Do I need to trust Jon Skeet can alter the time and he was adult when Chuck Norris was a kid?

Comment: Or is he a new life form that has a constant age?

Comment: People have been suspecting so for quite long. But Jon Skeet hasn't commented thus far. Some say that Jon Skeet doesn't age, and it is he who first discovered fire while he was talking in his sleep. He has been this way ever since man has existed.

Comment: So probably Darwin was wrong. There's no evolution. It's just Jon Skeet was dreaming a wonderful world and, well, now we're all here. God exists.

Comment: Absolutely. Just Jon Skeet's dreams; they both make and drive the world. Quite amazing.

Comment: This argument has a big issue: who's Jon Skeet and who's his mom? How old is he? Jon Skeet couldn't create Jon Skeet himself. Or, maybe, there're parallel worlds and other Jon Skeet copied himself many times. BTW, WHO is Jon Skeet?

Comment: We should invite Stephen Hawking to the chat...

Comment: These are questions that us commoners shouldn't ask. Its forbidden. Jon Skeet has mastered parallelizing threads(*true*) and we already know about his mastery of time. So, anything is possible. Anything....

Comment: hahahahahahahaha

Comment: Or Jon Skeet. Cause Jon Skeet taught Stephen Hawking everything he knows.

Comment: loooooooooooool

Answer (score 10):

1. Said game character is shooting, running, and jumping at the same time.
2. Only Jon Skeet could be that awesome.
3. Therefore, the game character must be Jon Skeet.

Comment: 1. The character may die. 2. Jon Skeet cannot die. 3. Therefore the game character cannot be Jon Skeet.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - spoken like a true logician.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski 1. The character may be hit by the falling fireball. 2. The character dies. 3. The character again comes to life. 4. Therefore, The character is Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi 1. The fireball is a downvote. 2. Jon Skeet never gets downvotes. 3. Therefore, the character cannot be Jon Skeet.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9462979/4121347          Sorry Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi nah, that's just a bug in the SO software. ;-)

Comment: @Hackerdarshi, If you look at the vote count, he still has the most up votes. +6/-8 :P

Comment: @Hackerdarshi https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265771/4284627