# What's with the Stack Overflow UNIKONG game?

Tags: discussion, questions, april-fools, unikong

What's the deal with this new UNIKONG game on Stack Overflow?

Is it some sort of ad? Is it just for fun?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: April Fool's thing.  SO does something quirky every year.  Last year it was [meta-tag:stackegg]

Comment: @ryanyuyu - Yeah, I keep forgetting that Stack Overflow is in a different time zone.

Comment: It's actually an ad for Careers. You'll need to use Careers if your current boss catches you playing it

Comment: @BSMP technically, SO runs on UTC; however, we try to do "is it that day anywhere?". As a bonus: that means you get nearly 2 days, yay!

Comment: *It's an advertisement for selling unicorns.*

Comment: For awhile I wasn't sure _which_ end of the unicorn the flaming piles were coming out of...

Comment: WOMP. WOMP. And it isn't even April 1 yet.

Comment: @MrLister - it is. Somewhere on this planet.

Comment: OK, just one serious question. Can you make the game start with the sound off, please?

Comment: Spencerlarry, it seems you have just enough rep (>500) to see the game.

Comment: Oh goodness, it is April Fools Day again.  Completely forgot

Comment: @MrLister Turn it off once and the setting will persist (per browser, assuming local storage is supported).

Comment: The important question is: can I get a badge for getting a certain score in the game?

Comment: it's really a tool for us to track which employees don't work.

Comment: Last time [StackEgg](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289032/whats-stackegg) and this time **UNIKONG**

Comment: Hope next time you make more interesting and challenging game. this one was disappointing

Comment: It's very sad I missed it - I would have to disable my ad blocker for it and the meta questions didn't get featured until today...

Answer (score 152, accepted):

We bought a game studio to diversify our income stream. Keep playing. For the love of all that is good, KEEP PLAYING!

Comment: Pfff, if you guys were serious about income, you'd let me buy rep. IE, The Candy Crush revenue model.

Comment: Awesome game Jon! Thanks for that, it reminds me of my childhood days ... The [bug reports](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320196/4099593) have started though, So you will have 2 days of additional work :P

Comment: Careful @meagar, soon we'll have to buy rep in order to comment more than once an hour. Rep that we'd have to spend... to get more comment tokens.

Comment: @CubeJockey Yeah, but you can get bonus comment tokens by sending invites to your Facebook friends

Comment: @Thriggle I think that's the true plan of growth for the Developer Story project.

Comment: What's with all the high scores? My initial play and then 1 logged per death? http://i.imgur.com/hKUrHXp.png

Comment: Hi, love the game, but I can't find the DLC store. Please help.

Comment: @acbabis [Blocked by our legal department.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320216/1438)

Comment: Two words: Rep Mining

Comment: Unicorns are a start, but these days all good indie game business models are founded on goats.

Comment: @JonEricson is this highscores are real?

Comment: If Only Rep can be mined like that of a bitcoin miner

Answer (score 30):

It's an [April Fool's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) joke. Stack Overflow has one every year. My personal favorite were the [unicoins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227363/223467).

Note that this is shown to everyone, even those in time zones where it is still March 31st.

Comment: No, it's serious business. Very serious.

Comment: @Haney I take April Fool's Day **very** seriously. Perhaps the word "joke" was misused, as English isn't my native language. I believe it's just lost in translation - can you suggest a better phrasing for "critical business endeavor"?

Comment: It's mildly annoying, and not funny at all, when SO tries to be funny.

Feel free to vote this up if you agree.

Comment: @JoeBlow, unwind a little. Try to have fun/

Comment: Well, I liked it. I've always wanted to pretend I was Jon Skeet battling with a mean-tempered unicorn. Achievement unlocked.

Comment: @JoeBlow Actually, I found this year's April Fool rather tame, and that's entirely because they've made it deliberately *extremely innocuous*. It's basically a small advert in the side panel which will disappear after 24 hours or so, *and you're still complaining that they're having too much fun*. :(

Comment: @JoeBlow Or perhaps it's because you just "Blow," Joe.

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood which one, his life or his "job"?