# Why do you collect blue diamonds in Unikong?

Tags: discussion, unikong

Moderator diamonds make *no* sense as something to collect. You can't ever have more than one (on Stack Overflow), and they're basically volunteering to be tortured anyway, right?

Clearly we should be collecting green checkmarks.

Comment: When you collect them they go in your pokedex.

Comment: I'm also disappointed flags didn't make it in anywhere, that I can see anyway.

Comment: Something had to be blue.

Comment: @bluefeet Well, yes, but the trolls could be blue and the checkmarks green, right?  Or at least they could've had blue extremities...

Comment: You can _never have [too many diamonds](http://stackexchange.com/users/1083/jon-ericson?tab=accounts)_.

Comment: @Jon Are you the guy with the most diamonds?

Comment: @BhargavRao - he's an employee, so it doesn't count ;)

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: Nope. I'm missing one from my collection.

Comment: @ChrisF Yep, true, but creating accounts does take time too! @​Jon, Wrote a script Shog has 154 and you've got 155, who's the highest guy? :P

Comment: They aren't just something to collect. They are the only things you need to collect to finish a level.

Comment: Because, like all the Lucky Charms, blue diamonds are magically delicious.

Comment: About those blue diamonds, I had not linked them to "Moderator diamond", I though it was linked to bounties, though they only have their color.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sorry you're not super pleased with our choice to use diamonds as a collectible in the game. If you'd like, we're offering a full refund of the entire purchase price paid.

(In all seriousness, don't sweat it! Just play it and have FUN!)

Comment: I thought writing nitpicky questions about trivial issues on meta *was* how SO denizens had fun?

Comment: It is... when there isn't an evil unicorn to thwart!

Comment: Shame on you for making unicorns evil! Shame! Next you will tell me that they are just confused Rhinos

Comment: They're not confused. They know *exactly* what they're doing.

Answer (score 26):

The DLC will include [purple horseshoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPnBSBslv2o). We are waiting on a licensing agreement for the rest of the set.

Comment: I'll probably have to buy it for 2k rep ;).