# How best to deal with large number of duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion

Even after several minutes of searching, I was unable to find this issue on Meta, which surprises me. It seems like this is something that would have come up before.

The basic problem: a question, often one which is either broad, especially because it has a lot of possible answers, has been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow. I.e. there really should just be one question, with all others pointing to that one as duplicates.

Compare to questions we have with canonical answers, e.g. "What is NullReferenceException…".

In the particular case that prompts this question, one big problem is that the question asks about a specific error message, but there are many possible reasons for this error message to occur, and thus not only does the question appear many times, each instance of the question garners a large number of answers, all of which are legitimate possibilities (but only one of which will be the correct answer in a given scenario).

Here are just a portion of all of the relevant Q&A's for the question in the example at hand (in date-asked order):

[Name Does Not Exist in Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14281509) (asked Jan 2013, no answers)
[The name “XYZ” does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:ABC”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16216662) (asked Apr 2013, protected July 2014, 8 answers)
[The name ViewModel does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17025601) (asked Jun 2013, 10 answers)
[The name “YesNo” does not exist in the namespace “clr-Namespace:WPF_Tutorial.WPFTutorials.Converter”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20824032) (asked Dec 2013, 1 answer)
[The name does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22128311) (asked Mar 2014, 2 answers)
[WPF: The name does not exist in the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28216096) (asked Jan 2015, 1 answer)

Ideally, someone looking for help with this error message would quickly find the *one* question with, at a minimum, all the possible answers. Even better would be a thoughtfully written discussion of what can cause this error to occur and the ways to fix the various causes for it.

Is there any well-defined process for addressing this kind of problem? Is it even acceptable for someone (i.e. a motivated volunteer…naturally, it's my assumption that any solution will involve one or more such people :) ) to single-handedly start closing as duplicate some of the questions (if they have moderator or gold badge status for the topic)? Is there a good way to migrate answers from various instances of the question to the target "canonical" version?

Comment: Coming to meta is always good as a start :-) Yes, being motivated enough to [go on a close rampage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255738/duplicate-closing-rampage) seems to be accepted. If you're unsure, just ask here or in the chat.

Comment: These questions fit a special category.  They are the same question but they'll always be phrased differently, the OP invariably wants a "press this button to solve your problem" answer and they'll never stop coming.  You got all the power to hammer and to write a canonical Q+A, however neither stops them from coming or actually helps the OP.  It is the [regex] of the [wpf] tag.  I'd say the best thing to do is to categorize them, remove all tags and leave [xamlparseexception].  Which is a crappy tag btw, consider creating [xaml-error].

Comment: "*Even after several minutes of searching ...*" OMG! ;-)

Comment: @alk: in my experience, if an answer is readily available, it takes me less than five minutes of searching to find it. Some answers are a bit harder to find, but I've found that for me the likelihood of one existing after I've been searching 10 minutes is very low, and after 15 minutes, it's nearly guaranteed not to exist, at least not in a form that is retrievable in any reasonable amount of time. I generally don't pursue a search longer than that. (Contrast "several minutes" with "several hours", the next time-unit up).

Comment: The problem is the point system. How can anyone unlock features of the site if they aren't allowed to answer questions for points? If all of their answers are rejected due to being a duplicate somewhere, then how shall they get points? Currently, they may know it is a duplicate and actually copy and paste the duplicate answer as their own, to get the points. Perhaps there should be +5 points awarded for pointing to the duplicates as an answer, but that type of answer cannot be upvoted for more points. As it is, only the old school members who wrote the original answers are allowed points.

Comment: @GaryHayes: _"The problem is the point system"_ -- I guess that depends on what you mean by "problem". It's true that the reputation system can create counter-productive incentives in the less-diligent. But there's no reason to accommodate those who would abuse the system. _"only the old school members who wrote the original answers are allowed points"_ -- sure, for questions that have been already answered. But there are still plenty of questions left to answer; I only started answering six months ago and have almost 20k now. Clearly we haven't run out of new questions. :)

Comment: @GaryHayes: btw, I'm impressed by your suggestion to award rep for someone who does the work to search for and find a good duplicate. I think with some fleshing out (close-dupes are vote-based, and gold badge users can close with just one vote, so implementation of the idea is tricky), that's actually a feature that could improve the site. Maybe you should propose it on Meta in the feature-request tag, after considering and addressing the potential unintended incentives/consequences of such a feature?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. But as a member with less than 1,000 points, I am unable to use many of the sites features, and therefore don't know which features are available or how they work, as I've no experience with them. It wouldn't be prudent for me to formally suggest a new feature, as I wouldn't know what other features my new feature would be in conflict with, so I wouldn't know how to address these conflicts. I could only suggest the feature, but not help implement it.

Comment: Further... I answer lots of questions in the comment section, as the question is easily answered. No points are awarded for these type answers. Perhaps one rep point should be given for each up vote in the comments as well.

Comment: I posed the question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298572/how-to-avoid-duplicate-answers-with-points-reward

Comment: @GaryHayes: _"I answer lots of questions in the comment section"_ -- don't do that. First and foremost, comments are second-class citizens on SO; they can't be edited, there's no history, and they can be deleted at any time for any reason. Beyond that, the main point here is actually to provide answers to the _community_; answers in the comments are extremely hard to find, and just as hard to curate. In any case, there's no point in complaining that the rep system is broken when its you who are limiting or eliminating opportunities to be awarded rep.