# How to avoid duplicate answers (with points reward)

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

It was suggested that I pose this question for a new feature request.

There is an ongoing problem of people posting duplicate answers to questions that have already been answered. One major contributing factor for these undesirable answers, in my opinion, is that the person answering the question is trying to gain upvotes for points, so they could unlock other features of the site.

They may already know it is a duplicate answer, and may even be copying and pasting the answer from another users answer to get the easy points.

My proposal is simple (though I've been told the implementation could cause conflicts with other systems):

- **Award 5 rep points for doing the leg work and finding the best answer and linking to the original answer instead of creating a duplicate answer.** These answers cannot be upvoted for more points.

This will encourage users to find the duplicates for an easy 5 points, but will keep the system clean from duplicate answers, when all relevant questions are pointing to the same answers.

Some issues I can see are:

Automatic point assignment would cause many users to point to the same answer for 5 points a piece. This would have to be addressed by only awarding the first person to link to the answer with the points. (The link would have to be audited to ensure they are linking to a relevant answer.)

As such, there could only be 5 points awarded once. This is to eliminate the possibility of a moderator removing the link from the question during an audit (thereby removing the 5 point credit from the original linker, and posting the same link for their own points).

Of course there are other systems that may need to be adjusted to implement this feature, but I think it is a worthwhile endeavor.

Comment: Could I not post an obscure dup and then 'find it' from one of my sockpuppets?

Comment: Perhaps, if you're really into self abuse. :D

Comment: I'll take my unicorn dollars now...

Comment: @MartinJames no matter what you implement, there is potential for abuse.  I wish people would stop worrying about someone gaming for rep as the end of the world and focus on the quality of the site.  Getting a duplicate question closed is the higher priority IMO.

Comment: and: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5

Comment: and: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214685/accept-score-for-the-duplicate-finder

Comment: Yeah...unicorn dollars! :) Yes, points are worthless once you have enough to unlock all of the sites features. People writing dupes are trying to unlock the site! OR, as is the case with this post... people have similar solutions to problems. With a World of 7 billion + people, this is bound to happen.

Comment: *The link would have to be audited* - I think the OP should just accept the duplicate. But that's a potential problem. Many people are put off a little (to say it mildly) if their questions are unmasked as not being this unique-asked-only-by-razor-sharp-me question and not many will easily accept it. I can see one benefit of this approach though. Often, when I mark as duplicate, I wish I could link to the best-fitting answer in stead of just the question. OPs tend to read the accepted answer first and then bounce back, *that's* not what I asked!

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm doing the best I can.  I'm close-voting like crazy:)

Comment: I think that similarly one should be able to add to utter people's questions so they can get answers that help them to maybe they should incorporate that too

Comment: @JediPythonClone add what to other people's questions?