# How to deal with recurring questions? Tag Hints

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

The topic is quite general and I could find some similar questions, but those do not contain a suggestion for a new solution.

[How best to deal with large number of duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298474/how-best-to-deal-with-large-number-of-duplicate-questions)

[Duplicate Closing Rampage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255738/duplicate-closing-rampage)

---

### Problem

There are questions that return (almost) daily:

1. and are duplicates,
2. or are not duplicates but can be solved in the same way, following the same steps.

#### Example #1

For example in the Go language, unmarshalling JSON text into a struct requires the struct fields to be exported (`public` in other languages) so the parser is able to change / set the values of those fields. If fields are not exported, usually there is nothing to indicate what went wrong.

This question is asked in one or another way like three times every week. Sure, we can mark them as duplicates and/or we can answer them, but I think we could do better.

#### Example #2

Again, taking the example of Go, in Go error handling is done by returning errors which many people new to Go forget (or just too lazy) to check, and when something doesn't work, they post questions when all that would be needed is to check / print the returned error value (and using that knowledge the solution is trivial most of the times).

### Proposed solution: Tag Hints

I think it would be super helpful if something similar to tag excerpt would exist, but with the purpose of "Be sure to check these before asking.". It could be called **"Hints"**. It would be displayed by default when questions of that tag are listed, and if someone is already familiar with them, it could be hidden / closed. It should be short and contain solutions for questions asked daily.

For example it could look something like this for Go:

```
1. Always check / print returned errors.
2. Unmarshalling into structs requires fields to be exported.
```

Alternatively we could use the tag excerpt for this which is already implemented and visible for the tags, but its purpose is different and it would be good to be able to hide these "hints".

Another alternative would be to present this when a "new" user (below a certain reputation? having less than X questions?) wants to post a question, and optionally having to acknowledge that he knows and tried these hints.

Comment: This is kind of how the tag wikis were intended to be used. But they seem to be invisible to 90% of users, so maybe we could display "tag hints" more prominently (even if they're pulled from the wiki).

Comment: Putting them in the wiki still helps close voters find the canonical questions, though, so that's still worth doing.  (Some communities have off-site lists, such as http://sopython.com/canon/ .)

Answer (score 1):

"Hints" like these are more often than not ignored by users that just want an answer to their question.

If a user didn't manage to find the (obvious) duplicate, I think it's very unlikely a small hint like that will dissuade them from posting a question.

That aside, if you want to add hints for all common issues for a specific tag, those lists can grow to be extremely long. This is just what the tag wiki is meant to be used for, but users with questions like that usually don't bother reading the wiki. (Or any documentation at all, for that matter)

Comment: And how about presenting this when a new user posts a question? Optionally having to acknowledge it? See last paragraph of edited question.

Comment: How many _"I agree"_ buttons have you clicked without reading a single word above it?

Comment: Point made... but maybe _some_ users would read it... I guess asking an answerable question instead of having to click "Acknowledge" would complicate things too much...