# What about all these long-forgotten duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[image: Google search]
*See below for links*

Pretty self-explanatory. All of these are about the same topic and the question body is extremely short and all can be summarized in this one sentence:

> What is the use of abstract classes in C# (and what's the difference to other ones)?

What should be done about these questions? Essentially, they're highly-upvoted duplicates.

My suggestion is mark the oldest one as original, and all others to duplicates. I don't see any reason for 10 questions about the same topic with the same answer.

*Note this is only an example, it may even happen to other things, not only abstract classes.*

Relevant duplicates: **[second](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj_49rCyrLRAhWGlSwKHdhfDHMQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2570814%2Fwhen-to-use-abstract-classes&usg=AFQjCNGS_9mFvj7ySxSCBqb0AL4YyEInTQ&sig2=TPZzaT_6HZAQ9EOZR9eEdg&cad=rja)**, **[third](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwj_49rCyrLRAhWGlSwKHdhfDHMQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F391483%2Fwhat-is-the-difference-between-an-abstract-function-and-a-virtual-function&usg=AFQjCNH9zdWT7hWlqmeKiFvqFED2NsW7Ew&sig2=qpLdjOpfkNLIT11vjbLV5Q&cad=rja)**

*Irrelevant*: [already marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912475/what-is-an-abstract-class), [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865387/how-to-use-abstract-class-in-c-sharp), [first](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj_49rCyrLRAhWGlSwKHdhfDHMQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F239127%2Fexact-use-of-abstract-class&usg=AFQjCNHXsZxRehSdqxkAsqT5xJSAYYB3Rw&sig2=-BcuEiI2JSZrAJYE8oe4dg&cad=rja)

Comment: I tried clicking on those links to dupehammer them, but all I got was a stupid image. My dupehammer doesn't work on images.

Comment: Why the oldest one? Why not the one with the (objectively ^^) best answer?

Comment: @CodyGray I added four example links. Note there are also a few duplicates of "What is the difference between abstract classes and Interfaces?", I might search them out too.

Comment: @CodyGray Note also I stated it's not only C# and not only this topic. Two duplicates of "Interfaces vs abstract classes" that are tagged [tag:oop]: ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo?rq=1)). I guess they are ignored for the fact that they are marked protected and have high votes.

Comment: No, they are "ignored" because we don't have enough users with the requisite privileges to handle all of this. Stack Overflow gets a *lot* of questions. And yes, I realize you are asking about the general problem, but I don't know what to tell you about that. All I can say is that we have to deal with them when we see them or they are brought to our attention. There is no better solution that I can see. Do you have an idea about what we can do?

Comment: Not exactly, but I can just say that low-rep users that can only flag or close these. [Is that really manageable?](https://i.gyazo.com/cb530353082fc47aae83161b3e654636.png)

Comment: Also, I don't think old questions draw enough attention. They are used mostly for archive purposes, quick knowledge, and to actually have something that can be the proof that something's a duplicate. I don't think enough users are actually going to take care of "forgotten duplicates". @CodyGray

Comment: My New Year's Resolution was to help the hungry by volunteering at a homeless shelter, but now I've decided to devote the year to cleaning up old dups instead.

Comment: For every one user that asks a question, it takes five users to close it and (usually) eight users to delete it.  That is a scaling problem that was waiting to happen.  And it did happen, a fat three years ago.  Today the problem has grown by a factor of ~2, doubling the number of contributors is an impossible goal.    So the only real way this can be solved is when it is the questioners that keep the place tidy.  Yes, they are doing a pretty crappy job of it.  They are not expected to care about the site, so they don't.

Comment: 90% of new users don't read the tour, help center, and suggested duplicates. This should somehow be enforced. Maybe then the questioners will keep an eye out. @HansPassant

Comment: @devRicher Figuring out *how* to enforce this effectively is the 6-8 week question. Some attempts have been made, but it's difficult to force user behavior.

Comment: Are duplicates really a problem?  Things change - languages, techniques, features...  an old question may have a better answer today, and who is going to go back and add new answers to old questions?  Abstract classes may not be the best example of this, but in other cases, a newer version of the same question may get a more up-to-date answer.

Comment: @TylerH - objective enforcement isn't very difficult I dont believe. Make the tour page a required viewing. If the user scrolls and clicks through they can still be a member but when a question is seen as a duplicate and flagged as such by four or more users with flag powers, "community" closes it and in X days the question isnt edited to dedupe, delete. In cases with an updated answer to an old question,  answers pertain to updated software and should be tagged with the appropriate software. So, drop dupe and retag if needed. Otherwise, notify user of deletion and remind of tour page.

Comment: @ShawnGordon What's the point of forcing the user to visit the tour page if they are just going to hit End and click out of it? Also, that's not how duplicates work; they should stick around to act as sign posts, not be deleted. Either way, that still doesn't 'force' users to ask good questions or search before asking a question that's already got an answer. To put it another way, the only way we can handle dupes currently is with lagging responses. To do what devRicher is suggesting is to come up with a *preventative* response that kicks in *before* the question is asked.

Comment: Unless you hand-held, you're not forcing anyone to do anything however if you don't make mandatory certain things in a hardset fashion, you're going to have a slick area.  How many sign posts are "enough" sign posts? My comment was merely to say that a nearly objective means is not impossible, just seemingly undesirable. That's one of (IMO) the biggest issues with a Q&A type forum: the lazy typically flood entry point but unless there's a precedent enforced, there can't be one expected, which comes by way of indoctrination at entry so when enforcement happens there no valid excuses.

Comment: Next time... provide the links of all the questions.

Comment: @Braiam I actually linked all relevant questions, and this has already been stated by Cody Gray.

Answer (score 11):

When facing a situation like this you have to see if there exists a canonical duplicate - a question and answer that were very good and have therefore been up-voted a lot by the community. Please note that this is not necessarily the oldest one.

If such a duplicate exists, the questions should be closed as duplicates. You can flag/close vote the questions as duplicates.

If you don't have enough rep to moderate this yourself, the ideal solution might be to draw the attention of a person with a gold badge in the topic (C# in this case), as they can instantly close everything as duplicates ("dupe hammer"). You could ask around in the C# chat or in the close-vote review chat to see if you can find someone who is willing and able to help out.

Comment: I agree, but there should be brought more attention to this. I, or any person in general, wouldn't want do do it "all by themselves".

Comment: @devRicher That's why seeking help in those chat rooms could be a good idea. Suppose you find five or so people with gold badges, you can then close down all duplicates rather quick, especially if there's a prepared list of results. But of course every post has to be examined manually still, there's no way around that.

Comment: @devRicher If you feel confident that you selected an appropriate canonical and have a gold badge, [there's nothing wrong with that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255738/1048572). Of course, getting feedback on meta or chat is fine.

Comment: @Bergi "and have a gold badge". That's the problem I'm trying to state. All I can do is flag (and soon close vote), but tons of close-voted questions that remain ignored are the result.