# How long does a question stay on hold?

Tags: support

I went to this question which was really poor made, but as I saw that it were made by a new user I tried to understand what he meant through comments and then I edited it to help him and the site:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662159/how-to-create-a-conceptual-model-for-a-currency-converter-assignment?noredirect=1#comment36349913_23662159

But the question was put on Hold and still with this status even after my edit was approved,
How long does a question remain with such status?

I mean on the FAQ it says:

**When you edit your question, it may be re-opened if enough users believe you have corrected the problems and it is now answerable.**

Are the same users who flagged that have to change it to answerable? Or how does it actually works?

Comment: "How long does a question stay on hold?" Forever, or until re-opened by 5 people or a mod.

Comment: It is supposed to become `[closed]` [after five days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/164403) if left `[on hold]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How long does a question stay on hold?

Forever. It can be re-opened by five 3K users, or a moderator.

> Are the same users who flagged that have to change it to answerable? Or how does it actually works?

When a post is edited (by the OP, I'm not sure on this fact), it is placed in the "Reopen" queue for 3K users to vote on.

Also `[on hold]` becomes `[closed]` after 5 days.

Comment: Note that a user with a gold badge can reopen questions by themselves if the question was originally tagged with that badge. See [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/456814).

Comment: *If you really want a post to be re-opened, flag it.* Whoa there! Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Cupcake, our reopening superpowers only work on duplicates, though, and the question at hand was not closed as one.

Comment: Users should not be flagging posts to have them reopened.  They should be editing the posts so that they are worth reopening.  The reopen queue takes care of the rest.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I thought there was a "flag to reopen" just as there is a "flag to close". Thanks to Servy for removing that line.