# What is the best way to get feedback on a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently asked a question and it was marked as off topic.  There were other questions that were along the sames lines as my question, but not exactly the same, that were not marked as off topic.

When I asked why it was marked as such, I received no response.  So, how can I get the feedback?

Here is the question: [Installing nokogiri on Ubuntu/Debian Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661011/installing-nokogiri-on-unbuntu-debian-linux)

Comment: This comment sounds like an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661011/installing-nokogiri-on-unbuntu-debian-linx#comment36344148_23661011

Comment: The existence of other offtopic questions that aren't closed doesn't mean that your offtopic question should be open, it just means that some other offtopic questions weren't closed.

Comment: I reopened the question.

Comment: Actually I'm a bit confused now. I found this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130246/is-how-do-i-get-this-installed-a-programming-question So it seems this question is ontopic! I admit I made the mistake of close-voting some similar questions... Sorry about that.

Comment: @kapa: I reopened the question.  Do I need to be a bit clearer about that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The source of the confusion is myself. The facts already convinced me, but thanks ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual way to get feedback on a question is to post here on Meta, just as you have done.

Naturally, your first line of defense is to ask for clarification in the comments below your question.  This is your second line of defense.

The other thing you can do is flag for moderator attention, explain in the custom moderator flag that you believe the closure to be without merit and why, and ask for a reopen.

Comment: "The other thing you can do is flag for moderator attention". Is this something you want people doing? I [suggested this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254899/how-long-does-a-question-stay-on-hold/254900#comment21385_254900) and I was told that was incorrect.

Comment: Moderator flags are intended for situations that either cannot be handled by the community, or are being handled improperly by the community.  In this particular case, think of a moderator flag as a request for a review by a judge, if you will.  Moderator flags have always been suitable for this purpose.  That said, don't expect a good reception if you merely flag and say "please reopen."  There needs to be an *actionable justification* in your flag description, and if the community is saying that your question needs improvement, and you don't improve it, don't expect a moderator to reopen it.

Comment: Whoah, congrats on the 100k.  Must have happened today.

Comment: Posting on meta really helped to identify some issues with my questions. I was hesitant at first, but everyone was very helpful. If you're open to constructive criticism, you can improve the question and/or do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

You received no feedback because others thought, upon seeing the comments, sufficient reason had been given.

Comment: So, if that reason given was sufficient, I should conclude that questions should only be about programming only and not about how to get an environment for programming to work.  Is that the proper conclusion?

Comment: Maybe. And as @Servy said previously, "The existence of other offtopic questions that aren't closed doesn't mean that your offtopic question should be open, it just means that some other offtopic questions weren't closed."

Comment: @JayBlanchard Regardless of the fact that OP was right in this case, Servy's statement is absolutely true.