# Is there any facility to update older questions with new?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As we can see that the technology regularly updates itself...the changes in the coding patterns ... inbuilt functions changes day by day...versions to versions...

So is there any facility here to update those questions or remove those type of questions..

Comment: Take note that not everyone has the latest technology and still stuck on older version, especially in a company.

Comment: But the company must upgrade itself to be in the competition.. not in 1st,2nd but in 3rd year it has to...

Comment: Users searching for the new technology and will find different questions. Questions about outdated technology will be seen less and less often automatically, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist no inherent StackExchange functionality, since the topics that could become obsolete is just too broad.

The only way to adequately address this would be through question closure on an as-found basis. Note though that this would also be community-driven (unless you have [god-like powers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/914686)).

Then again, what might be obsolete for *you* could still be somewhat functional to someone else.

Comment: then i think there should be a functionality to just pass the moderators review flag for un-useful for future on as-found basis..

Comment: @X-Developer: Note that the site is still community-driven. So you can go ahead and mark content as obsolete through a vote-to-close. If others agree, that is a different question.