# Gold badge superpowers inappropriate for language tags?

Tags: discussion, privileges, dupehammer, tag-badges

I only recently found out I had [certain super-powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/149334) thanks to my [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) language tag gold badge. Apparently this is because the system thinks that I am an expert on questions with this tag, and therefore deserve additional trust.

To be honest, I find these super-powers somewhat problematic with programming language tags:

There are lots of questions tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23); but not because these are *about* the C# programming language (on which I *am* indeed quite knowledgeable), but because the question only *uses* that language as an "implementation detail", e.g. for code snippets. The question itself, however, might very well focus on anything else, let's say on a problem with some specific framework or library where I am *not* necessarily that knowledgeable.

What it boils down to is that certain tags — namely those for programming languages — serve a double duty:

1. A question might carry the language tag because it actually is about the language;
2. A question might carry the language tag merely to indicate what language is used for the OP's implementation; but beyond that, it's actually not relevant.

I don't think I should have the super-powers in the second case. What is the general opinion on this, has this been discussed before? Is this even problematic at all? Is there a way to automatically distinguish case #1 from #2?

**Update:**

> *"At most it means you'll be extra careful in applying duplicate votes. That doesn't seem to be a problem."* — @Bart

The almost-ubiquitous presence of the C# language tag means that I have to be so careful now with duplicate votes *in general* that it's become frightening to even use that mechanism at all:

I could previously cast a duplicate vote when I was fairly sure that a question was a duplicate, and I could suggest it to others, but I was glad to leave the final decision to the real experts on the topic. (Possible because more than just my vote was needed.) I can no longer do that.

I would now have to resign to writing comments, such as "Might be a duplicate of...", to achieve the same thing, which seems the wrong way to do it given that the system actually provides a specific feature for just that. So I probably won't write such comments.

What SO is therefore losing (thanks to the gold badge super-powers) is possibly helpful hints at duplicate questions.

Comment: At most it means you'll be extra careful in applying duplicate votes. That doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: @Bart: Good point. I added a reply to your comment at the end of my answer.

Comment: How do you define a "language" tag? Personally, I quite like it... being able to close immediately is really useful. If you're in a large tag like C# when there'll be loads of other people with gold badges who can immediately reopen it.

Comment: @Ben: A "language tag" is a tag for a programming language. My definition; there probably isn't an official category for this on SE, but that doesn't matter. You're probably asking, Why do I single these out? What makes them special? Because of the special double-duty they serve. As I'm explaining above, these aren't always problematic. They only lead to a problematic (IMHO) situation when one has gold bade super-powers & when they're added to questions that aren't *about* the language, but *use* the language.

Comment: No, I'm not asking why you single them out - I'm pointing out that such a categorisation doesn't exist - it's impossible to find an order in a system that doesn't have it and isn't checked by a human. I'm asking how you would define a language tag... how do you actually find these tags and keep the necessary metadata up-to-date and accurate?

Comment: *I could previously cast a duplicate vote when I was fairly sure that a question was a duplicate, and I could suggest it to others, but I was glad to leave the final decision to the real experts on the topic.* Then use a **comment** instead. You should really have only ever used a duplicate vote *when you sure before* as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If I am actually meant to suggest duplicates through comments, and not through a close vote, then I'm happy to do so. It just strikes me as add; after all, a "close vote" should be a *vote*, and I should be able to cast a vote, even if it ends up being a minority vote.

Comment: @stakx: sure, but you still want to be able to stand behind that minority vote too.

Comment: @Ben: SO does syntax highlighting; not for every existing programming language, but for the most popular ones. It would probably be enough to tag the most popular programming language tags as such, based on the list of languages that SO can syntax-highlight. Less-common languages probably won't have many users with gold badges anyway, so they're not likely to lead to problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And I could: For me, casting a vote does not mean that I have to be 1000 % sure that I'm right. If that were the case, I could never cast a vote. There's always the possibility that one is wrong; which is probably why the system requires several votes in the first place, and then decides on the majority of votes.

Comment: @stakx: you *also* have a *reopen* hammer. Be sure when you close it, be graceful in reopening. In a language tag, there is always someone else with the hammer to re-close as a different dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The re-open hammer is an entirely different issue. My point is, I don't want these hammers in so many situations where I have them now.

Comment: @stakx: but then you still were using your votes incorrectly.

Comment: Related: [Allow user to choose between an ordinary close vote and the mighty Mjölnir](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255064) and [How Do I Opt Out of Privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231504)

Comment: Also related: [Let moderators disable the dupehammer for certain tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231509)

Comment: That's definitely a way @stakx, it misses out a few major tags but it should get most of the top ones...

Comment: you might like to support http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer

Comment: @KateGregory: Thanks for the hint. Your suggestion has my support, FWIW.

Comment: This situation means we need to make it clearer when to use a tag; only the first situation in your post is appropriate, in my opinion. Only use tags that are necessary for the solving of the problem.

Answer (score 26):

> What SO is therefore losing (thanks to the gold badge super-powers) is possibly helpful hints at duplicate questions.

You should **never** use a close vote as a hint. Not for duplicate votes, not for other votes. That is what comments are for.

If now that you have a dupe hammer you are being more careful to be certain before voting to close, then *that is excellent*.

From here on out, when you *suspect* something is a dupe, just use a comment.

To quote [Shog9 on making the dupe hammer optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges):

> To be perfectly frank, I've never liked the attitude toward closing that [turning it into a voting system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/) brought with it: **too many people vote without much thought, expecting other voters to keep their carelessness in check**. If that *doesn't* apply to you (and I don't think it does) then you're exactly the sort of person we'd all appreciate having a bit more say in what gets closed.

As for 'language' tags somehow being special, I entirely disagree. If a language tag doesn't apply, remove the tag (although the hammer will still apply). But never blame the tag; it is still your responsibility to take care when voting to close.

Also see [Let moderators disable the dupehammer for certain tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231509/let-moderators-disable-the-dupehammer-for-certain-tags)

Comment: *Why* shouldn't I cast a vote? My general understanding of a "vote" is that it should not be a dictatorial decision; it should be one of possibly several opinions, and that there is some algorithm that computes the final decision, e.g. "when there are at least 4 votes, the majority opinion wins". In intention, casting a duplicate close vote and writing a comment "Duplicate of..." are the same thing.

Comment: @stakx: yes, but how does that preclude you from *standing behind your vote*. We are disagreeing on something right here, we are having a discussion. You appear to dissent with my opinion, but I certainly stand behind my opinion right now. It may be possible to sway me from that with good arguments, but until then, I stand behind it. I could cast a close vote with that conviction, you can cast a vote with yours, and let the majority win.

Comment: In my opinion, "I am allowed to cast votes" does not require that "I am 100 % sure that I am right". I can only cast a vote to the best of my knowledge, and there comes a point when I am *reasonably* sure that I'm right. That is when I cast a vote. But then sometimes people are even more sure than I that something else is right, and I'm happy to accept their better knowledge. That, however, should not mean that I must not be allowed to cast a vote in the first place.

Comment: @stakx: If you feel, to the best of your knowledge, your vote is correct *then stand behind it* and make that call. If then someone comes by and points out a better dupe, *they* (or you) can re-open and re-close. Your dupe hammer gives you one reopen and one close vote per post, order doesn't matter.

Comment: @stakx: What I am talking about is the 'other voters will validate the vote' mentality. They won't anymore, so do your homework and be sure.

Comment: According to your line of thinking, why doesn't *everyone* get to have a dupehammer then? What I intended with my question here was to show that in a system where I sometimes have it, and sometimes I don't have it, the system gives the dupehammer to me in situations where I don't deserve it. It gives the privilege to me based on the presence on a tag which is not really significant to the question. This has the same effect as me having the dupehammer for tags where I am no expert at all; and the system doesn't usually give me the dupehammer there. That to me is an obvious contradiction.

Comment: @stakx: because the *system* has assigned it to you based on trust, with the trust being measured by your gold badge. You answered 200 or more questions within that tag, gained at least 1000 upvotes for it. That is a lot of Unicorn Dollars.

Comment: @stakx: if you are not an expert in the language, then *just be more careful with the hammer*.

Comment: I'm afraid we are talking in circles. My point is that there are questions with a language tag where the language is an unimportant side detail. The dupehammer shouldn't apply there, because if it does, it basically ruins the whole close vote / majority decision system. I cannot understand why the duplicate close vote system should work one way for question A, and another way for question B, just because question B has a tag that is basically irrelevant to the actual question, but wrongly gives me dictator power.

Comment: @stakx: not for **most** people with the gold badge. Have you considered that you might be an exception? Like [Tim Pietzker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker); he's a gold badge holder in 3 languages because he is a regex expert. The same advice still applies: *Be certain*, and *be careful*, comment if you are not sure.

Comment: I *am* an expert in the language, but just because a question is tagged with that language doesn't mean that it is *about* that language itself. And *that* is precisely why the dupehammer is problematic with language tags.

Comment: This is the same argument as for the mandatory Meta tags and the dupe hammer. You *still have to be careful, **regardless of the tags***.

Comment: Of course I can simply be more careful. But may I suggest that there's a better way, namely improving the system that decides who gets the hammer, and when. And that is what I wanted to bring up for discussion. I've hinted at a place where the system could need some improving (IMHO). But: if the general opinion is simply "be more careful, we don't see a reason to fix the system", then I'll live with that and stop casting votes.

Comment: @stakx: Sure, and my opinion is still the same: it is not the tag that is the problem. It is the attitude that people hide behind others to provide protection from incorrect dupe votes.

Comment: Re. the latest edit. Removing a language tag means that SO no longer automatically syntax highlights code. While one can add a language hint to code sections, that's quite inconvenient compared to simply adding the tag. I believe that therefore, when given a choice, most people will go down the easy route and simply add the tag, and voilà, instant syntax highlighting (and a hint what language code in answers should be written in). But that doesn't make the programming language as relevant to the question as other, more specific tags.

Comment: @stakx: Sure, and on meta we have mandatory tags that *have* to be present. On Meta.SE I have a dupe hammer in `discussion` and `support`. It means I have to be careful with voting.

Comment: I'm sorry I brought this up for discussion. Obviously noone else sees the problem that I see, so I'll shut up and do as you suggest.

Comment: Even if "the real experts" do disagree there is nothing they can do to oppose the closure. They can't vote against your thoughtless vote to bring the total down to 0. They just have to keep an eye on it and reopen it. A waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @stakx: so, you have a discussion with one random person on the internet and you give up already? It is *Sunday morning* in Europe, not exactly rush hour on Meta. I feel one way, you feel another. It could well be that others don't agree with me either.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Who said I cast "thoughtless" votes?

Comment: Well you said you were happy to defer to the experts. But that isn't how the voting system works. It isn't a majority decision. It just goes one way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You're right. I am someone who easily becomes frustrated when a discussion is going in circles. I don't feel like I've been able to make you see my point, and I feel that I perhaps don't fully understand yours. But since you obviously participate more actively on Meta, I do admit that you are perhaps in the right and I'm not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My comment already says that. But it means they need to checkup on the question to see if it actually got closed.

Comment: No I fully support the dupe hammer. No idea why you think that.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Read again what I wrote above. Just because I am happy to defer to the experts for the final decision doesn't mean that I cast random, or "thoughtless", votes. All I said was that when I cast a vote, I am not necessarily *totally certain* it's the right one; I'm just *certain enough* to believe that a vote is appropriate.

Comment: @stakx Well if you aren't totally certain that the vote is correct you shouldn't be voting to close at all IMO. I don't see the issue with leaving a comment if you suspect it might be [as indeed I did here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223021/download-file-from-reporting-services-using-c-sharp#comment37406282_24223021).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think my lack of `@` prefixes may have made it a bit confusing who I was addressing. I find the autocomplete system highly annoying on an ipad (no tab key and trying to select the pop up often ends up clicking the hyperlink underneath and sending me off to the user profile) so I sometimes don't bother when it seems clear to me!

Comment: @MartinSmith ah, indeed, I had the context mixed up.