# Can I give up my golden hammer?

Tags: support, dupehammer

I recently got the gold badge for java. Now I can close questions with those tags with a single vote.

I actually don't like that. I want just to vote to close like everybody else. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It may take some getting used to, but I think you'll get used to it and grow to like it. Closing obvious dupes before 5 users answer it can be pretty rewarding. That said, an option to disable it isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Sometimes I like it, sometimes I don't. The times I don't, I generally leave a comment manually saying *Possible duplicate of XXXX* hoping that another close voter will pick it up. Worth noting that it's not just any vote to close, it's only duplicates afaik.

Comment: You'll grow to thoroughly dislike it.  Nothing quite like SO users having a single person to complain to.  You are now personally responsible for their crappy question and their unproductive day.  Even a perfectly good answer in the dup is your problem when they don't understand it.  They'll send you emails to remind you how much you suck, be sure to remove any trace of a valid email address from your profile, blog or web page.  They'll DV your posts.  What you are asking has been requested many times before and always turned down.  Nobody has thought to ask for anonymization, might work.

Comment: lol, I don't have any hammers and even I don't ask questions any more.  Questions are just retaliation-targets:(

Comment: @HansPassant yeah that sounds pretty terrible :/ An alternative if anonymization is rejected (which I can also understand) might be that other users are still allowed to add their close vote after the fact so its not only you :/

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255064/1288408

Comment: How about instead of an option to disable this, make `vote to close` and `close` separate for gold badges? There are grey areas sometimes where I'm 98% sure, e.g., that a question is off-topic. However, the voting process is useful to account for that 2% of uncertainty. Another thing is a lack of immediacy. Sometimes I retract a close vote when the author makes a clarifying edit to his question. The close vote has that grace period (albeit typically short) where others have to chip in before the Q is truly shut down. At other times, I'm 100% sure the question is OT, and I'd love a gold badge.

Comment: @HansPassant: When you put it that way... Damn that's depressing.

Comment: @Jens the hardest part on this site is ignoring notifications (I'm not good at it) I can imagine the more you do, the worse it would get with people protesting votes.. the one thing you can do is vote more on other tags until you feel more comfortable with your golden hammer

Comment: Unlike @HansPassant I don't really care who likes it or not. I trust my judgment but I'm willing to hear other opinions too. In case someone convinces me otherwise, I can always reopen with a single vote- so no harm done. In general, I think that fast moderation is a great feature for a huge site like SO, rather than waiting each time for 5 over 3K users to close an obvious dupe. Though I agree with you that an option to use a normal vote should be granted. Not sure regarding removing the Hammer entirely.

Comment: @DavidArenburg it would be good if silver tags counted as two votes.. to help that close review queue

Comment: @HansPassant forgot to mention that they'll mention you by name on their blog and social media. Don't Google yourself. You don't want to know.

Comment: That pretty much sets the rule for why you don't use your own name on public sites.

Comment: @HansPassant to be clear, this has all happened to you several times?