# Make the automatic deletion of "possible duplicate of" comments more precise

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, comments, deleted-comments

**Proposal:** Change the criteria for automatic deletion of comments generated by duplicate votes so that only comments that *begin exactly with* "Possible duplicate of [link to a question]" are deleted.

**Rationale:** As things stand, comments containing the word "duplicate" and a link to another question anywhere get deleted when their parent question is closed as a duplicate. It shouldn't be necessary to jump through hoops when writing comments that use the word "duplicate" to eliminate the risk of automatic deletion.

**Impact:** By adopting the proposed criteria, all automatically generated "possible duplicate of" comments that aren't edited will keep being deleted. I presume most such comments that are edited will have the same fate, though I can only speculate about that. Meanwhile, accidental deletion of useful comments that happen to contain the word "duplicate" will become far less likely, and both the necessity and the extent of the paraphrases needed to prevent such deletions will be much reduced.

**Previous discussions:** [*Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414/242059) (Meta.SE) and [*Do not automatically remove hand-written comments when closing as duplicate*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270643/2751851), which identify the same problem and suggest somewhat different solutions. In each case, there are a handful of duplicates, but most of the interesting discussion is concentrated in the two linked questions. As far as I'm aware of, the behaviour described in the Meta.SE answers of [Ben](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195654/242059) and [Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193692/242059) still is the current one.

Comment: My anecdotal experience with edited auto-comments is that the majority leave the prefix alone and add more stuff on the end. Some users who currently don't do this would probably adjust their habits, too.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yup -- one possible adjustment would be using a separate comment if one has anything else to say that is not immediately related to the close vote. (At least that's what I do now if I'm casting a dupe vote without a hammer.)

Comment: +1 but I'd go with an even more conservative approach: Only delete it if it is auto-generated, unedited, and links to the same dupe target.

Comment: The current situation (as described here) is news to me. My first comment on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277052/add-my-app-to-suggestions-of-share-in-apple-maps#comment71710675_42277052) explicitly stated *not  duplicate* and why, but since I used the "d" word with a link to an answered question.... wow.

Comment: Surprisingly low score so far :) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate?rq=1 have 71 and nothing come out as result...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for the link; I will add it to the "previous discussions" section. *In principle*, I'm fine with hand-written comments that happen to match the pattern being deleted, but the pattern should be far more conservative than it currently is.

Comment: Playing devils advocate here, what is the point of this? Comments are meant to be ephemeral anyway - nobody should care too much if they are deleted.

Comment: @DavidG [1/2] It's not necessarily about long-term value. Things such as advice on how the asker can clarify their question, pointers to relevant Q&As, and brief explanations of why something is (or is not) a duplicate have, at the very least, short-term value for recently asked questions, and should not disappear in a flash just because someone cast a binding dupe vote.

Comment: @DavidG [2/2] Furthermore, and a bit more opinionatedly, comments being ephemeral doesn't make it okay to remove long-term valuable content just because it happens to have been posted as a comment. For instance, I don't see why a comment saying "Not a duplicate, but relevant reading: [link to another Q&A]" should be deleted unless and until it gets incorporated into an answer.

Comment: What happens when I post a link to this question? The question title and thus URL contains "duplicate" …