# Closing question as duplicate caused too much of comment to be removed

Tags: bug

I responded to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969719/finding-the-closest-xy-and-generete-direction-to-it#comment74969953_43969719) with a comment.  It's a 2-part question.  The first part appeared to be a duplicate; the second part wasn't clear.  At first, I didn't think I should close it as a dupe because only the first part was a dupe of the question I had found.  So I posted a comment saying that the first part was a duplicate of another question, and that it wasn't clear to me what the second part meant but if it meant what I thought it might mean, I gave him a couple of pointers to check out, and suggested that maybe it should be a separate question since it wasn't really related to the first part.

A few minutes later, I reconsidered and decided that since the second part wasn't clear and should have been a separate question anyway, it was OK to close the question as a duplicate.

When I did, I found that the entire comment I posted previously was deleted.  I thus had to enter it again, since I still wanted the OP to see my suggestions.

I'm sure this is a use case that doesn't happen very often. But it seems that the logic that automatically deletes "Duplicate of ..." comments should avoid deleting comments that have substantial additional information besides the "duplicate of [link]".

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344519/make-the-automatic-deletion-of-possible-duplicate-of-comments-more-precise

Comment: @user000001 I think that's the problem here, not just a related post.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: This one is a bug report, the other a feature request. I hesitated to vote to close as a duplicate, as I agree that the system deletes stuff it shouldn't, so I didn't want to shut the thread down.

Comment: @user000001 I wasn't saying it should be closed as a dupe, just that it is more than likely it is the same issue.