# Preserve duplicate nomination comments in timeline

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, timeline

When a gold badge holder closes a question as a duplicate of another (called "hammering") any comments suggesting that the question may be  a duplicate are automatically removed. This is sometimes undesirable - the comment removal is fairly aggressive, and sometimes removes comments which contain other useful information as well, and occasionally even comments which do not actually constitute a duplicate nomination.

I'm not asking for this to be changed (though it would be nice to have options) but it seems that these comments are also removed from the question's timeline completely.

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56101415/timeline had a duplicate nomination which I chose to override. I planned to investigate whether I should *also* add the nominated question as a secondary duplicate, but now the comment is eradicated from our universe, so I can't see which duplicate target was nominated, and there is no trace of it anywhere.

Surely, trimming these comments **from the timeline** is an outright bug?

Comment: I *think* I managed to relocate the nominated duplicate based on my memory of its title. But having to remember and guess is obviously not an acceptable recipe in the general case.

Comment: Notice how this obvious dupe was reviewed and accepted from the first posts queue ...

Comment: I think calling this a bug is a misnomer. This is clearly a feature request. As it works now, it's consistent with the expected behaviour: deleted comments are logically not shown in the timeline. What you want is a new behaviour: certain kind of comments should be preserved in the timeline despite being deleted. Maybe adding an event to the timeline at the time they are auto-deleted.

Comment: @tripleee I can confirm you did indeed find the suggested duplicate

Comment: Shouldn't the **Linked** and/or **Related** section, on the right of the post, list the question which was posted as a potential duplicate?

Comment: The hammer system is really blunt, it's called hammer for a reason I guess. The far larger problem is that if there's pending cast close votes on a post, for whatever reason, these are lost in space as soon as the post gets hammered. And then if the merry hammer-wielded realizes "oh hmm this wan't a dupe" and re-opens the post, those close votes cast earlier by others are lost.

Comment: I've encountered this several times and it would be really nice if they were preserved.  I really dislike how aggressive it is since it deletes comments with links to different questions.  It should at least preserve those somewhere.

Comment: Iirc former dupe targets (including the suggested, but not picked) do indeed stay in the "linked" section of the right sidebar.

Comment: @Lundin Whether the post is actually hammered or just normally closed as a duplicate by five close votes from regular users is ultimately unimportant here; but having the hammer means you bump into this more often, and have a stronger incentive to clean up if the results of hammering are less than ideal.

Comment: Tangential note: on the automatic removal, see [*Make the automatic deletion of “possible duplicate of” comments more precise*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344519/2751851) and its linked questions.

Comment: I'm not surprised it made it through the first post review, SO's tools for finding dupes are rather lacking.  If you're not a tag expert (and thus already have a good idea what the dupe is called), going from "smells like a dupe" to actually finding the dupe target is easier said than done.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any reason to even delete them in the first place. Sure, they're *slightly* redundant, but who cares? They're not going to cause any problems.

Comment: When comments are deleted, they are always removed from the timeline. That's normal for a deleted comment. There's nothing special about proposed duplicate comments which results in them being handled differently wrt. the timeline page. Once a comment is deleted, there are no records of it visible to non-moderators, other than that some other comment may mention the the comment or have used @username to have pinged the comment author prior to the comment being deleted. [If a user only qualified to be pinged due to comments, then they are no longer pingable once the comments are deleted.]

Comment: @Makyen That's a useful clarification as such, but I still think this is unintuitive enough to be called a bug. If it's by design, the design is wrong. The simplest solution by far would be to not delete the duplicate comment; it's not hard to separately mark it as "no longer required"; these flags tend to get handled fairly quickly as of late.