# Recently gained C# badge - can I still vote to close by committee?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I recently gained the C# badge, which lets me unilaterally close as a duplicate any question with the C# tag.

Can I turn this ability off, or selectively apply it?  I prefer to vote by "committee" and do not want the additional power and the responsibility the C# badge entails.

Comment: I can down vote some of your answers so you're no longer eligible for the gold badge ... but it in all honesty we can some dupe hammers in that tag, so welcome to the club! And don't worry to get it wrong now and then ... lots of users are kind enough to gently and friendly let you know you mis-hammered ...

Comment: I [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368762/50049) on the noted duplicate (it's been a while and some other stuff deserves mentioning).

Comment: Don't fear the hammer! In the hands of a conscientious wielder (like you -- otherwise you wouldn't be posting this question), duplicate closure is one of the nicest moderation tools we have available: [it has the potential to make everyone happy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366725/2751851). Also, as @rene notes, if you get it wrong sometimes (as we all do) your tag community will be there to help.